# Why is Sony a good tag when Apple and Google aren't?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-blocklist

[google](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google) is blacklisted on Stack Overflow. [apple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apple)'s got a big "DO NOT USE THIS TAG" message on the wiki summary (which, of course, is completely ignored by the people who keep adding it to questions...). [microsoft](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/microsoft) has a less forceful (and not in all caps) "This tag is too general to be useful on most questions" warning on the summary.

This all makes sense. The questions people try to use these tags on aren't about the companies, they're about specific products. These tags should never be used.

So why do we have a [sony](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sony) sponsored tag that's apparently perfectly fine to slap on any question having anything to do with a Sony product? How much would Google need to pay to get un-blacklisted as a tag? Did they just misstep by only sponsoring product-specific tags?

Comment: And also [IBM] or [yahoo] or [amazon]

Comment: It's a horrible tag and should probably go. Sponsoring or not.

Comment: Because no one has brought it to our attention before... it is a pretty small tag still. Looks like it needs some serious disambiguation.

Comment: Looks like it needs to cease to exist @animuson. What is the point of a Sony tag? If there is some specific tech, use a tag with the particular name.

Comment: Just looking through the first page of posts, I see a lot of questions by users who don't have enough reputation to create new tags. This is probably why they use the existing `sony` tag plus `camera` and `api` instead of creating `sony-camera-api` (for one example).

Comment: Sometimes you can have a question that needs a company tag, but they are used wrong most of the time.

Comment: The primary purpose of tags, as I understand it, is to attract the right people to answer a question.  This is exactly how Sony are using this tag, so I'm not sure there's a problem.  Google, Apple, and Microsoft so far as I know don't have people paid to answer questions on SO (?) so the situation isn't comparable.

Comment: While I tend to agree with @HarryJohnston, I think the way Sony presents it is [very misleading](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/253625/1446005).

Answer (score 38):

Actually, it looks like this is due to how Sony recommends tagging to developers [on their developer portal](https://developer.sony.com/support/how-to-post-tag-a-question/):

[image]

(Incidentally, I can't help but be a little bit impressed at the lengths to which they've gone to integrate SO questions there - [surprisingly tasteful](https://developer.sony.com/support/stack-overflow/) given what we usually see).

Comment: See [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30187/what-do-icons-on-the-tags-mean) and [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33081/should-tags-that-represent-concepts-be-sponsorable/104757#104757), @Grant. I don't know what the exact details of the agreement are, but generally-speaking it's considered rude to remove a heavily-used tag without discussing it here first - *regardless* of whether or not it's sponsored.

Comment: I came across this issue again [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253394/third-party-development-support-hosted-by-stack-overflow). Any updates to this tag sponsorship? It's a rather poor tag that IMHO (hah, humble ...) really shouldn't exist.

Comment: Propose a better solution then, @Bart. Apple & Google are discouraged because folks were breaking tagging by splitting apart product names ("google + charts" vs. "google-charts", etc.) There's *some* of that going on here, but no one's going to be happy if you create [tag:sony-android], and even if you want to change, say, [tag:smartwatch] to [tag:sony-smartwatch] you should probably raise the issue here first (does anyone else *use* that tag?)

Comment: Will do @Shog9. Still, you might want to include some form of explanation in your answer. Your answer currently doesn't address the question. "Because Sony says so" might be a reason why it exists, but not why it's allowed to exist.

Comment: Well, this isn't any more of an answer - its not like either of us made a conscious decision to allow it, more that no one has made a compelling argument to *remove* it. Of the other examples, [tag:Google] took a long time to process and [tag:apple] is still around...

Comment: At least now there's this: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253528/clean-up-the-sony-tag-is-it-useful-at-all-or-should-we-re-tag-and-clean-up ;)

Comment: @Shog9, Regarding sites like https://developer.sony.com/support/stack-overflow/ and [Plone](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/253424/632951) , are they using officially supported APIs or is it doing un-APIed web scraping?

Comment: @Pacerier, Yes, they are using the [Stack API](http://api.stackexchange.com/).