# Reach out to OpsHub about outsourcing their support to Stack Overflow

Tags: support, outsourcing

It appears OpsHub is outsourcing their support to Stack Overflow ([opshub](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/opshub)). A lot of their questions are recent and are something along the lines that the operation is failing.

[Here is a page that links off to Stack Overflow](http://opshub.com/main/component/content/category/9-landingpages):

> After performing all these steps if you are still unable to connect,
>   then please check your credential of proxy given in step number-3,
>   restart your installer. Even after this if it does not work,For
>   further more queries, please post them to StackOverflow
>   www.stackoverflow.com with hashtags #opshub and #visual-studio-online.
>   OpsHub team will be periodically reviewing the questions posted there
>   and answering them as appropriate

It also is found [here for a Visual Studio extension.](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/28a90a17-d00c-4660-b7ae-42d58315ccf2)

Comment: Hashtags‽ That’s awful!

Comment: Relevant: [Third-party development support: hosted by Stack Overflow](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253394/third-party-development-support-hosted-by-stack-overflow) and [Is it accessable to use Stack Overflow as a Q&A for a specific product?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253849/is-it-acceptable-to-use-stack-overflow-as-a-qa-for-a-specific-product?rq=1)

Comment: I'm somewhat thankful that Twitter managed to popularise the concept of meta-data, but... really?! #curse #blessing #ohgodwhy #hashtagAllTheThings

Comment: There's this also: http://stackoverflow.com/users/3627522/opshub-inc

Comment: This has also been done with the [ESPN API support page](http://developer.espn.com/support)

Comment: @david99world theirs is at least better IMO

Comment: I reviewed some of their questions and answers, and they don't seem to care about SO guidelines. They mostly use SO as their forum, I've even found duplicate questions answered from their account 4 hours one after another. Some of their questions and answers do look all right, but most of them is garbage we will have to cleanup.

Comment: If we end up burninating a bunch of their garbage do you think they'll get the message about making a mess here?

Comment: I flagged a handful of their stuff a few months ago when they started, as it looked very self-promotional.  It looks like most of the early content I was worried about has already been removed.  If the current content is *also* considered bad, then I doubt that removing it will help.

Comment: Firstly, based on the post " Third-party development support: hosted by Stack Overflow and Is it accessable to use Stack Overflow as a Q&A for a specific product" we are following the guidelines. If we are missing any particular aspect of it, please help us understand and we would be happy to follow them.

Comment: @OpshubInc. thanks for the reply. we just feel that a lot of the questions that are being asked are of very low quality and of a very limited scope to the larger internet audience at large.

Comment: @OpshubInc. we are not a forum in the traditional sense.

Comment: We are promoting the use of SO primarily for the free migration utility (for migrating from on-premise TFS to Visual Studio Online). It is meant to be community supported. It is not used for commercial products. Given the audience (TFS admins primarily) we are likely seeing a larger than average number of first time users (a large number of questions are from users who recently registered and typically have low reputation scored)

Comment: @OpshubInc. in one case i saw that your account asked for logs - that isn't appropriate for SO. SO isn't meant to be a catch all for all errors or support issues. i do see something as potential gaming the system as well.

Comment: @OpshubInc. all we are asking for is concrete guidance on your page to guide the users to ask appropriate, on-topic questions.