# Reach out to SoundCloud about outsourcing their support to Stack Overflow

Tags: discussion, status-completed, outsourcing

SoundCloud ["moved their API Support to Stack Overflow"](https://developers.soundcloud.com/blog/moving-api-support-to-stack-overflow), and so developers are asked to post their questions over here. So far, so good -- see [Third-party development support: hosted by Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253394/third-party-development-support-hosted-by-stack-overflow) for a longer discussion, and I think the consensus is that "it is not a problem if the questions are on-topic for SO".

But in their announcement, SoundCloud uses this phrase:

> We encourage you to start using the 'soundcloud' tag on Stack Overflow from now on **for all questions related to** the SoundCloud Platform.
>   (my emphasis)

and so I happened across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25833532/soundcloud-assets-not-available), which is *not* about how to use the SoundCloud API, but asks for external assets.

Per Daniel E. White's comment on [the same move by OpsHub](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262729/reach-out-to-opshub-about-outsourcing-their-support-to-stack-overflow),

> .. all we are asking for is concrete guidance on your page to guide the users to ask appropriate, on-topic questions ..

should SoundCloud be contacted and asked to rephrase their page?

---

Of minor importance, one can only wonder where the question about SC's assets *should* have been asked (not on any SE site, I'm sure). SC's users are left in the dark, and run a risk of being shouted at on SO, for all their innocence and "following the rules".

Comment: Depending on the question it could even go to [Web Apps](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/soundcloud) or [Sound Design](http://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/soundcloud).

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I left this message below their blog entry.  Hopefully that will be enough.

> It's worth noting that Stack Overflow has standards for accepting
>   questions, and that they're not affiliated with SoundCloud in any way.
>   Not every question gets accepted at Stack Overflow, nor does Stack
>   Overflow provide customer support services.
>
> It is important that everyone asking a SoundCloud question at Stack
>   Overflow read the rules for posting first:
>   https://stackoverflow.com/help/.... Stack Overflow exists to answer
>   people's questions about writing computer code; questions about any
>   other topic (like "how do I get an API key, how do I download the SDK"
>   etc.) will be closed.
>
> Read the SoundCloud documentation first, before asking your question,
>   and make your question clear, specific and answerable.
>
> If you have a troubleshooting problem, describe the problem in detail,
>   along with the exact wording of any error messages you are getting,
>   and provide a snippet of code that reproduces the problem. Describe
>   the troubleshooting steps you've already taken to attempt solve the
>   problem.
>
> Asking "How do I..." questions are OK, as long as you're request is
>   specific, and you don't ask us to write your program for you.
>
> Thanks for listening, and welcome to Stack Overflow!

Also worth noting: the blog entry is dated March 7th, 2012, and the world hasn't come to an end yet, so...

Comment: Given that you only got to the first dot out of 3, did it ju

Comment: The world ended. Now it's back again! Hooray!

Comment: *>you're request*