# Rename [soundcloud] to [soundcloud-api]

Tags: support, status-declined, tags, retag-request

Following [Reach out to SoundCloud about outsourcing their support to Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/271389/792066) and that recent questions are mostly off topic for Stack Overflow (since Dec 16, 4 out 8 questions are closed or downvoted), I believe that the name of the tag should be changed from [soundcloud](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/soundcloud) to [soundcloud-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/soundcloud-api) so it makes more obvious that questions are about the API, and not SoundCloud in general.

Answer (score -4):

Same could be said about facebook, android, iphone, windows, wordpress, google-maps, etc...

I don't think it needs to be explicitly changed because no matter how someone chooses to interpret the tag the scope of on-topic questions doesn't change.

If it's not "obvious" to the person that they are on a "site for professional and enthusiast programmers" then the wording of a tag probably won't change their mind.

Comment: This answer fails to address the fact that I see way too many questions tagged [soundcloud][api]. The same problem happens in your other examples, such as [google-maps][api].

Comment: @Laurel - I feel that your point might have more to say about the [api] tag rather than soundcloud or google-maps

Comment: I've been spending a lot of time getting rid of [api] tags. There's still ~45k questions with the tag, so any other avenue of reducing new tagging is helpful (this q is similar to one I was proposing as a step towards killing [api]). I also don't have enough votes to close all the off topic [api] questions.