# Reach out to SoundCloud - again

Tags: discussion, outsourcing

It seems that [Robert Harvey's attempt](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/271411/1864610) to deflect some of the off-topic traffic from SoundCloud has not been successful (as evidenced by [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28591347/soundclouds-api-returning-no-tracks-for-a-user)). Their support page now reads just *'Our team is answering technical questions on Stack Overflow'*

Would now be a good time to make another attempt at persuading them to clarify what is and is not appropriate to post on Stack Overflow?

Comment: Three of the top answerers in the tag are in fact SoundCloud employees, the support page is accurate.  The question is from a programmer that tries to use the api, he tagged it properly with high odds that those employees will see it.  Pretty unclear to me what else you expect them to do.

Comment: @HansPassant Is the question API related or is it about a mere mulfunctioning of the service which has nothing to do with programming really?

Comment: The url is api.soundcloud.com, mentioned in their http api reference  The questioner has a lot of posts tagged [ios], [objective-c], etc.  It is an api, it is a programmer, what do you think it is?  Hard to see why he has to be flogged like this.  If you don't want to see these questions then just add the tag to your ignored tags list.

Comment: @HansPassant Take a look at the question. if there's a fault with the OP's code then there's nothing there to allow us to help debug it - it's off-topic for that reason. If there's a fault with the API (which is what the question implies) then _only_ Soundcloud can fix it, and once they have done so the question is meaningless - it's off-topic again.