# Reach out to PayPal about outsourcing their support to Stack Overflow

Tags: discussion, outsourcing

Based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30578384/how-are-fees-calculated-for-this-paypal-adaptive-payment-chained-payment-example), I feel it's not made sufficiently clear by PayPal to its users that Stack Overflow is not the correct platform to ask their non-technical questions on.

The link to Stack Overflow is on PayPal's sub-site https://developer.paypal.com/developer/support, where the "Developer Resources" page containing only the brief sentence

> Visit StackOverflow to check out our PayPal forum.

It may be helpful for PayPal, their developers (and, as it appears, their regular clients), and Stack Overflow to ask them to change the wording there to something such as in Robert Harvey's [answer to SoundCloud](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/271411/2564301):

> It's worth noting that Stack Overflow has standards for accepting questions, and that they're not affiliated with **Insert Name Here** in any way. Not every question gets accepted at Stack Overflow, nor does Stack Overflow provide customer support services.
>
> It is important that everyone asking an **Insert Name Here** question at Stack Overflow read the rules for posting first: https://stackoverflow.com/help/.... Stack Overflow exists to answer people's questions about writing computer code; questions about any other topic (like "how do I get an API key, how do I download the SDK" etc.) will be closed.

Comment: Hmya, you can't really expect PayPal to do any better at this than StackExchange.  I'm the hapless victim of the [windows] tag, answering a lot of Windows programming questions.  I easily VTC 8 questions a day that have nothing to do with programming.  These are just people that google "paypal support" and land on that page without having any real idea what "developer" might mean.  Or expect to need a developer to solve their support problem.  Only real way to slow them down is to not let them create an account and instantly ask a question.

Comment: They could, at least, change the word "forum" to something more Q&A friendly.

Comment: ...and besides it not being a forum, it's certainly not "their forum"...

Comment: I am bit confused when Paypal or similar companies openly announce user to visit SO for support. Do they have any formal agreement with SO? If not, then how SO handles this type of association?

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a forum, and should not be treated by PayPal as such. To add to this, PayPal is misusing the SO trademark as SO's name is 'Stack Overflow', not 'StackOverflow'...

Comment: "check out our PayPal forum" is definitely wrong and (intentionally) misleading. I'm surprised they're willing to accept the backlash for this.

Comment: @Rahul, No, no formal agreement. PayPal is just telling people to come to SO with their questions. Stack Exchange will probably send them a letter or an email at some point ansking them to stop doing this, or a at least change the wording on their website.

Comment: Would it be possible for Stack Exchange to display some sort of warning when the HTTP referrer matches that "support" page?  I mean, that's kind of a nuclear option, but I don't imagine PayPal will be very responsive here.

Comment: Or not by referrer, but just by certain tags or keywords in the question. *"Your question seems to be about PayPal, have you read [this]? ..."

Comment: @Rahul the "right" way to do this, for technical help (eg. Ninject and ServiceStack do this) is to have developers actually monitoring and answering questions on SO which have the right tag. The problem here is partly that people who follow the PayPal link aren't aksing technical-enough questions.

Comment: Maybe PayPal can start their "support forum" on Area51 and donate some moderators when they do so.

Comment: Paypal has their logo on their tag, so they have some sort of sponsorship setup or at least communicate with SO..

Comment: @Raystafarian, That does not excuse them from sending crap questions here.

Comment: @JonasCz I'm aware of that, I'm just saying obviously they have a sponsorship agreement and *may* think they are entitled to something that they aren't. I think that'd be handled by whoever the account manager is at SE.

Comment: The terms for tag sponsorship are roughly spelled out on MSE, @Raystafarian: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/104757/159251 Presumably there's a more detailed agreement that SE and the sponsor actually sign.

Comment: [This answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/3984) in [Is it okay to use Stack Overflow as the support forum for a product or project?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/3966) reflects my view: *yes*, it should be allowed to have others point to SO as a good place to ask *technical* questions on, subject to the limits of SO. It's their wording that is, well ... minimally, and probably too unclear for the casual reader.

Comment: Since nobody has mentioned it yet, a reminder/pointer that there is now [an official help page addressing third-party support](http://stackoverflow.com/help/product-support). Note that PayPal's page *does* actually follow the advice to clearly differentiate topics. The problem here is more unusual in that they're claiming a relationship which doesn't exist - "our forum". Given the sponsorship arrangement and brand implications on both sides, I think it would be sensible for a member of SE staff to get involved in this one.

Comment: Assuming Paypal (or any other third party who uses SO as a support forum) are loathe to change their wording, could you not just include an initial message for new users coming in from external sites to links directly to third party support tags?

Comment: Related Meta.SE, **dated March 2013**: [Is Stack Overflow the official PayPal support site?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/173138/162730)...

Comment: I mentioned the misuse of the wordmark, and the language "our forum" in 2014, as well: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261199/reach-out-to-e107-about-outsourcing-their-support-to-stack-overflow#comment47417_261199

Comment: I really think if someone is going to post a link to SO to their related tags they should link to the about page: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/paypal/info That gives a user an immediate view of what they are looking at. With only 5,294/11,803 tagged questions that are unanswered and from the few questions I looked at the answers as far as I could tell they weren't answered by paypal developers.

Comment: I have reached out to Paypal staff members regarding this. Hopefully they will get back to us and rectify the message on the website. Cheers

Comment: @aadarshsg: It's now "Check out the PayPal forum on StackOverflow." So, they fixed the "our" and left _all the other problems_ intact. Sigh.

Comment: Just came accorss this: https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/products/instant-payment-notification/ which is actually even worse and says "To discuss issues and share ideas, visit the PayPal stackoverflow forum". So its even suggesting people visit stack overflow to share ideas

Answer (score 75, accepted):

Just suggest to PayPal that they change "Visit StackOverflow to check out our PayPal forum." to something like:

> Check out our active [PayPal tag](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/paypal/info) on Stack Overflow (a Q&A site for developers).

OR (based on That1Guy's comment, and better IMHO):

> Check out the active [PayPal tag](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/paypal/info) on Stack Overflow (a Q&A site for developers).

I actually saw that link a few weeks back, and got excited as not only is SO a better place for Q&A than any product-specific forum site, I assumed it means PayPal developers monitor that tag. (Actually I imagine/hope part of the sponsorship is that they agree to have a minimum number of developers subscribed to their tag.)

But, however you rephrase you are still going to get off-topic or duplicate questions. From what I hear, PayPal can be a bit slow to respond to questions from their merchants, so people get desperate, and will start asking for help in other places. Desperate people either won't read long pieces of advice, or will assume it doesn't apply to them, or will say to themselves, "well, I'm only going to do it once, it'll be okay." :-)

Comment: If I had my choice, the use of "our" would be removed from the phrasing.

Comment: @That1Guy Thanks. I added that suggestion (our --> the).

Comment: Well, we can all pat ourselves on the back about making a good decision for PayPal. So... Is anyone going to tell them?

Comment: @Basic Presumably that is the job of their Account Manager at StackOverflow... This question has got lots of views, so let's hope that includes someone in the accounts department :-)

Comment: Both  lines looks exact same

Comment: @NullPoiиteя you are wrong and **our** 1st line is changed to **the** as Darren Cook already commented.

Comment: @fujiFX lol both line are exact same !! so how am i wrong

Comment: @NullPoiиteя well, if you intended the light hearted side of it yes it **looks** to be the same but **grammatically** not ;)

Comment: @DarrenCook They do monitor the PayPal related tags, I once had my question answered by the developer from the PayPal iOS SDK. Unfortunately, I believe he was the only guy working on the whole SDK.

Comment: @Leandros: but do they vote down and VTC off topic questions, as they should? (I doubt it.)

Comment: They have yet to fix that..