# What can we do with questions where the only response is "contact the vendor"?

Tags: discussion, flags, unanswered-questions

Take for instance:

[WriteFile returning error code 995](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20187861/writefile-returning-error-code-995)

The comment discussion diagnosed this question to a likely driver problem with a USB-serial device.  Should we wait for the OP to provide a followup with the results of their vendor contact?  Should we flag this as "too localized" because it requires the OP to contact the device vendor?  Should we provide a "Contact the vendor" answer?  Should this question hang around unanswered forevermore?

Comment: Note that the "too localized" close reason [no longer exists](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/185102/234299).

Comment: @gnat Note that the focus of that question is *customer* support, not development support. The most upvoted answer states, "Yes. For your on-topic, programming-related questions. For your questions having specifically to do with writing code for their API. For questions that involve customer service issues, you need to contact the company directly." Sure seems programming related to me. If we want to use that as an FAQ for *programming* related issues that we don't really have any way of answering, it needs to be expanded some.

Comment: @gnat I knew there was a related one focused on actual programming questions: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253394/third-party-development-support-hosted-by-stack-overflow?lq=1 Note that that question isn't really a duplicate, either. The user came here of their own accord (near as I can tell, anyway), seeking help with code they're writing. It just turns out that we can't really help much because it's probably a third party bug.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Stack Overflow can't provide the *final, definitive solution* to a problem of this type, but there is still value in an answer that tells the poster *what to do next*, particularly when someone else might trip over the same problem.  We are a public resource and we optimize our description of the problem for maximum searchability.  Vendor knowledge bases, bug trackers, and engineering support contacts tend to be poorly searchable at best, and often aren't public at all.

Therefore, I think questions that arise directly from a *programming* problem, where the next-action answer is "You need to take this up with a third party, who can be contacted at [hyperlink]", should be considered on-topic and an answer of that form should be considered the correct answer.

In addition to bugs in hardware drivers, here are some other example scenarios where this could come up:

- As mentioned in the comments, in the C and C++ tags, it is uncommon-but-not-rare for the correct answer to "Is this MCVE valid code" to be "Congratulations, you have found a bug in your compiler, here is how to report it."
- Similarly, in the various web-related tags, "how do I do X?" or "why does this page not draw as I expected?" might be best answered "this is a known bug in browsers A and B but works correctly in C, see the tracker here" or "that's not currently possible, here is how to advocate for a new browser feature".
- This might be more relevant to ServerFault and its close relatives, but it's not unheard of for vendors to change the procedure for some manual task on every release; in that case, the best answer we can give is a pointer to the vendor's documentation plus instructions on how to know which version of the documentation to read.

Comment: That's just posting an answer to say, "we can't give you an answer".  The way that you say that a question cannot be answered (here) is to close it.  If the close reason states that the question needs to be asked to the vendor, then future readers can see that just as easily as in an answer.

Comment: @Servy, no, it's not. It's a real answer, it's just not the type of answer that was expected.

Comment: @nmr It's telling someone where they can go to find a real answer.  It is not, itself, an actual answer.  A pointer to where you can go to find an answer is not an answer, by SO's standards of a valid answer.

Comment: Strongly disagree. The question is "why does WriteFile return the error code 995" the direct answer is 'apparent driver bug'.

Comment: You're trying to answer the question you want to answer, not the question that was asked.

Comment: @servy I'm with nmr here.  This sort of thing comes up in other contexts too: for instance, when there is a documented procedure to do X, but that procedure changes with every release of the software for X, the correct, on-topic-for-SO answer to "How do I do X?" is "It keeps changing. Consult the documentation for your exact release of this software, which you can find at [this link]." IMNSHO.

Comment: I have to agree with this. We have plenty of questions in the C++ tag which boil down to "there's a bug in your compiler". As long as the question is "what is this behavior" and not "please fix this bug", it would appear to be a valid question.

Comment: @Servy The drawback of closing the question is also that it might get deleted, so won't be helpful to future readers.

Comment: This should be the real answer.

Comment: @Servy Bottom line is that it's still *useful content* and within the purview of this site. It tells the OP that they're probably not doing anything wrong and that it's most likely a bug with the device. It isn't the end-all of their problem, but it's definitely something I would want to read in a similar situation.

Comment: this approach opens quite interesting opportunities for [astroturfing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Astroturfing). _Q: "How do I make Foo show Bar when I run SuperMegaTool over Baz code?" A: ""That's not currently possible, go to SuperMegaTool homepage (spammy link) to advocate for a new feature"_ -- spammers gotta love it if this is declared legitimate Q&A at Stack Overflow

Comment: @gnat I am confident that our moderators can tell the difference.

Comment: @zwol your confidence seems to be based on wrong assumptions. Making decisions based on domain specific knowledge is not moderator's job, see [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/site-moderators)

Comment: @gnat That's a good case against questions where the answer is just, "that feature doesn't exist yet" and advocating for a feature request, which is something this answer brings up (and you're right to question it). On the other hand, I hesitate to throw these questions out categorically. Probably a lot of the bad questions you mention could be closed as simply Too Broad. Regardless, the specific question referred to in the OP is not that sort of question; it's a specific error someone ran into in the course of writing code. Asking about how to deal with specific errors is definitely on topic.

Comment: @jpmc26 upon further thinking, you probably have a point, this is more like a gray area, rather than clear cut bad-vs-good difference

Answer (score 14):

Close the question with a custom offtopic reason stating that bug reports should be reported to the vendor.

Comment: Done -- looks like that's the most reasonable thing to do.