# Are bug report-ish questions in the scope of SO?

Tags: discussion, scope

I've found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32958900/is-it-a-google-bug-in-app-purchases) about a possible bug in Google App Purchases and was about to flag it because I think it doesn't belong on SO, but should be reported as a bug to the relevant tracker.

However, as I'm not an expert in the field and the question may evolve into something useful on using App Purchases (although from the way things are going I wouldn't think so), I hesitated.

A [search query](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22is+this+a+bug+in%22) on "is this a bug in" returns a lot (~3,6k) of results, albeit with very mixed results (upvoted, downvoted, closed). So I'm wondering whether bug report-ish style questions are indeed in the scope of SO or not?

Comment: a bug in a certain c++ compiler would be in the scope, but a but the http://www.nytimes.com/ page would not.

Comment: That search is potentially misleading. A question like "Is this a bug in my function x or in my function y" will be part of the list even though it's not a bug report.

Comment: There's a bunch of screen shots, but they don't really convey any useful information.  Without more context on the application they developed, the question is more of a "general software" question and not that on-topic for SO.  _Possibly_ on-topic for Super User.  The biggest giveaway though is "It happens also when I tried to purchase another apps on play store so I think it's not my fault." which leads me to believe that it's not programming related.

Comment: "Is this a bug?" can potentially be a useful question: the answer might be "it's *not* a bug" and an explanation of how some spec'd behavior causes the anomalies the user sees, or maybe it's "it *is* a bug" and the answers provide a useful warning to others or help with workarounds. Agree with Bob: if it's a question and good otherwise, "is this a bug?" doesn't disqualify it, but not all bug-report-y questions are good.

Comment: IMO bug-report-y questions *without proof* are useless. Too often people like to blame the tools and make their life miserable in the process. As in "I get this error, is it a bug in Java?" - no its a bug in your code and Java is working perfectly by showing you the error, fix it.

Comment: Relevant: [Are link-only answers pointing to resolved bug reports answers?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/303974)

Comment: related (possibly a duplicate): [Why we're not customer support for \[your favorite company\]](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255745/839601)

Comment: Closely related: [What can we do with questions where the only response is “contact the vendor”?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284708/what-can-we-do-with-questions-where-the-only-response-is-contact-the-vendor)

Comment: If you squint really hard, you can kind of make out the OP's credit card number from under the black marker... Don't you think?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

**Yes**, such questions are within the scope, *but* they must:

- Not be in the format of "I've found a bug. Please fix it."
- Have an example (MCVE) of the faulty code
- *Be questions*

The question you linked is off-topic, as [it has no MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve):

> When asking a question about a problem caused by your code, you will
>   get much better answers if you provide code people can use to
>   reproduce the problem.

We can't reproduce the OP's problem without *some sort* of code example from them. It can be likened to someone telling you their car isn't working, but doesn't let you check under the bonnet.

The question should therefore **be closed** as:

> **Too Broad** - There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. **Please add details** to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.

(we can't identify what the problem is without the code that's causing the problem, so any answers will likely be guesses and as such, the question is too broad)

Comment: I agree the question is off-topic, though for different reasons: it's not about programming; it's about a bug in a mobile app. Stack Overflow is definitely not the place for that kind of "question". *Maybe* if the OP included their code, but I don't know how feasible an MVCE is for that question.

Comment: @TylerH The OP created the application, so yes, it is a programming question. However the OP's not provided us with any code and as such, it should be closed as no MCVE. I raised a custom moderator flag asking for closure as it has a (rather foolish IMHO) bounty, and bounty questions cannot be vote-closed.

Comment: I'm with @TylerH here. The line, "It happens also when I tried to purchase another apps on play store so I think it's not my fault," means it probably isn't a problem with the code. If the OP doesn't think it's a problem with the code, it's not a programming question. If they do research and discover that it *is* a problem with their code, it becomes a programming question and they will probably have gained the knowledge necessary to produce an MCVE. Where they should go to get help making that determination, I couldn't say.

Comment: @bob: The flag will be declined, as the bounty-graceperiod is nearly over.

Comment: @Deduplicator Flag was marked "helpful" and the moderator who reviewed it put the question on-hold and refunded the bounty.

Comment: @Deduplicator [Rep history](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1254996/alon-shmiel?tab=reputation) of the OP shows a +200 bounty for today, which presumably is a refund of the bounty that was set.

Comment: @bob Yep, just looked. Strange decision...

Comment: @Deduplicator I guess the system does it automatically, it's probably possible to override it though in certain circumstances.

Answer (score 10):

Of course. Two classic formats of these:

Q: "According to the docs, I should be able to do X, but when I try that, it doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?"

A: It's a bug.

and:

Q: "Is there a bug in X, because it sure looks like it for these reasons: ..."

A: Yes. (Or, no, you goofed..)

The ones that are probably off topic include:

- bugs that don't actually matter. ("Hey, I think I found an edge case...")
- bugs in things that aren't software tools
- questions where the question is not simply establishing whether or not the bug exists (and workarounds), but delve into getting the bug fixed.
- questions without enough information to confirm/disprove the bug

Comment: "questions where the question is not simply establishing whether or not the bug exists (and workarounds), but delve into getting the bug fixed" -- Why would that be off topic? Such a question could easily be too broad, but that's a separate issue, and assuming it's asked in a way that doesn't make it too broad, what else do you see wrong with it?

Comment: Well, because once you start talking about taking action to fix something, it's not really a question anymore is it?

Comment: Ah, are you thinking of taking action to get the developers to fix the bug? Right, "should I report this?" does not make a good question. I was thinking of fixing it yourself and asking concrete questions about that.