# Why was one of my NAA flags declined?

Tags: discussion, declined-flags, not-an-answer

I've followed this question (*[Why is the enumeration value from a multi dimensional array not equal to itself?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36588365/why-the-enumeration-value-from-a-multi-dimensional-array-does-not-equal-to-itsel)*) since the beginning. The day after it was asked, this answer popup:

> I'm a dev on the JIT team at Microsoft. I've reproduced the bug and have opened an issue for it internally (shipping x86 JIT is not yet in the open on github). In terms of timing of when this would be fixed, I anticipate that we will have this fix included in the next major release of the tools. If this bug is having business impact, and you need a fix earlier, please file the connect (connect.microsoft.com) issue so we can look impact and what alternatives we have to getting a fix to you faster.

To me, it doesn't, at all, answer to the question asked by the OP:

- Q: Why it (wrongly) behave like this?
- A: I've reproduced the bug and we'll fix it.

As a reminder, this is the description of the NAA flags (I've bolded the reason why I flagged the post):

> This was posted as an answer, but **it does not attempt to answer the question**. **It should possibly be** an edit, **a comment**, another question, or deleted altogether.

Is this post really an answer? Or should it be converted to a comment?

As my previous flag also been declined I start to think that I should re-read the whole part about flagging in the FAQ in order not to less bother moderators with useless flags.

Comment: It is an answer. It clearly states "Yup, that's a bug", adresses OPs problem and also mentions a solution ("Wait for the fix"). IMO that's an answer.

Comment: You did read the [your answer is in another castle](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer), right? If not I suggest you do. I know some of the crowd here don't like the [SOCVR](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers) room but our regulars have a noticeable track record in both helpful, disputed and declined flags. When you need advice hop in there and ask if a flag is warranted. Despite popular believe, we don't bite.

Comment: somewhat related: [Are bug report-ish questions in the scope of SO?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/308010/are-bug-report-ish-questions-in-the-scope-of-so)

Comment: *Why it (wrongly) behave like this?* Seriously, man, I don't follow. It's a bug in a complicated piece of software, and one of the only people that *can* fix the issue has taken the time to reproduce the problem and to make sure it will get fixed somewhere along the way. Yet you want their answer to disappear because of *policy*? Biting the hands that help us will lead us nowhere.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi I don't want it to be deleted, IMHO it should be converted to a comment. When I posted this question I didn't understand why mods didn't want to to it and that's why I asked, to try to understand and don't repeat my mistakes. I'm glad that this user took the time to do his job and I'm thankful for the fix it'll bring.

Comment: @Thomas Anytime you flag any answer as NAA you're asking for it to be deleted.  That's the appropriate course of action for non-answers.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

How is saying, "It's a bug" *not* an answer to the question of "Why does it behave like this?"  Not only is it *an*, answer, it's *the correct answer*.  If you feel that it's not sufficiently well explained then you could downvote it on the grounds that you don't think that the answer is helpful, but your opinion that it's not a *quality* answer doesn't mean it's not an answer at all.