# Another failed audit

Tags: discussion, disputed-review-audits

https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/12184787

Failed that audit, but I think, it is obvious, that it is not the kind of answer we want at SO. Please remove this from audits.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/321444/why-was-one-of-my-naa-flags-declined

Comment: @PetahChristian Ok, the accepted answer there states "You could have downvoted". That's exactly what I did.

Comment: Wait, what?  Why?  Why should this be shunned?  It's a dev from that project answering a question on some strange behavior.  Why would we not want that here?

Comment: An answer from someone at Microsoft telling us that it is a bug? Why wouldn't you want that?

Comment: It does not solve the problem, it is as simple as that.

Comment: What "solution" do you want from a question like that?  The main premise of the question isn't looking for a workaround, they want an explanation.  The explanation was that it was a bug.  The *solution* is that Microsoft is going to fix it.  I'm not sure why there's an issue.

Comment: @Makoto I would have expected a technical explanation for the bug and a suggested workaround for the meantime. YMMV, but imho, this is enough reason for a downvote which failed the audit. Therefore, I ask to remove this question from audits.

Comment: This is a pretty terrible answer. The answer posted a day before already identified it as a bug, and fully explains how the bug works. Dev or not, we don't need another answer that just confirms they reproduced it and will get it fixed. It provides no useful information other than "we're working on it." Aka we are not tech support.

Comment: Not sure why you are getting downvoted but that is a pretty trash answer and I would have recommended deletion for it if I saw it in the LQP queue. Its definately meant as a comment.

Comment: Seems like the answer was converted to a comment on the accepted answer in the meantime. Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Yes**, this should be removed from audit because it really is a comment.

In essence, the answer says:

> [something something] There is a bug report here. It will be fixed in the future. If it's a problem with your business contact Microsoft so they can help you [something something]

That they are an employee is not relevant, while not hurting either, it's context. I have no strong opinion on this but this is in no way a clear good answer for audits.