# What constitutes an answer to a bug report?

Tags: discussion, questions, not-an-answer

[This watchOS 3 beta 3 bug report](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38574384/watch-networking-broken-in-xcode-8-beta-3) doesn't appear to contain a question.

*I think this is a good illustration of [Are bug report-ish questions in the scope of SO?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/308010/are-bug-report-ish-questions-in-the-scope-of-so)*

Since then, [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38645771/4151918) has been posted:

> The relevant thread with Apple is here: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/52586
>
> Looks to be a widespread issue. No known workarounds at this time.

*I voted to close the question as off-topic (Seeking help but no MCVE;  no actual question asked). I also flagged the answer as Not-an-answer.*

**Link-only answer?**

@Laurel felt this was a link-only answer, but the link doesn't happen to include any form of answer. (At present, it's a series of "Me too" replies.)

Laurel's recommendation could generally be followed when there was a solution that could be included here, but at present, the question is whether it's better off as a comment.

**Not-an-answer?**

Setting the link aside for now, the answer basically says "Others reported this too, **no one has an answer**."

If we apply the [Not-an-answer guidelines](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265552/when-to-flag-an-answer-as-not-an-answer), it *is* an attempt to answer the bug report.

**Where to go from here?**

*Once* the bug does get fixed, programmers ***would*** want to know.

But until the bug is fixed, has this (implied) question really been answered?

Instead of continuing the discussion in the comments, I wanted to move this discussion to meta to figure out how "Q: Bug Report, A: It's an issue, no workaround" would be helpful to others in the future.

Comment: I finally looked at the link. It's not a bug report itself, but somebody mentions they filed a bug report. And then (after a bit of research) I realized that [**you can't even see the report**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/144873/can-i-browse-other-peoples-apple-bug-reports). My [link](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303974) applies even less here. Also note that the text of the link only answer says that "while this link **may** answer the question", so that's what I go by.

Comment: It makes little sense to focus on the answer.  Getting rid of it just gets somebody else to post it.  The problem is with the question, it needs to be closed.  It doesn't have to be deleted.