# I'm extremely confused about this audit which appears not to contain a question

Tags: discussion, review-audits, disputed-review-audits, specific-audit

The specific (known good) review audit is this: [Base R wilcox.test gives incorrect answers, has been fixed in DescTools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77633780/base-r-wilcox-test-gives-incorrect-answers-has-been-fixed-in-desctools)

As the commenters noted, this doesn't really look like a *question*, more like a "call to action" for a person or persons not directly affiliated with Stack Overflow.  Since it looks well-researched and insightful, I upvoted it, but I also flagged it as "*Needs Improvement* → *Community-Specific Reason* → *Not Reproducible*" (only because there's no "not a question" closure reason).

It looks like I must be missing something?  Are announcements relating to code repository bugs on-topic here, even if they don't explicitly ask a question?  I was under the impression that if someone wants to share information on Stack Overflow, they should format the problem they have solved as a question, and then post a self-answer to that question.

Comment: *Very tangentially* related to this question: on Windows 11 in Firefox, the preview of this question on the main Questions page seems to split the double-quotes character apart into its character code, displaying just the initial ampersand: https://i.imgur.com/anh50I1.png  I don't know whether this is a bug or just what's supposed to happen when there isn't enough room to display a character.

Comment: For what it's worth, I agree with your assessment. The Q&A format of Stack Overflow is quite clear, and people looking to answer their own questions should adhere to it for the sake of searchability and consistency. While I can't find a post explicitly saying this (I'm sure there's one around here somewhere...), there is [a Meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/309555) stating that it's acceptable to move someone's answer from their question to an actual answer, which implies that this is the desired format.

Comment: However, I am aware that different "sub-communities" on the site (the users that are active in the [tag:r] tag in this case) moderate content a bit differently, so that may be what's happening here.

Comment: Why did you OK let alone upvote a post that doesn't ask a clear useful (on-topic) question? (Rhetorical.) "well-researched and insightful" **don't matter** if it's not an on-topic question. (I rephrased the non-topical "question" request "Will someone kindly bring this ... to the attention ...") Those are reasons to downvote. "Known good" to the automated review audit process only means that it wasn't downvoted by somebody. That doesn't mean people actually voted constructively. Also you should have edited out the social content.

Comment: @philipxy I **didn't** "OK" it, I *flagged it as unanswerable*.  I would argue that it **is** both 'clear' and 'on topic,' and, judging by the post's score, at least 6 other viewers found it useful.  Another commenter has already suggested the possibility of converting it to an actual Q/A pair (or at least, I interpreted the comment as such).  As a non-subject-matter-expert, I *personally* wouldn't be able to come up with the question to go with that actually-an-answer, but someone else might.  If the post were edited into a question, and its current contents pasted into an answer,

Comment: then OP would keep their score, and it would no longer be off-topic.  But, this should be done by a 2k+ user, since there's no way that drastic of an edit would survive the suggested edit queue gauntlet :D

Comment: Rereading my last comment, I realize it wasn't clear what "edited into a question" should mean.  I was thinking of something like, *there must be a problem someone noticed (i.e. whatever wasn't working because of the bug in the programming language), and presumably that resulted in a specific error or unexpected outcome, which could then be asked about.*  Then the answer would be how the paper, or repository, or wherever the solution was discovered addresses that problem.  The part about contacting the R development team could of course be edited out.

Comment: Related: [Are bug report-ish questions in the scope of SO?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/308010/are-bug-report-ish-questions-in-the-scope-of-so) Considering that the question being discussed boils down to "There's a bug in wilcox.test in Base R someone please report it to Base R development team" it isn't on-topic.

Comment: Please be aware that review audits are selected automatically, so review audits are not really "known good", they are just questions that were upvoted and did not receive downvotes (I'm probably missing some items in the selection criteria). If you're confronted with such a bad audit, open the question itself, downvote it (and if it is not on-topic, vote/flag to close).

Comment: This seems like it could easily be turned into a real question, e.g. "Base R wilcox.test gives incorrect answers, is there a workaround?" and the answer could be "use the new C++ implementation of DescTools::HodgesLehmann." The goal of drawing the attention of the developers would be better served by a bug report, but workarounds for bugs are on-topic here.

Comment: For reference, the question has now been removed "for reasons of moderation".

Comment: @DarrylNoakes It's just deleted by some users. That seems to be a bit over the top. There are by far much worse questions on SO. Unless maybe it was deleted to protect from the meta effect. All in all not really the best outcome, which would have been a salvaged question.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

> even if they don't explicitly ask a question? I was under the impression that if someone wants to share information on Stack Overflow, they should format the problem they have solved as a question, and then post a self-answer to that question.

Your understanding here is correct.

> Since it looks well-researched and insightful, I upvoted it

Please don't do this. Other people incorrectly did so, which is why the "question" was inappropriately selected as an audit.

"Question" posts that don't fit the site standards should be closed.

To close something is to prevent it from receiving answers until reopened; this is, in other words, a signal that the question should not be answered.

The purpose of questions on a Q&A site is to be answered. Therefore, closure is a signal that the attempt at a question is **not useful**, which makes it eligible for downvoting as well. Especially when it appears [that the problem could not be solved without fundamentally changing the question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/426219/): if close votes were consistently accompanied by downvotes, unsalvagable questions would more consistently reach -3 upon closure, and thus be more consistently eligible for immediate deletion.

But this question *probably could* be salvaged by moving the "has been fixed in DescTools" part to an answer, showing a concrete example in the question, and asking about how to get the correct result - without assuming in the question that it's a bug in `wilcox.test`, and without explicitly asking for alternative tools etc.

> but I also flagged it as "Needs Improvement → Community-Specific Reason → Not Reproducible"

It appears that "not about programming" was the consensus among those with close-vote privileges. When there is no attempt to ask a question, but the post still seems to be about some programming-related topic, my default is "needs details or clarity": it's unclear why the post is being presented as a Stack Overflow question, when it doesn't appear that there's anything to ask or answer.

Answer (score 4):

> It looks like I must be missing something?

Why? What makes you think that was a good question?

> Are announcements relating to code repository bugs on-topic here

Sure, it's still code.

> even if they don't explicitly ask a question?

That would be a "no". We can't assume the poster's intention. There are also questions about why things work (perhaps unexpectedly to the poster).

What could we make out of a post that starts and ends with saying "this html button submits a form" (stating a fact, without a literal question). Are we supposed to guess what the poster is asking?

> I was under the impression that if someone wants to share information on Stack Overflow, they should format the problem they have solved as a question, and then post a self-answer to that question.

Agreed, or worst case scenario - clearly answering it under the question (in the same post).

That particular post, however, doesn't have a question *at all*. It clearly goes against the principle of Q&A.

---

Edit: the quality of the content is off-topic, in my opinion. Otherwise people can easily start abusing this by posting random technical junk just for the upvotes.