# Visual Studio Code encouraging users to ask questions on Stack Overflow

Tags: discussion, product-support

[Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/Home/Connect) are encouraging users to ask questions about the IDE on Stack Overflow.

> Engage with your peers and ask questions about Visual Studio Code on Stack Overflow using the tag vscode

It seems to me that they haven't properly followed the guidance from the [Product Support](https://stackoverflow.com/help/product-support) page.

The number of [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/?show=all&sort=newest&page=1&pagesize=50&layout=expanded&tagfilter=list&tags=vscode) is currently very low, but given the blasé approach to sending users to Stack Overflow we are at risk bug/feature requests.

They do have a separate bug reporting system and are not asking users to report bugs on Stack Overflow. It's just not very clear.

Should someone reach out to Visual Studio Code to give better guidance, and should I even report this if it's not currently a problem?

Comment: They probably think they are following the guidance: _"Guide your users in where to ask what -- something along the lines of the following:"_. Their page actually does point users to other places for feature requests and bug reports. I think the phrase "something along the lines of" might lead people to think being kinda/sorta close is OK when we really want them to make it clear that SO is for programming questions only.

Comment: At least their suggested tags are getting better :)

Comment: I think their wording is just fine. Visual Studio Code is an IDE, and questions about an IDE (being a software tool primarily used by programmers) are on topic, within reason. (obviously some are still off topic, such as "Why doesn't it have feature X?")

Comment: This is their wording: "Engage with your peers and ask questions about Visual Studio Code on Stack Overflow using the tag vscode". Far too open IMHO. Asking a good question at SO takes serious effort, you have to prepare people for that. Also, questions about tools tend to be off-topic much more often than questions on programming languages or libraries.

Comment: Can you suggest an alternative that isn't 3 paragraphs long? I guess they could instead link to the "how to ask" guide, but... don't we already present that to new users?

Comment: "Engage with your peers and ask questions about coding issues on Stack Overflow using the tag vscode" To me it's the "ask about VSC" that seems problematic. And they could add something about reading the guidelines hear on how to ask a good question and/or provide a link.

Comment: I think that narrows it down too much. coding issues aren't the only kinds of questions allowed here, those types of questions typically won't be about the IDE anyway.

Comment: @KevinB "alternative that isn't 3 paragraphs long". Maybe we should rename Stack Overflow to Lion's Den or Snake Pit :)

Comment: I don't consider a problem if it's worded too narrowly rather than broadly. SO is already used as a dumping ground for any sort of computer question *even by people that really ought to know better* (i.e. rep between 150 and 500) so anything that may help dissuade that is a positive in my book.

Comment: @KevinB there's nothing wrong with asking about an IDE on SO, and also "coding issues" questions should not be tagged with the IDE you're using.. My concern is more "engage with your peers" - SO is not a social network.

Comment: You reminded me long time ago there was reference to SO from d.android.com site explicitly stating that you can get help here.

Comment: @Blorgbeard asking questions is also "engaging with your peers". they aren't suggesting anyone come here to do anything against our rules, they just aren't instructing them not to do something against our rules.

Comment: They do have different links for bugs and suggestions/why there isn't this feature requests so assuming people can read it should be fine.

Comment: Isn't it part of stack exchange's Bussiness model to encourage other companies to outsource their support to stackoverflow and other se network sites?

Comment: Also: [**Third-party development support: hosted by Stack Overflow**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/253394/119527)

Comment: I see the tag a bit annoying. It should be visual-studio-code to be in line with the others, but...

Answer (score 57):

> ... should I even report this if it's not currently a problem?

No.

Not only is there not a current problem, but I don't see how Visual Studio Code is violating the guidelines as outlined. It is perfectly acceptable to encourage folks to have productive Q&A on Stack Overflow as long as they fit the Stack Overflow guidelines.

Comment: "as long as they fit the Stack Overflow guidelines". I think that's the problem. People don't do that naturally. And if they land here from a product page they feel warranted to ask *anything*. Sometimes they even think they address product support directly.

Comment: @GertArnold Vote to close the questions that don't fit within Stack Overflow guidelines.  If it becomes a chronic problem with a large majority of questions in that tag, then address it with a post like this on Meta.  Until that happens though, don't worry about it.

Comment: I like to be more pro-active. They're not the only one. We already have enough questions to close.

Comment: @GertArnold Why don't you set up an alert then to be notified of vscode tag questions so you can personally monitor the tag and take action as people make posts?  Then you can report back here if the problem gets worse.  The Stack Overflow guidelines are quite clear and are not being violated at this time.

Comment: It's also fine to have someone reach out to them.  Though the main thing I'd add is that the focus should be on better educating users about how to use SO, as opposed to trying to stop third-parties from haphazardly referring people to SO.  The latter bit is always going to happen; the best solution is to provide our own clear, high-quality guidance to those users who wind up on SO haphazardly, whether they've done so at the behest of a third-party software vendor, a Google search, or anything else.

Comment: 2 people were triggered by the word "discussions".

Comment: @BoltClock Clarified s/discussions/Q&A as that's what I was trying to get at.

Answer (score 6):

This is not a new thing. See the list of third-party development support being directed to Stack Overflow at [Third-party development support: hosted by Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253394/third-party-development-support-hosted-by-stack-overflow).

The good news is that the Stack Overflow model for Q&A is working. It is working so well that third-party vendors/developers are using Stack Overflow to provide support to their users.

It's hard to predict where this will head in the long run. Will it grow to unmanageable levels? It's quite possible. For the time being it doesn't seem to be a problem.