# Is this up-to-date: "Can I support my product on this site?"

Tags: discussion, product-support

I was wondering if I could support my product on SO. So I went searching and found this link: https://stackoverflow.com/help/product-support

> Types of questions and where to ask:
>
> - How do I? -- Stack Overflow (tell them what tags to use -- your       product and language at minimum)
> - I got this error, why? -- Stack Overflow
> - I got this error and I'm sure it's a bug -- file an issue (on your own site)
> - I have an idea/request -- file an issue (on your own site)
> - Why do you? -- your own community (developer forum etc)
> - When will you? -- your own community

So there seems to be some kind of encouragement, but these questions don't seem to agree:
[Third-party development support: hosted by Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253394/third-party-development-support-hosted-by-stack-overflow)

> I feel this is very wrong:
>
> https://developer.sony.com/support/
>
> "You can easily find (...) answers (...) by going to our Stack Overflow
>   page."

and:
[Why we're not customer support for [your favorite company]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/why-were-not-customer-support-for-your-favorite-company)

Comment: It shouldn't be your only support channel

Comment: I think [this answer from Tim Post](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/253852/578411) has the back story on that help page you found.