# IBM Bluemix - confusion about link to SO

Tags: discussion, external-links

Please have a look at this suggested edit: https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/10664540

This is what you can find in the [Service Description](https://www-03.ibm.com/software/sla/sladb.nsf/pdf/6605-06/$file/i126-6605-06_12-2015_en_US.pdf)

> All customers of Bluemix are provided Free Support. A consumer of
>   resources provided by the platform can go to Stack Overflow
>   (stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bluemix) or the DeveloperWorks
>   Forum (https://developer.ibm.com/bluemix) and post a question about
>   any item found in the Bluemix product. Questions posted to the forum
>   are not provided an SLA for response or a commitment to fix. Free
>   Support does not entitle access to our Support Ticket System. All
>   questions or issues are addressed in the Forum.

This is indeed confusing, as it mentions SO and their own forums in the same sentence and thus `question about any item` seems to imply that SO rules do not apply.

I am not sure if we can/want to do something about this.

Comment: SO should contact them and tell them to **** off

Comment: It may be useful to clarify which SO rules you believe that that statement encourages breaking.

Comment: @ChrisAnderson-MSFT, everything that does not meet http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: Haha. I'm aware of the rules page... Questions about software tools are allowed: "software tools commonly used by programmers;". The statement in the description says "post a question about any item found in the Bluemix product". That doesn't explicitly say ask a question which breaks the other rules of SO (i.e. "What's better Bluemix or Parse?"). I think it could be improved by reminding folks they should adhere to all the rules, but certainly isn't necessary given that most tags out there don't remind folks to stick to the site rules.

Comment: @ChrisAnderson-MSFT - ["Why we're not customer support for your favorite company"](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/why-were-not-customer-support-for-your-favorite-company) is a better reference.

Comment: @BradLarson - All of that totally makes sense, but doesn't exclude asking questions about a company's products - "Yes. For your on-topic, programming-related questions. For your questions having specifically to do with writing code for their API. But for questions that involve customer service issues, you need to contact the company directly.". Sure, it could vaguely be improved by reminding people to follow SO rules, but is that the point of tag descriptions?

Comment: @ChrisAnderson-MSFT Come on.  If they're going to suggest people come here, they should spend a few minutes and be *absolutely clear* about the support they can provide here.  They couldn't be arsed to spend ten minutes specifying that they support programming questions on StackOverflow, thus saving us all a load of bother.  That's their bad, and they should rectify it.

Comment: @Will - I agree that the language talking about support is a problem, which I think is why Brad shared that link. Tags shouldn't be used to advertise business features. I don't think the part of that description you quoted implies that SO rules don't apply; they just don't reiterate the rules of SO. The JavaScript tag talks about questions without reminding you to follow the rules; do you have an issue there? Providing a link to their support forum is also a good idea for easily finding another avenue when your question doesn't meet SO's rules.

Comment: @ChrisAnderson-MSFT [struck the first lines of this comment as OP has made the claim you refute--my bad]  What they  have done is direct people *with no idea what StackOverflow is or what it does* **to** StackOverflow to ask questions about their product.  What questions?  They don't state what types of questions to ask here.  That has, and will continue, to cause confusion in their own user base and consternation here--both of which they could forestall by being good neighbors. [again, redacted incorrect assertion] OP is incorrect that this is the equivalent of telling them to break rules.

Comment: Yeah, I do agree with @ChrisAnderson-MSFT that "seems to imply that SO rules do not apply" is more of an assumption than a valid conclusion.  They aren't being good neighbors, tho.

Comment: Honest question, why aren't they being good neighbors? If there is something specific you'd like to see changed, you should suggest it. Assuming they have good intentions, they may want to improve or a mod can decide your suggestion is better for the community. I'm personally in favor of changing that description to explain what bluemix is (I only know because of the StrongLoop acquisition) and removing the "free support"; SO isn't a support tool, it's a community to ask & answer programming questions which employees at company can participate in.

Comment: @ChrisAnderson-MSFT I don't use any of their products so I don't know how it works, but I believe the main issue here is the direction from IBM is unclear what topics can be asked on SO. "*post a question about any item found in the Bluemix product*" is not clear. Whether it's worsen by the tag excerpt, probably, and sure we can fix that, but we can't fix the one on IBM site without telling them the proper way to advertise SO. Compare to, let say, [Google Maps developer support](https://developers.google.com/maps/support/)

Comment: I also voted to close a [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34368150/whitelisting-ips-on-bluemix-secure-gateway) about bluemix that appeared to just be configuration related not programming, there really needs to be some guidance about what is acceptable for SO.

Comment: It's probably make the topic much more clear if they stuck with a description of the product and a link to their support page which could then say what they wanted. I don't think they are explicitly doing anything against the rules in that description; it's just not helpful if you're someone trying to answer a question and don't know what BlueMix is. I don't disagree there can be improvements, only that rules have been broken by the part quoted in OP.

Comment: It'd be great if there was clarification on configuration related questsions. The rules don't say anything specific. Using the Bluemix API correctly may require proper configuration (not sure). If that's the case, is it not a "a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development"?

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253394/third-party-development-support-hosted-by-stack-overflow