# Is [bluemix-mobile-services] a dupe of [bluemix]?

Tags: discussion, tags

Seems like a few questions already tagged as [bluemix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bluemix) are also being tagged with a new tag [bluemix-mobile-services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bluemix-mobile-services). A stack of them came through the edit requests queue with just additional tag added

I'm not sure what the difference is (if any) or if this is just a rebranding by IBM? Do they need synonomising? Or the redundant tag removing? The old tag renaming?

I also suspect that IBM employees are doing this, so may also be worth looking at [IBM Bluemix - confusion about link to SO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/313268/ibm-bluemix-confusion-about-link-to-so)