# When and by whom was [ibm-watson] replaced by [ibm-watson-cognitive]?

Tags: discussion, status-declined, tags, retag-request

I am a developer evangelist for IBM Watson Developer Cloud. There does not appear to be any information here on meta about when or why the tag [ibm-watson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ibm-watson) was retagged to [ibm-watson-cognitive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ibm-watson-cognitive).

This is problematic and breaks the support link used for customer guidance and from IBM's website at https://developer.ibm.com/watson/.

If this retag occured at the request of IBM, please provide a point of contact. If it was not, please retag back to the original [ibm-watson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ibm-watson).

Comment: The oldest question with [tag:ibm-watson-cognitive] was never edited: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21032308/what-is-the-data-format-required-for-input-in-the-ibm-watson-cloud-product

Comment: Who demanded it be ibm-watson in the first place? Or should IBM not just throw it over the wall like that

Comment: The use of the ibm-watson tag and IBM's referral of customers is well within community guidelines and an appropriate use of the site. The tag has been in active use.

Comment: Got a link to any questions where this tag ever existed?

Comment: The tag seems to just be *gone*. It existed still as of last night. I had never seen the ibm-watson-cognitive tag until this morning.

Comment: Found some: https://web.archive.org/web/20160409082619/http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ibm-watson

Comment: Seeing as how [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36504879/watson-stt-java-varying-results-between-websockets-java-and-http-post) was never edited, the tag was either renamed or they both were merged.

Comment: As an example, last night question ID 33271140 was tagged with ibm-watson, not ibm-watson-cognitive. Yesterday, I downloaded a dataset from data.stackexchange.com with every ibm-watson tagged question from the last year.

Comment: It was renamed because the contract expired

Comment: @random it was renamed punitively without regard to how it affects user experience?

Comment: @random How do you know that?

Comment: Is there a documented community guideline that explains the policy concerning tag renaming when "contracts expire"?

Comment: You need to refer to the original contract where it stipulates that SO will maintain the tag wiki naming convention as preferred by IBM

Comment: I believe random's point is that there was never any contract and therefore SO isn't obligated to never rename tags. Which is technically true... but also potentially creating unnecessary friction. I don't know what happened with this specific tag (and personally, I don't see why it'd be renamed but not at least synonymized, etc.), but I'll ping someone to investigate next week.

Comment: The links on IBM's site worked on May 25th, when I wrote [my question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37440293/how-do-i-retrieve-a-list-of-my-corpora-using-watson-developer-cloud-python-sdk),  because I went from their support site to SO. I don't see the tags edited on my question though, so it appears that either I used the cognitive tag, or something changed behind the scenes. Can't verify that either way, but I do know I used the link provided by IBM to get to SO when I asked the question.

Comment: I had no hand in this, but there is potential for things like this to happen when [third parties offload to Stack Overflow](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253394/third-party-development-support-hosted-by-stack-overflow).

Comment: It's worth noting that the [IBM developer page](https://developer.ibm.com/watson/) linked in this question refers to SO as a "developer forum", and groups it alongside what appears to be a SO-esque but more forum-like technical site. Perhaps SO and IBM could exchange favors here: a bit of clarification on IBM's side so their users don't think we're a forum to throw bug reports at, a tag rename on SO's side so IBM can keep their links intact. Obviously not my call though.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart This use case is specifically provided for https://stackoverflow.com/help/product-support. We fully support the spirit of that document: we actively monitor tags, respond, and redirect questions as appropriate.

Comment: @computerfreaker I agree fully and I often redirect users, for example my comment here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36472851/the-conversation-id-specified-either-does-not-exist-or-is-invalid-for-the-id#comment60572146_36472851

Comment: Looks like IBM have updated the website - [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ibm-watson-cognitive?cm_mc_uid=23077963707414653046672&cm_mc_sid_50200000=1465304667) now points to [tag:ibm-watson-cognitive].

Comment: While still calling [so] *"developer forums"* *yuck!*

Comment: If IBM bothered to get a sponsored tag, they could have a cute little icon on the  [ibm-watson] tag. It is unlikely that could be removed ad-hoc.

Comment: We've changed the Watson Developer page (https://developer.ibm.com/watson/) to clarify when to use Stack Overflow and removed the reference to "developer forums."

Comment: This had to be tagged [declined] that day, but wasn't. In the mean time, there was another request by IBM staff to change the synonym direction. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/348039/change-ibm-watson-cognitive-to-ibm-watson. Technically what you have requested is [completed], but since it was decided not to when you had posted the question, I've marked it as [declined].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This change was made at the request of IBM.

Comment: Note: This change was reverted two years later (aka two days ago), at [the request of IBM](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/348039/change-ibm-watson-cognitive-to-ibm-watson).

Answer (score 14):

We're working with IBM on quite a few things. The end goal is to help them structure how they're supporting developers on Stack Overflow more efficiently. When *possible*, it's extremely helpful for them to have a normalized nomenclature for the tags that they're actively working to support on the site.

At the same time, we're helping them ensure that guidance provided when sending folks to Stack Overflow is optimal for the variety of products that they offer where support is currently (and possibly, in the future) being sent to the site. It was initially a quite ... bumpy ... experience for all involved.

We're trying to do this with minimal inconvenience for everyone. That's not *always* possible and we do apologize for any confusion or inconvenience. However, you can count on the `ibm-` nomenclature remaining going forward.

Comment: So you're saying that the tag was renamed by moderators/staff? Can you explain in more detail what benefit this brings? The name of the new tag seems really awkward to me. What was wrong with the old one? It seems really odd that this was done quietly, with no announcement on Meta or even a note on the tag's wiki. People's searches will be broken now and they won't even know why.

Comment: Sounds like the rename was made at IBM's request, to flag the tag as belonging to IBM's [cognitive business](http://www.ibm.com/cognitive/) unit (where Watson belongs).  Expect to see all IBM tags trailed by a unit designator.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Quite a bit, they've been fumbling around a bit with 'watson' being all to encompassing when quite a bit should have been specific to the API, and quite a bit .. well .. just shouldn't have been asked. The tags get remapped internally so we don't break anything, we've now set some synonyms (some had already been suggested in order to fix this) are now in place to prevent some of the not-so-good guidance still out in the wild from making them come back. This was a cleanup effort of around 300 questions that 160 people were following, and has been remapped.

Comment: To be clear, there's a *ton* of more specific tags other than 'watson' or 'ibm-watson' that should be applied to the majority of these questions. I'll update more as we get everyone over there up to speed, guidance corrected in a few more places, and everything finally settled. It's just .. a mess.

Comment: That is a lot of work, maybe they could you know, purchase a tag icon or something to support all of the time the team seems to have invested in helping with their "developer forum" here on Stack Overflow.

Comment: What he said! Please don't take this to mean that I think none of this should have happened. I'm not here to disagree with anything or to stomp on anyone's hard work. It just seems like a lot of pandering has taken place to an unpaying third-party, which goes against the general "line" that we let third parties be third parties and they have to live within _our_ rules if they want to call us their "support forum". And, as such, this seemed like an odd and broad change given that it was unsponsored. But as long as we know what happened, I suppose that's fine.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit You know for a fact they are *"unpaying"*? End of the day there is always going to be a reason SO are *"pandering"* to them. The whole *"Developer Forums"* thing is just dirty, they need telling Tim!

Comment: @Lankymart: Paid tags have icons on them.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit We (occasionally) get a flood of email about off-topic questions where folks trace the origins to third-party sites sending folks to SO in a less-than-optimal way. When we hear about it, we're pretty quick to take action and do whatever's needed to make it, well, optimal. This case isn't really any different than the dozen or so we see each month, except that it's quite a bit bigger. We've done this with Microsoft a few times when the rebranded things and managed to get us some advanced notice. I _think_ IBM is going to be sponsoring some tags, [1/2]

Comment: [2/2] once we finally help them figure out the set that makes the most sense for the site. I'm in contact with them via email now. The end result should be some of their engineers becoming very familiar fixtures on SO through answering questions, some tags being sponsored so folks know it's definitely IBM behind it, and (hopefully) the end to a bunch of pretty off-topic feature requests / bug reports that the ambiguities all around led to. tl;dr - we do this all the time, usually without anyone caring, this was just the biggest instance of it we've seen.

Comment: And as far as the amount of work goes, it's really just janitorial by nature and part of what's involved in providing such a big public space. Occasionally, folks are going to make a mess, and the mops need to come out of the closet. Person-wise, it just takes a few minutes to execute, and about half an hour to sanity check; not a whole lot of time on our part and it helps calm the noise for our regulars as well as helps the new folks have a better experience.

Comment: @TimPost: Ooh, eureka moment - the intention is, effectively, to temporarily break the path between the third-party site and the heretofore-would-be-"abused" SO tag "subsite"? Because that makes sense if so...

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Precisely. Stop the noise on the input lines, reach out and get that corrected, and then tune things so they work as optimally as they can (much like they would have if we had been involved earlier in the effort to send folks here). Many companies don't realize that we offer help to those that want to send folks to SO, I'm thinking about ways to get that message out more clearly.

Comment: @TimPost, a similar problem exists with IBM's tag for "mobilefirst". Please see here: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/355262?noredirect=1

Comment: As a long time user of SO and a major advocate for its use within IBM, I find this entire episode extremely disappointing and will have to reconsider my support. Even if I determine that we should continue to engage, you have made my job significantly harder, providing ammo to everyone who raises a not-invented-here argument. This could have been handled much better.

Comment: @TimPost: Ah. :) I didn't really pick that up from this answer. Perhaps you were just trying to be delicate...