# Change [ibm-watson-cognitive] to [ibm-watson]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request

In June 2016, IBM Marketing worked with Stack Overflow staff to change the [ibm-watson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ibm-watson) Stack Overflow tag to [ibm-watson-cognitive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ibm-watson-cognitive). See [When and by whom was [ibm-watson] replaced by [ibm-watson-cognitive]?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/325536/when-and-by-whom-was-ibm-watson-replaced-by-ibm-watson-cognitive). According to Tim Post's answer, Stack Overflow staff made this change as part of "working with IBM to help structure how they support developers on Stack Overflow." Unfortunately, this IBM marketing effort did not contact the IBM developer community or anybody inside IBM who actually uses Stack Overflow. The Marketing Exec who made the decision was asked to leave the company shortly afterwards.

This tagging has an unexpected consequence. The "cognitive" part of [ibm-watson-cognitive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ibm-watson-cognitive) is a marketing concept and is not intuitive. Because of this, someone (non-IBM) created a new [watson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/watson) tag on 9/21/16 and now the IBM Watson questions are randomly split between the two tags. Within the internal IBM Watson developer community, we would prefer to make [ibm-watson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ibm-watson) the principal tag, and make both [ibm-watson-cognitive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ibm-watson-cognitive) and [watson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/watson) synonyms for it.

Comment: Easy stuff, merge watson into ibm-watson-cognitive. I don't think ibm-watson would be less likely to have this kind of error, since, well we have [tag:ibm]

Comment: Wouldn't changing it to [tag:ibm-watson] break link to SO on the Watson support page (https://developer.ibm.com/watson/)... again... ? Right now it links to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ibm-watson-cognitive.

Comment: @g00glen00b, that's a good point. Once it's clear if/when the tag change will occur, I will follow up with the Watson doc folks to change this link and any other ones they might have.

Comment: @g00glen00b IBM doesn't link to Stack Overflow anymore.

Answer (score -2):

[watson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/watson) wasn't created because people couldn't find [ibm-watson-cognitive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ibm-watson-cognitive), but because tags are separated by spaces, someone just typed [ibm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ibm) [watson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/watson), *voilá*. So, the long term solution would be removing the ibm tag, and merge watson into the [ibm-whatson-cognitive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ibm-whatson-cognitive). That would be the best course of action.

This is what people see when they type watson, with a touch of *my art*:

[image]

Comment: But what about poor Dr. Watson?  Won't this leave him out in the cold? ;)

Comment: Just wondering, why do you think that the tag was created by someone typing "ibm" and "watson"?

Comment: @g00glen00b that's the usual way that those tags gets created, like the example [visual-studio] vs [visual] [studio] in the tag page.

Comment: @cxw Watson has merely failed to realize [the obvious](http://www.sunnyskyz.com/funny-jokes/20/Sherlock-Holmes-and-Dr-Watson-Go-Camping)

Comment: @Machavity I only knew that story in spanish.

Comment: Not sure I believe that somebody was typing [tag:ibm] and [tag:watson] when they created the [tag:watson] tag last September. For one thing, it was a user with 22,931 reputation. For another thing, when you create a new tag, you get a message asking if you're sure you want to do it, which reduces the chances of finger slippage.

Comment: My point about the tags is that [tag:ibm-watson-cognitive] is confusing because it isn't really the name of the technology, but rather something that Marketing wants CEOs to *think* about the technology. So basically I am saying the community would be better served if [tag:ibm-watson-cognitive] defaulted to [tag:ibm-watson].

Comment: I think the [tag:watson] tag was created because all the other related tags use this prefix as well, such as [tag:watson-dialog], [tag:watson-discovery], [tag:watson-conversation], [tag:watson-iot]. I personally think [tag:ibm-watson] is better as well, but I would also pefer all other related tags to be prefixed with ibm-* so that it's clear that they are related.

Comment: @ralphearle I don't know what would be confusing about it? You type watson, you would get ibm-watson-cognitive that says "A collection of REST APIs and SDKs that use cognitive computing to solve complex problems."

Comment: There are different watson things out there that are not IBM Watson. The most famous being Dr Watson Windows debugger. The `cognitive` part is redundant in the tag. So I'd say merge everything to `ibm-watson`. I also like @g00glen00b suggestion of prefixing the others with ibm.

Comment: Very few people facing a technical issue will think about adding 'cognitive' to formulate the ibm-watson-cognitive tag. So they will just tag with 'watson' and the question will go to a queue in which the experts on 'ibm-watson' are not listening. 

Ideally 'watson' would be nice to own, but its not IBM exclusive, so a compromise of ibm-watson works. It doesn't matter if ibm-watson-cognitive is grouped under ibm-watson or the other way round, so long as anyone with a problem can add the tag ibm-watson and the question gets routed to the right group of SMEs.

Comment: @chughts doesn't matter, they will see ibm-watson... and use it.