# Watson wants to get rid of [ibm]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request

*This tag has been burninated. Please do not recreate it. If you need advice on which tag to use, see the answer below. If you see this tag reappearing, it may need to be blacklisted.*

---

Watson's AI evolved to a point where [ibm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ibm) is more of a hindrance than a help, so it wants to let it share the fate of [microsoft](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/microsoft) and [apple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apple).

[ibm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ibm) caused [some discussion](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/348059/misusage-of-ibm) lately, so this is a follow-up to explicitly request blacklisting and [burnination](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/324070/what-is-the-process-for-burninating-tags).

The tag itself is about the company; its excerpt currently states:

> **Use IBM's product name instead, unless you are asking about IBM itself.** International Business Machines is an American multinational technology and consulting firm headquartered in New York. IBM manufactures and sells computer hardware and software, and it offers infrastructure, hosting and consulting services

The problem is, questions about the company are most likely off-topic.

It has 2,700 questions at the moment, but most of them are about specific IBM products, not about the company, e.g. [websphere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/websphere) [ibm-bluemix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ibm-bluemix) [ibm-mobilefirst](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ibm-mobilefirst) [watson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/watson)<sup>1</sup> [ibm-watson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ibm-watson)<sup>1</sup> [ibm-watson-cognitive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ibm-watson-cognitive)<sup>1</sup> ...

So, what to do?

1. Blacklist the tag [ibm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ibm).
2. Close questions about the company as off-topic (not even sure if there are any, didn't find one).
3. Retag questions about any IBM product, creating new tags as needed.

If possible we could do automated retagging to some extent, since many questions already contain a more specific tag, e.g. questions tagged [ibm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ibm)[websphere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/websphere) could just be retagged to [websphere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/websphere), or [ibm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ibm)[watson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/watson) to [ibm-watson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ibm-watson)<sup>1</sup>.

<sub>1: That Watson mess is [another](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/325536/559745) [topic](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/348039/559745).</sub>

Comment: Related: [How to Deal with People Misusing the Visual-Studio and Android-Studio tags](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/346150/how-to-deal-with-people-misusing-the-visual-studio-and-android-studio-tags) as well as [this feature proposal](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/347903/display-a-popup-when-a-low-reputation-user-tags-a-question-with-a-frequently-mis)

Comment: I find this actually pretty funny. Specially for the fact that *"`[watson]` wasn't created because people couldn't find `[ibm-watson-cognitive]`, but because tags are separated by spaces, someone just typed `ibm watson`, voilá"* ([source](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/348081/3889449)).

Comment: @MarcoBonelli I don't believe `[watson]` was created that way. I think it's because all divisions of Watson are only prefixed with `[watson-*]`, like `[watson-conversation]`, `[watson-dialog]`, `[watson-iot]`, ... so it makes sense that people may think that the "parent tag" is `[watson]` and not `[ibm-watson-cognitive]`. But as Floern said, that's probably another mss.

Comment: @g00glen00b that's probably true, but who knows who did it first... lol

Comment: @MarcoBonelli Your source has no source.

Comment: @BrianMcCutchon that was only a link to where I copied the phrase from.

Comment: Rather than relating this to Watson, the main issue is the tag [tag:ibm] serves no purpose even the tag excerpt suggests not using it unless your asking about the company IBM. When on [so] is anyone going to do that and be on-topic?

Comment: Stats at the start of featuring: Q: 115/-4

Comment: Remember that this burn has got 1k+ posts, and therefore if it's decided to burninate, it will be a tag deletion and not post deletion. (Also, I get it that the CB is crowded, but we need to push forward with these. There's a lot of backlog, which we need to complete)

Comment: @g00glen00b that was a elegant assumption. Reality is that it was this question that created the tag https://stackoverflow.com/q/39619629/792066

Comment: What about IBM as a stand-in for the various mainframe platforms? zOS, s360, etc.    Maybe some tags should be mainframe, or something like that.

Comment: @GC_ it is relevant in a programming context where no other existing tag fulfill the same needs?

Comment: I'm getting deja vu, hasn't this tag been up for burnination before? Because I clearly remember making the mandatory lame burninate pun: "Nobody got burninated for picking [tag:ibm]".

Comment: @Lundin IBM has been a bit problematic quite a lot of times https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=ibm

Comment: @Braiam For me, this is like getting rid of windows.  Of course IBM is broad, but it is useful.  Is JVM, IBM or sun?  Are people going to start making tags like IBM-JVM, IBM-cobol, IBM-db2, IBM-chipset, IBM-eclipse?   Remember many people can't tags.

Comment: @GC_ That's a poor excuse. If they aren't able to tag effectively (in the sense that people able to answer will see the question), is because the system doesn't suggest the correct tags, and for suggesting the correct tags a descriptive unique name is necessary.

Comment: @BhargavRao Will Trogdor be devouring this tag soon?

Comment: @EJoshuaS, I've contacted the community managers. The ball is in their court now.

Comment: @BhargavRao Excellent - Trogdor to the rescue again.

Answer (score 25):

[ibm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ibm) has been *burninated*.

[image: trogdor]

Thanks to everyone who participated.

## Observations/Retag Guidance

> <sup>1</sup>: That Watson mess is another topic.

Well, it's tightly linked: the Watson mess is to be clarified if we want to avoid a retagging bump and later a renaming bump.

Let's review the steps needed, by priority:

1. (optional step) A community manager should quickly acknowledge that [current IBM and many users want [ibm-watson-cognitive] to be renamed back to [ibm-watson]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/348039/change-ibm-watson-cognitive-to-ibm-watson). That step would save us from double-retagging in the long run. [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
2. The community will decide whether to burninate or not. [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
3. The community will edit the [ibm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ibm) excerpt and add "*DO NOT USE THIS TAG. Instead use...*", followed by the recommendations from point 5. [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
4. A community manager will hopefully blacklist [ibm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ibm) to prevent people adding the tag and to force people to remove the tag when they edit a question containing it. [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined)
5. The community users will retag [ibm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ibm) posts to:

   - [websphere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/websphere)
   - [ibm-bluemix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ibm-bluemix)
   - [ibm-mobilefirst](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ibm-mobilefirst)
   - [ibm-watson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ibm-watson)
   - [ibm-mq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ibm-mq) IBM MQ related (formerly Websphere MQ)
   - [websphere-mq-ams](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/websphere-mq-ams) IBM MQ Advanced Message Security
   - [websphere-mq-fte](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/websphere-mq-fte) IBM MQ File Transfer Edition
   - [ibm-integration-bus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ibm-integration-bus) IIB (formerly Websphere Message Broker, name is changing to IBM App Connect Enterprise in next version)
   - [ibm-datapower](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ibm-datapower)
   - [ibm-bpm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ibm-bpm) IBM Business Process Manager
   - [zos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/zos) IBM Mainframe
   - [db2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/db2) IBM DB2 Database
   - [informix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/informix) IBM Informix Database
   - [ibm-rad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ibm-rad) IBM Rational Application Developer
   - [ibm-sterling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ibm-sterling) Includes IBM Connect:Direct (used be called and still often referred to as NDM)
   - [ibm-cloud](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ibm-cloud)
   - [cloudfoundry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cloudfoundry) Cloud Foundry is an open source, platform-as-a-service (PaaS) on IBM Cloud
   - [apiconnect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apiconnect) IBM API Connect for IBM Cloud
   - [ibm-rational](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ibm-rational) Current rollup tag for anything related to IBM Rational that doesn't have a more specific tag
6. In the rare occasion where a new product tag is needed, it shall be prefixed with `ibm-` and preferably make sense for at least 10 questions.
7. In the rare occasion of a question on the company itself, community should likely vote to close it as off-topic.
8. **IMPORTANT** If a question is asking for *links to official documentation* they are NOT considered Offsite Resource requests ([Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32094191/ibm-cognos-business-intelligence-10-1-1-with-ie11), per [Shog9 comment](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/43207688#43207688))

## Progress:

The [ibm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ibm) tag is in the process of being burninated. You can help out by reviewing the questions with this tag, and...

- **editing** questions (to improve the question *and* remove the tag),
- **flagging/closing** questions that are duplicates/off-topic/unclear/too broad/opinion-based,
- filtering on this tag in the [Close Vote Queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/?filter-tags=ibm),
- **voting** on questions with this tag,
- voting to **delete** the questions with this tag (after they have been closed, and only if the entire Q&A contains nothing of value). However, keep in mind that at the end of the burnination process all closed questions containing this tag will be deleted automatically. Thus, there's rarely a need to vote to delete these questions.

Here are some quick links to get you started:

- [Open](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bibm%5D+closed%3Ano)
- [Closed](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bibm%5D+closed%3Ayes)
- [Unanswered](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bibm%5D+answers%3A0+closed%3Ano)
- [No Accepted Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bibm%5D+hasaccepted%3A0+closed%3Ano)

### [Track progress of the burnination!](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174431/burnination-progress-for-the-ibm-tag)

[image]

#### Large Tag Guidance

Remember that [ibm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ibm) has more than 3000 questions. Therefore do not go through all of them! Retag the ones which are worth saving (usually the top voted posts) and vote to close the unsalvageable questions (usually the very low scored).

## Remember that burnination is a *clean-up* effort!

#### Salvage whatever possible by editing and re-tagging.

We don't want to destroy value, so salvaging a post should be your first priority. If a question can be saved, please edit it. Your edit should improve *all* problems with the question *and* remove the [ibm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ibm) tag, possibly replacing it with another tag, as described above in "Observations/Retag Guidance".

#### Unsalvageable questions should just be flagged/closed. They don't need to be retagged.

If the question is not appropriate for this site, then don't worry about removing the [ibm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ibm) tag—just flag/close the question it is attached to.

At the end of the burnination process, the [ibm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ibm) tag will be removed from the tag from the system automatically, with minimal disruption.

#### Ask for help if you need it.

If you have any questions about specific questions you come across, or the process in general, please feel free to leave a comment on this post. You can also drop into the [SOCVR chat room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers) for real-time advice and discussion.

Comment: "A moderator will blacklist ibm" moderators doesn't have this power. Only devs and CM's.

Comment: Step 0 should be "The community will decide whether to burninate or not".

Comment: @BhargavRao OK, but how? I noticed that it's not the first time that a burnination process is featured on Meta with 0 answers to the question. So if it's decided by votes on the question itself, it seems already decided.

Comment: [Chemistry] had one answer which mentioned yes, but finally the consensus was no. You never know what'll happen at the end of burnination.

Comment: "current IBM and many users want [ibm-watson-cognitive] to be renamed back to [ibm-watson]" notice that both tags are synonyms, meaning that the system treats them as if they are the same.

Comment: Why all the `[ibm-*]` prefixes. I though most people hate prefixes, as they deserve to be a seperate tag, as per: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/370095/merging-the-excel-vba-into-vba-speak-now-or-forever-hold-your-peace?cb=1

Comment: @Luuklag "I though most people hate prefixes" [citation-needed]

Comment: @Braiam, When I followed that thread it seamed to be the popular opinion.

Comment: @Luuklag the top voted answer is the complete opposite to that perception.

Comment: @Braiam Zoe's answer in the tread makes a good reference then: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/370095/merging-the-excel-vba-into-vba-speak-now-or-forever-hold-your-peace/370147#370147

Comment: @Luuklag https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/226637/213575 ;) Prefixes are necessary. There isn't a inherent hate for them.

Comment: [tag:ibm] cleanup has begun. Let's all clean up the tag for 1 week, after which I'll poke Shog to remove the tag from the system.

Comment: I guess, we should be waiting for a few more days, rather than dropping the axe after 1 week.... It's progressing at a good rate.

Comment: @Machavity How is the link to the Doors discography on Wikipedia an example of on-topic asking for a link to official documentation? Is the Wikipedia page an example of official documentation somebody can ask for a link to? Am I a Blue Meanie if I don't get the joke?

Comment: @AndrewMyers Bah, was a typo. Too many pastes I suppose

Comment: @BhargavRao You stated "At the end of the burnination process, the ibm tag will be removed from the tag from the system automatically, with minimal disruption."  This makes sense, but at some point between then and now the [ibm] tag was made a synonym to the [websphere] tag.  [websphere] is for Websphere Application Server, IBM has many other products.  I don't think the right action is for [ibm] to be a [websphere] synonym.  I'm not sure of how to tell how many questions actually have [ibm] since when I search on that I get all [websphere] questions.  Any suggestions on cleanup?

Comment: @JoshMc, yep. The ibm tag was back sometime [in Feb](https://twitter.com/BhargavHS/status/1235297960617021441). I wasn't aware of the new synonym, I must guess that some users who have enough score in websphere must have gone ahead with that. The best way for you to cleanup now is to create a meta post ([tag:synonym-removal-request]) and detail out the issue with the synonym and ask for it to be removed.

Comment: @BhargavRao Strange that I'm getting this notification, my name isn't JoshMc: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MFvve.png

Comment: It's just nature telling you that you need a name change @Cœur. (https://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/370427/1)