# Merge/cleanup tags [zos], [mvs], [zseries], and [mainframe]

Tags: discussion, retag-request, synonym-request, tag-disambiguation

In going through [ibm] questions for [burnination](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/348131/the-ibm-tag-is-in-the-process-of-being-burninated) I found four tags that appear to all be related to two topics, but usage is mixed across them.

The first two [zos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/zos) and [mvs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mvs) have tag wikis that which indicate that they are the same thing, z/OS is the current name and MVS is a legacy name for an IBM operating system that runs on IBM "Mainframe" hardware.

The tag [zseries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/zseries) indicates it is related to the IBM "Mainframe" hardware itself, but of the 4 questions only 2 appear actually related to differences due to the hardware, 1 is closed, and 1 could have the tag removed.

The tag [mainframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mainframe) also indicates it is related to the IBM "Mainframe" hardware, but in browsing the questions posted it appears many/most of them probably could be re-tagged with [zos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/zos) or another specific IBM product tag, ex: [cics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cics), [db2-zos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/db2-zos), [ibm-mq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ibm-mq), and many others.

---

- [zos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/zos) has 376 questions and 253 watchers

Usage guidance (excerpt)

> z/OS is a 64-bit operating system that runs on IBM's traditional mainframe hardware, also known as System z.

- [mvs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mvs) has 29 questions and 57 watchers

Usage guidance (excerpt)

> MVS is the name for the IBM OS/VS operating system released in the late 1970s, and the name was used through MVS/ESA 5.2. The name was replaced by OS/390 in the mid-1990s, which itself was replaced by z/OS in the early 2000s.

- [zseries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/zseries) has 4 questions and 7 watchers

Usage guidance (excerpt)

> IBM System z is a family name used by IBM for all of its mainframe computers. In 2000, IBM renamed the existing System/390 to IBM eServer zSeries with the e depicted in IBM's red trademarked symbol, but because no specific machine names were changed for System/390, the zSeries in common use refers only to the z900 and z990 generations of mainframes.

- [mainframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mainframe) has 894 questions and 834 watchers

Usage guidance (excerpt)

> The mainframe tag refers to the class of "big iron" computers, primarily those from IBM. Currently this is limited to the System z hardware, typically running zOS as its operating system, zVM, or zLinux.

---

I am not a SME on this subject, but I think the following could help:

1. Tag questions in all four related to z/OS (MVS) to the [zos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/zos) tag
2. Make [mvs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mvs) a synonym of [zos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/zos).
3. Add the wiki information from the [mainframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mainframe) tag to the [zseries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/zseries) tag.
4. Re-tag what is left in [mainframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mainframe) that is hardware/architecture related to [zseries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/zseries).
5. Cleanup anything left in [mainframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mainframe) that is not related to z/OS or the hardware.
6. Make [mainframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mainframe) a synonym of [zseries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/zseries).

Does anyone with IBM Mainframe / zSeries / z/OS / MVS knowledge and experience have any more information to add to this discussion?

---

Per ValerieR's comment i checked and found the following:

- Questions with term [`"z/Linux"`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22z%2FLinux%22+is%3Aquestion) mentioned = 10
- Questions with term [`"z/VM"`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22z%2FVM%22+is%3Aquestion) mentioned = 5
- Questions with term [`"z/VSE"`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22z%2FVSE%22+is%3Aquestion) mentioned = 4

If any of these are programming or scripting related and the above terms would make a difference in the answer then possibly new tags could make sense on Stack Overflow, if they are hardware or operating system related questions they would belong on [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/help/on-topic) not Stack Overflow.

Based on comments it sounds like if there was a tag related to hardware differences in the "mainframe" architecture it would be better to call it `ibm-mainframe` and make [mainframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mainframe) and [zseries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/zseries) as synonym to  the former.  The tag usage/wiki should point out that it would be used only when a programming/scripting question is influenced by the hardware.  Questions about hardware should be asked on Server Fault.

If questions in any of the existing tags are about hardware or administration of the OS can they/should they be migrated to Server Fault?

Comment: My comments on suggestions:

1. Yes, make the tag [zos] for all.  There name of the operating system has changed over the years but in my lifetime it's been MVS/SP, MVS/XA then z/OS.  The primary difference is in the hardware architecture as it moved from 24-bit -> 31-bit and then 64-bit.

2. yes

3. zSeries traditionally refers to the hardware and its associated operating systems (VSE, z/VM, TPF, z/OS, Linux)  Most people use mainframe to refer to zos.  I'd make mainframe a synonym of zos as I strongly doubt we'll see references to non-z/OS environments except for some z/VM questions.

Comment: 4. See above, I'd retag mainframe to zos unless its specifically a hardware question

5. yes.

6. see 3 and 4

Comment: @Hogstrom Thank you for taking the time to comment. As I have seen others often do on his site, I'll make the statement "Sounds like an answer" :).  Also please vote on the question if you think this is a worth wild effort.

Comment: I started doing some tag cleanup as part of the ibm burniate effort.  I was notified that I received a temporary ban because there were too many minor edits.  I assume the ban will get lifted at some point.  Is there something I should put in the comments to note the effort?  I think the reviewers were seeing lots of little fixes and I hate to fatigue them.  Thanks

Comment: I have seen it said on here that less than 2000 rep users should not do tag cleanup since it then causes the need for 2 users to review and approve the minor edit.  Once you hit 2000 rep you can edit with out approval needed.  You could try to flag for moderator one of the posts you edited with a rejected edit and explain what you were doing and see if they can lift the ban.

Comment: A problem with [tag:zseries] is that it was a marketing term for mainframe hardware and IBM changes these.  Mainframe hardware has variously been known as, in IBM parlance, zSeries, zEnterprise, System z, and now (as of this writing) IBM Z.  Having a mainframe tag is independent of IBM's whims and has the advantage of being well understood.  So I would say to reverse 3, 4, 5, and 6 unless you want to revisit this issue every couple of years as IBM changes the name they want to call their mainframes.

Comment: A few extra comments: #1 and #2: Agree, except it would be nice to have zVM, zVSE and zLinus tags too (these are the other mainframe operating systems). #3: I don't like "mainframe" since it gets confused with UI items (lots of windowing systems have a "MainFrame")...I'd be use something like "ibm-mainframe". #4: I think I'd create a term like "ibm-mainframe-hardware" (but more succinct) to clearly separate hardware from software questions (assuming there are any hardware questions these days)...I agree with cschneid that zseries is just a marketing term and might not be best long term.

Comment: @ValerieR Thank you for the comments.  Please vote up the question if you agree this is a effort worth supporting.  I see these types of meta questions typically have people provide answers detailing the type of info that was provided by youself, cschneid and Hogstrom.  What I provided was my initial thoughts but I pinged you all as you have much more knowledge on the subject than I do.

Comment: @Hogstrom A ban? I've made plenty of minor edits. Perhaps a moderator banned you because the burnination effort has not begun yet.