# Huawei - too many tags?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, retag-request

I noticed that there is at least one tag wrong for Huawei.

We have:

- [huawei](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/huawei) - reasonable tag;
- [hms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hms) - stands for "Huawei Mobile Services" and it is an alternative to Google's GMS

and..

- [hms-integration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hms-integration)

  In my humble opinion this tag is unnecessary to use and I am suprised that someone created it.

  [hms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hms) tag should be sufficient for Huawei's problems. There is no Google integration tag and that's why it doesn't make sense to have [hms-integration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hms-integration).

Comment: Actually, the tag that sounds the least reasonable here is [tag:huawei], as it's just describing a company. We tend to burninate company tags (e.g. [apple](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333833/i-want-my-overcooked-apple-pie), [ibm](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/348131/watson-wants-to-get-rid-of-ibm) (although [ibm's been recreated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ibm)), etc.)

Comment: Its fine when it means only one thing.  No need to get an okay, go forth and prosper.

Comment: As I recall I had to have enough points to create tags. Has it changed recently?

Comment: Hi, my personal opinion is that is a bit better to have more tags because they can be more specific, not so general. By the other hand, you have to be careful with the posible duplicated tags. I want to say that maybe one tag could englobe more than one determined area, but this specific areas to applied the tag would have to be perfectly known by the tag's user, for example with a description for that tag with the specific areas that be applied to it. I hope this point of view enjoy and be useful. Thank you very much. And happy codding!. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've synonymised [huawei](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/huawei) and [hms-integration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hms-integration) into [hms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hms).