# Tag [huawei] as a synonym for [huawei-mobile-services] is approiate or not

Tags: discussion, status-declined, tags, synonym-request

[huawei](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/huawei) as a synonym for [huawei-mobile-services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/huawei-mobile-services) is approiate or not

[huawei](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/huawei) is a company name and we should not use it as a tag name. Developers should use [hms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hms) to create a question.

**1.** Huawei Mobile Services (HMS) is a platform from HUAWEI.

**2.** Huawei's business scope includes operator business, enterprise business, and terminal business. Operator business includes 4G, 5G mobile communication services, etc; enterprise business includes routers, data communications, LiteOS Internet of Things, etc; terminal business includes mobile phones, computers, tablets, and smart Watches, smart homes, software ecosystems and other software and hardware businesses.

So we cannot simply count [huawei](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/huawei) and [hms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hms) / [huawei-mobile-services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/huawei-mobile-services) as synonyms. [hms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hms) / [huawei-mobile-services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/huawei-mobile-services) is just a sub-business under the huawei terminal business.

Comment: Huawei is a company and we generally try to avoid tags that are company names.

Comment: @RobertLongson I agree. Maybe we should retag huawei to huawei-phone?

Comment: Forgetting about what Huawei does and whether it has other lines of business separate from HMS, do you have examples of questions where a separate Huawei or Huawei-Phone tag would be relevant and useful?

Comment: Why people keep voting down this discussion? Where is the incorrect part? Can a moderator give me a point?

Comment: People are downvoting it to indicate that they disagree with your request/proposal. It doesn't mean that there's anything wrong with it. You've been given two (very good) answers explaining *why* folks disagree with the proposal.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If [huawei](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/huawei) was not a synonym of [huawei-mobile-services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/huawei-mobile-services), there would be opportunity for people to add it to questions that had anything to do with any of their massive number of subsidiary businesses, one of the reasons we avoid tags of company names.

Given that we don't want [huawei](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/huawei) as a tag on its own we're left with a limited number of choices, given the way tags work on Stack Overflow:

1. We can synonymize the tag with its most commonly used master tag that represents an on-topic subject. In this case, [huawei](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/huawei) was synonymized with [hms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hms), which was later renamed [huawei-mobile-services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/huawei-mobile-services).
2. We can "blacklist" the tag. This is an extreme measure that involves developer time and is rarely invoked.
3. We can rename the tag [huawei-but-only-programming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/huawei-but-only-programming) but I doubt that would help.
4. We can undo the synonymization and add text to the tag excerpt begging people to "not use this tag". This has never worked. [web](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web) has had this guidance for years and continues to be used.

Given the limitations of the tagging system, corporations' diversification of businesses, and human nature, I think we've struck the right balance in naming the tags, for now.

If more questions come in regarding programming some other aspect of [huawei](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/huawei)'s business, we can always revisit the decision.

Answer (score 8):

No, let's not do that.

The [huawei](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/huawei) became a synonym in March due to this request:  [Huawei - too many tags?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394772/huawei-too-many-tags)

And over the years we have removed other company tags like [Apple and Microsoft](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/293754/followup-to-blacklist-the-microsoft-and-apple-tags).

You say:

> we cannot simply count huawei and hms / huawei-mobile-services as synonym

Yes, we can. Tags on Stack Overflow are **NOT**  a strict taxonomy of real world concepts. It doesn't matter Huawei is a company which owns or operates several platforms. What matters is: Will the expert that is going to answer the questions on that subject by watching a certain tag. I doubt we have Apple or Microsoft experts here, nor Huawei experts. We do have experts (and a bunch of on-topic questions) about HMS. And that is a nicely scoped tag for experts to keep an eye on.

Once you find enough questions that warrants to have the Huawei separated again we'll have a new discussion.