# Google are sending YouTube tech support (upload quota) queries to Stack Overflow

Tags: discussion, outsourcing

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42998086/youtube-video-uploads-rejected-before-api-quota-limit-reached) describes a user battling against an upload limit and working their way through Google's seemingly labyrinthine support structures. This strikes me as an obvious support issue that only Google can help with, but the OP was referred to SO before the OP took it back to Google support anyway.

It seems there are some people in Google who want to help ([see the rev history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/42998086/revisions)) and the OP says he knows he was palmed off to an inappropriate channel, but has had little choice but to play hunt-the-tech-support game.

I appreciate there are some support questions that SO members can help with (for example, the answer to this may be that the quota cannot be changed). Nevertheless, it feels like another example where Stack Overflow infrastructure and volunteer time is being abused by a company that can afford to handle customer queries itself.

Is it worth a member of the SO team starting a conversation with YT tech support to see what is going on?

Comment: Where is the message of the rep redirecting them here?

Comment: _"Nevertheless, it feels like another example where Stack Overflow infrastructure and volunteer time is being abused by a company that can afford to handle customer queries itself."_ A company using the Stack Overflow infrastructure and volunteer time is not in and of itself a bad thing, so long as the questions being asked are on-topic and not duplicates.

Comment: @Braiam: in the revision history: "<employee names> from Google have been trying to help but this morning I was palmed off onto Stack Overflow."

Comment: @TinyGiant: that goes without saying, I think, but yes. For the avoidance of doubt, I think that support desk queries are not on topic, because we mostly can't deal with them.

Comment: Unless we have explicit confirmation of this happening and not just hearsay  (a disgruntled user choosing a sloppy phrase), what do you expect to happen?

Comment: YouTube is a big company. If this is the only time this has happened (and we can take the asker at their word), I wouldn't be surprised if this is just a case of an inexperienced support worker making a newby mistake, and it won't happen again.

Comment: I don't know if it's relevant, but YouTube's developer resources links to Stack Overflow sans any advice on how the resource (asking on SO) should be used: https://www.youtube.com/yt/dev/api-resources.html

Comment: Thanks @TiesonT. - yes, I agree that could do with some guidance. Nevertheless, it sounds like in this case, the guidance came from a tech support conversation.

Comment: _"Nevertheless, it feels like another example where Stack Overflow infrastructure and volunteer time is being abused by a company..."_ Don't forget even SoundCloud does it too : [Moving API Support to Stack Overflow](https://developers.soundcloud.com/blog/moving-api-support-to-stack-overflow). Too many companies developing an _"ask at StackOverflow"_ attitude. Don't know if it's just used by companies as a central place (for them) to keep all relevant answers in one place.

Comment: The phrase "a company that can afford to handle customer queries itself" is a bit misleading. Google has a lot of money, but the size of their userbase _far_ exceeds any possible human support system, which is why support for Google's services is basically limited to automated FAQs and help pages. This is becoming increasingly common in an industry where the marginal costs for taking on a single new user and assisting a single new user are both zero.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3, that's interesting commentary, and I see what you mean. However if those zero costs to a third-party service are predicated on palming off account management work onto volunteers, I would object, and I suspect others would too. We can't help with that anyway, as far as I know.

Comment: Yet another case of [Third-party development support: hosted by Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253394/third-party-development-support-hosted-by-stack-overflow).

Comment: Well, we're volunteers. If you don't like the question, don't answer it - don't get too worked up about others who feel differently. As far as I'm concerned, as long as the question fits SO well and has a high enough quality, it's all about the guys who ask and answer. This sounds suspiciously like the early FSF-like claims that for-profit companies should be prohibited from using free software :)

Comment: @Luaan, "If you don't like the question, don't answer it" is a frequent justification for off-topic questions (usually by a disgruntled OP in a comment who thinks there should be no topicality guidelines).

Comment: Sure, no argument there. But part of your argument is "They're trying to save money on support!", and that's entirely orthogonal. *If* the question is a good SO question, let it be. If it isn't, it has nothing to do with who wants to save on support costs - only that it's not a good SO question. Whenever you provide a service of any kind, you should expect people are going to use that service; the only problem here as far as I'm concerned is that *this is not a service provided by SO*. Many questions regarding YT APIs would be perfectly on-topic here and fine questions; this one isn't.

Comment: That was not the purpose of my argument @Luaan - it was that volunteer time should not be abused, which is not the same thing. In any case, it is a minor point in the scheme of things, since the headline is that we can't help with support questions. I have acknowledged the topicality of third-party-related programming questions generally in my comment to ananth, as you will already have seen.

Comment: This is where some shrewd person should contact Google and say "it's okay that you use our site for support issues as long as SO gets a very high rank in Google search results". Which is true for now, but when the Documentation project gets accounted for, the SO rank will go down like a lead zeppelin.

Answer (score -23):

Google  uses the Stack Exchange group of sites to direct support questions for almost all their products (For example see https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/community). While this may be beneficial to Google, I don't think this is **abusing** Stack Overflow, this is actually the right way for corporations to use Stack overflow so that answers to frequently asked support questions can be found by searching here which is what Stack Overflow is designed for.

They even provide links to materials on how to ask good questions in stack overflow, so I think this actually helps the Stack Overflow community grow once those people come and create accounts here. As long as the questions being asked are on-topic, not duplicates and doesn't violate any guidelines, then it actually strengthens Stack Exchange site by increasing our userbase.

Comment: ananth, you have misunderstood the question (and my clarifications in the comments). I am not saying that large tech firms cannot ask people to ask their programming problems here. I am saying that they should not ask us to do their tech support for them, which is a different question.