# SCIP "Contact" page redirects to SO: Expected?

Tags: discussion, support, outsourcing

Seeing [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48261114/2173917), I did a little research and came to know that [SCIP](http://scip.zib.de/), Solving Constraint Integer Programs, mention in their website's "Contact" part:

> We are also watching the SCIP tag on stackoverflow.com and will answer your questions there.

It does not look like "direct" outsourcing, but I'd ask anyway, is this acceptable?

Comment: There's no issue whatsoever with companies redirecting to Stack Overflow as long as they attract on-topic questions. In that case it'd be worth saying something like _"For questions about using the API"_ or whatever. Feel free to contact them to inform them about it.

Comment: @PaulStenne Thought so, however, I have a bit doubt regarding the wording "and will answer your questions there.", this could potentially lead towards many LQ questions (as SO is and would be the most responsive way amongst others mentioned there), this could be changed to something more subtle like "check a collection of existing Q&A in SO, where we are also contributing"...Ideas?

Comment: @PaulStenne also, the problem is with the assumption "as long as they attract on-topic questions". Just wanted to ask for views, anyways.

Comment: I don't think debating of the wording here will yield any result. It'd be best to directly contact the company and tell them something along the lines of _"For your customers to have the best experience on Stack Overflow you should mention that any off-topic question will be poorly received by the community and most likely closed and deleted. (Link to the help center)."_. Then let them come up with whatever wording will work for their customers, they know them better than we do. You can also decide to watch the tag for occurrences of LQ / OT questions if you feel like it.

Comment: Is there a field expert at hand who can decide if that question is salvegable? If only by removing the very first line... Or should we go totally Meta on it, downvote, close, and delete right now? As in "That'll teach 'em!"

Comment: @usr2564301 I do not see the OP's fault in this. Agreed, this is a very LQ post, but OP was likely redirected to SO from the contact page. Edited the question to remove the unwanted part, though.

Comment: @PaulStenne [I found a previous answer stating the same and downvoted to oblivion!!](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/345986/2173917). Strange!! (check the last paragraph of the answer)

Comment: @SouravGhosh There's a critical distinction in that answer: _`"answers to frequently asked support questions"`_. Support questions are definitely bad and off-topic on SO. Technical questions about APIs or whichever are perfectly fine.