# Is there any generic response for questions made about YouTube quota?

Tags: discussion

After checking [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63940895/4092887) and [several others](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=youtube%20quota) related with the YouTube quota, I don't find a generic, aceptable answer for these kind of questions - besides [this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/345986/4092887), but isn't answering the question.

My impression is that, users who ask about quota aren't really informed about the process for asking more quota and neither that those questions can't be answered or solved here.

I would like to know if there are a generic, aceptable answer for this that shows the OP their question can't be answered or solved here, but they have another ways to reach an answer - basically, a good answer for these kind of questions for close these questions as duplicated.

---

Edit: the main goal is to find/build a Q/A pair on SO that can function as canonical duplicate.

Comment: [Quota related questions tend to be customer support and outside of the scope of SO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/why-were-not-customer-support-for-your-favorite-company). Maybe elevate this question to a CM so SE guys speak with Yourtube guys.

Comment: @Braiam I honestly don't understand why you give that advice. What do you expect that SE does? Give Google a call? Tweet them? And then what?

Comment: Questions about YouTube quota should be directed at YouTube.

Comment: @rene you're right: `find a Q/A pair on SO that can function as canonical duplicate`.

Comment: @rene well, that's what the usual SE behavior has been. Or they changed that?

Comment: @Braiam if it blatantly states to ask everything on SO, yes. That is not the problem here.

Comment: Can you summarise here - what is the "YouTube quota"? E.g., quota for what? Is there more than one kind (in this context) - "YouTube quotas"?

Comment: @PeterMortensen The YouTube Data API uses a quota to ensure that developers use the service as intended and do not create applications that unfairly reduce service quality or limit access for others. [Source](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/getting-started?hl=en#quota).

Comment: @rene well, they should be made aware of what are ok questions that they could redirect here. AFAIK, there was a edit on their dev help page (or was their google api?) so it makes sure that their support is first line.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255746/12511801

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is [an existing answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15568405/youtube-api-limitations) that would seem suitable as a reference to many questions about quotas.

There are also bound to be support questions that are simply off-topic here and all we can do with those is close them.