# Reach out to GeoIP about outsourcing their developer support to Stack Overflow

Tags: discussion, outsourcing

As you can see from http://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/legacy/geolite, GeoIP are outsourcing the support of their free product (which has a paid edition) to Stack Overflow.

From [Third-party development support: hosted by Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253394/third-party-development-support-hosted-by-stack-overflow), this really isn't the way they should be handling support.

Is it worth somebody reaching out to their support team (lest we be referred back here!) to flag this up?

Comment: `MaxMind does not provide customer support for free GeoLite databases. If you have questions on how to use these databases, we suggest asking on Stack Overflow.` this seems ok. They are only telling people to come here if they have an issue using it. The wording could probably stand to be expanded to clarify that using means programming only

Comment: *popcorn intensifies*

Answer (score 42, accepted):

The tone of your post suggests there is something improper with a 3rd party out-sourcing their support to Stack Overflow.  In fact, there isn't anything wrong, and there is even [an article in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/product-support) to assist with this.  The best excerpt from the article is the 3rd paragraph:

> Stack Overflow can help support your product but it can't be the only support. There are issues that only you can address, and if you send your users to Stack Overflow for them they'll just get frustrated. Guide your users in where to ask what...

And some further reading from the opposite perspective can be found in [Why we're not customer support for [your favorite company]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/why-were-not-customer-support-for-your-favorite-company)

So back the the tool in question.  The excerpts from [MaxMind's website](https://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/geoip2/geolite2/) for both GeoIP and GeoIP2 say:

> MaxMind does not provide official support for the free GeoLite2 databases. If you have questions about the GeoLite2 databases or GeoIP2 APIs, please see stackoverflow’s GeoIP questions and answers.

and

> MaxMind does not provide customer support for free GeoLite databases. If you have questions on how to use these databases, we suggest asking on Stack Overflow.

It is also repeated on the [contact page](https://www.maxmind.com/en/contact), where additional means of contacting MaxMind are provided, and there is a support contact for customers of the paid products.

In all 3 cases, they indicate that if you have questions on how to use the databases, you can ask on Stack Overflow, which seems consistent with the previously mentioned guidance. The phrasing could be expanded to make it more clear that only programming-related questions are acceptable on Stack Overflow, and non-programming support is not available here.

So I would says that there doesn't appear to be anything incorrect being done here, but MaxMind is doing a disservice their users (of their free databases) by not providing more specific guidance, but perusing the [geoip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/geoip) tagged questions, there doesn't appear to be a lot of non-programming support questions (unless they are deleted quickly), so I don't see a huge issue with bad questions getting dumped on the site.

Answer (score 11):

Almost all questions are product related on products that are build by bigger companies. GeoIP is just referring to Stack Overflow as site to get community support. It is a suggestion to go there if you have any questions. This channel works when there is a community that uses GeoIP or they monitor Stack Overflow to answer GeoIP questions. If the questions and answers are low quality, wrongly tagged etc. The community will remove them (questions and answers) from Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

I found this presumptuous and sneaky the first 100 times I saw companies do it, then I realized it's actually win-win.

Needlessly to say, it's beneficial for the company because they don't have to try to afford providing technical support to a potentially large scale group of users/developers.

OTOH it's also beneficial for StackOverflow, because it's simply increasing membership and activity here. It is what we're here for afterall - technical question and answers for programmers who get stuck while they're developing. So, it

1. increases StackOverflow's visibility (i.e. free advertising),
2. grows SO's size, and
3. creates yet another potentially valuable corporate partner who depends upon SO.

The guys who work at SO-the-corporation probably love it and as a contributor I have no problem with it.

Comment: Stack Overflow doesn't really *need* free advertising at all costs anymore, and it doesn't need growth when that growth consists mainly of off topic question askers. We don't have a problem with companies pointing folks to SO - they're welcome to do so. But it's a problem when they make it look like SO is the place for *any* question you might ask their customer support. That's bound to lead to bad experiences all round. This is arguably a relatively benign case, though.

Comment: @Pekka웃 I appreciate your concern. What's the cost though? Dozens, if not hundreds, of companies already do this and IMHO it's been successful thusfar. The people they are sending us are *developers* after all. Like almost everyone, they initially come to StackOverflow to find an answer to their question, but they may go on to frequently answer questions in the same or different tags.

Comment: `IMHO it's been successful thusfar` I'm less convinced. There have been huge problems with companies sending everyone and their dog here, there's plenty of complaining about it here on Meta. Again, it's no problem for companies to send developers here who ask specific, on topic-questions about X product. The problem is companies that are so vague in their instructions that *end users* think they should ask questions here. (I don't think the "we're getting new members this way" argument holds a lot of water - every developer under the sun is bound to already know about Stack Overflow.)

Comment: IMHO = in my humble opinion. I'm to provide a citation for my opinion?

Comment: Well, something to back it up *would* be helpful - as said, I've seen many reports of problems with companies doing this (and closed questions from new users as a consequence) here on Meta. Anyway, it probably doesn't matter what we say - there are clear on-topicness guidelines on SO and when companies are too vague in their "go to Stack Overflow" instructions, the SO team is likely to reach out and ask them to change the wording a bit.