# Clean up the [sony] tag: Is it useful at all, or should we re-tag and clean up?

Tags: discussion, status-declined, tags, burninate-request, retag-request

The [sony](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sony) tag, despite being used on 743 posts, isn't a great one. Besides informing us that there is something related to a brand in the question, it doesn't tell us a whole lot. [An earlier issue has been raised](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251164/) about allowing Sony as a tag, while this is discouraged or even disallowed for other brands. But that doesn't really matter all that much, given that there doesn't seem to be a need for the tag.

Going through the questions tagged [sony](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sony) there are several patterns, largely due to [Sony's own recommendations](https://developer.sony.com/support/how-to-post-tag-a-question/):

- Questions are tagged both [sony](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sony) and [smartwatch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/smartwatch) on [on 142 occasions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sony+smartwatch). That might very well indicate that a tag like [sony-smartwatch] would be a decent alternative. So how about we create that and clean up those posts?
- Then [there are 39 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sony+camera) with a [sony](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sony) and [camera](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/camera) tag (or something similar). While some are off-topic/closed, several of them are related to the [Sony Camera Remote API](https://developer.sony.com/downloads/camera-file/sony-camera-remote-api-beta-sdk/). But we have a tag for those it seems, namely [sony-camera-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sony-camera-api). So let's clean those up as well.
- While Sony recommends the use of the [sony](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sony) tag in combination with the [google-tv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-tv) tag for their Sony Google TV Add-on SDK, there are only [4 posts with that tag combination](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sony+google-tv), and I'm not entirely sure they are about that SDK at all. (Though a Sony representative seems to have minimally answered in two). To propose a new specific tag for that one might be overkill. Perhaps general cleanup would suffice there?
- A lot of remaining questions simply are tagged [sony](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sony) because OP is using a Sony device for their development. In the cases I've seen, I didn't find a specific relevance for the tag, and a statement in the question itself would suffice.

I'd love some input here. Is the [sony](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sony) tag useful at all? Is there a reason for it to exist that I might have missed? Do the changes I mention above make sense, or would there be other ideas/alternatives?

Comment: I think getting Stack Exchange to talk to them first and getting them to change that all to Sony-prefixed tags would be a very polite thing to do, rather than just going in and changing it all around on them.

Comment: I would certainly not be against something like letting the tag sponsorship expire (or something similar) before cleaning up @animuson. I'm not that evil. ;)

Comment: Well, as long as all of the moderators and the community team agree that it's ok as long as Sony really wants crap tags, I guess we should all learn to love it.

Comment: "and I'm not entirely sure they are about that SDK at all" -- the two that also have `[tag:android]` are related to SONY's Google TV boxes. The other two are related to SONY's own line of "smart TVs". Since AFAIK SONY has exited the Google TV business, I doubt that setting up a dedicated tag for SONY Google TV questions would be worthwhile. Note that `[tag:sony]` is listed on the `[tag:android]` wiki; I'll be happy to fix that if somebody lets me know when tag changes are being made.

Comment: See also [Third-party development support: hosted by Stack Overflow](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253394/third-party-development-support-hosted-by-stack-overflow)

Comment: @animuson: It should be community driven. Is there some sort of contract here we are not aware of?

Comment: It is currently a sponsored tag @staticx. Getting rid of it while they have paid for sponsorship is ... well, funny ... but not really desirable.

Comment: @Bart: I don't think it's funny. I just think that if SO has a site to run mostly by the community, it should make sense.

Comment: @staticx It's not even so much about the sponsorship. I'd rather not completely break a very large company's system that they built without even giving them a chance to change it to match the tags we desire. That's a pretty big slap in the face.

Comment: Yeah, and this is not exactly an urgent issue either.

Comment: However we handle the issue, we should probably do something similar [with other wayward](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/microsoft) [company tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apple).

Comment: This seems more like a need for a meta-tag.  `[sony-camera]` tag should be tagged `[sony]`!  Meta-tags would be illegal to use on their own (you are given a selection of member tags to choose from instead), but `[sony]` can still filter on the meta-tag (for their own purposes).  That would also open up a route to fix `[microsoft]`, where it would be marked as a meta-tag on `[excel]` etc.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

This is surprisingly complicated...

"Company tags" like [microsoft](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/microsoft) or the now-defunct [google](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google) were clearly useless or wrong in most situations: tag sets like [javascript google chart] and [vba microsoft excel] were classic examples of someone trying to type out a product name complete with spaces and getting tripped up by the way tags are parsed, while in many other instances the tag was just redundant: [visual-studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/visual-studio) doesn't really need a tag to indicate who makes Visual Studio, nor does [android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android) need one to indicate *its* owner.

*Some* uses of [sony](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sony) fall into the same category: [sony](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sony) + [sony-camera-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sony-camera-api) is clearly redundant, while [sony](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sony) + [smartwatch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/smartwatch) is less obvious until you realize that (contrary to the tag wiki) [smartwatch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/smartwatch) actually refers to a specific Sony API in nearly every case - that tag should just be renamed to [sony-smartwatch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sony-smartwatch) and the tag wiki updated accordingly.

...Then we start getting into the weeds. Remember how we don't need a maker tag on [android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android)? Well, how *do* we refer to Sony's flavor of Android then? It's sure as hell not [sony-android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sony-android). There's an [xperia](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/xperia) tag that's used to refer to Sony's line of smartphones - we could rename that to [sony-xperia](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sony-xperia) (and then add it to the 100 or so questions regarding Xperia that don't currently have it but do have sony)...

...this would just leave us with a tag that sometimes refers to issues with specific software, others with issues on specific hardware, and still others neither - the asker just happened to be using an Xperia phone for doing generic Android development.

Alternately, we could focus on specific APIs for the software aspects: [sony-small-apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sony-small-apps), [sony-camera-add-on](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sony-camera-add-on), [sony-android-ir](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sony-android-ir)... Some of these are getting pretty obscure though. Remember, there are under 400 questions in the [sony](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sony) tag: there's only so much subdivision possible.

That's why I was fairly dismissive of this issue [the last time it came up](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251164/why-is-sony-a-good-tag-when-apple-and-google-arent) - it's just not that big of a problem. Heck, there are more questions tagged [htc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/htc), and even more tagged [samsung-mobile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/samsung-mobile) - and near as I can tell, those tags are even more devoted to hardware-specific issues, the developer equivalent of tagging your question [dell] [over on Super User](https://superuser.com/tags/dell).

**So all that being said, here are my recommendations:**

- Rename [smartwatch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/smartwatch) to [sony-smartwatch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sony-smartwatch) and update the wiki to reflect its true purpose (**Done!**).
- Rename [xperia](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/xperia) to [sony-xperia](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sony-xperia) (**Done!**). Maybe add it to *some* of [the hundred or so questions where it's possibly relevant but doesn't currently exist](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bsony%5D+-%5Bxperia%5D+xperia).
- Do *nothing else*. See if usage of those two tags picks up a bit. The [sony](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sony) tag is pushing *six years old* at this point, and one person could still remove it in an afternoon if it became necessary - I'm more interested in encouraging better tagging for the future than I am in worrying about a few hundred questions with a *slightly* too-broad tag on them.

BTW: I don't think any of this affects Sony's sponsorship of the various related tags, but I'll send this post along to the folks who handle that just so everyone is in the loop.

Comment: Personally, I don't how burninating eg. the [tag:apple] & [tag:samsung] tags would help people with general programming problems that apply to multiple products of that company. When considering situations where a programming question may apply to eg. all apple operating systems or all samsung mobile devices, allowing only more specific tags would result in less exposure of the question and therefore a reduced likelihood of getting your question answered. How is that progress?! —— See also [**my answer here**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/350753/1946501)

Comment: @John, since SO's topic is questions about using software technologies, it's only natural that they are tagged with the technologies rather than any related entities. If a question relates to a family of technologies, there are e.g. version-independent ([tag:ios]) or language-independent ([tag:confluent-kafka]) tags. If a question relates to so many technologies that even top-level tags don't fit into the 5 tags limit, it's definitely too broad.

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev : Even very specific questions can benefit from having tags that cover a broad range of topics, because it helps attract experts who have a broad expertise within that specific range. IMO, it's best to always use tags that have different levels of specificity, ranging from very high level (eg. [tag:javascript] or [tag:http]) to very low level (eg. [tag:react-router] or [tag:react-redux]).

Answer (score 10):

I've just run out of close votes after reading through all the recent [sony] questions. Before I ran out of close votes for the off topic questions I did not find *even one* good question. The tag seems to be full of garbage. I recommend blacklisting it.

Answer (score 1):

It is ridiculous that this was declined and this ought to be revisited, since the policy for company tags nowadays is probably much more strict than it used to be back in 2014. Similar arguments can be raised against pretty much any company tag which in combination with some other tag would then form a "meaningful combination".

[sony](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sony) is clearly a company tag. Good tags are named "sony-whatever" for *products* by that company. They should also be products that can be programmed, are programming tools or come with an API, or otherwise one might wonder if the tags can be justified.

Burnination criteria:

- > Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?

  It is ambiguous. Sony make a lot of diverse products that could be programmed or have an API.
- > Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?

  No, "company names" is not a topic for this programming site.
- > Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?

  No, since the tag is ambiguous and could mean a lot of things. Typical misuse would be to tag according to what a question *contains* instead of correct use, what a question *is about*.
- > Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?

  No.