# Is the "The Death of Meta Tags" finished?

Tags: discussion, tags

I have stumbled upon the [sap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sap) tag, thinking it was quite useless. It seems that the subject of company tags has already been discussed:

- *[Let's remove the [jetbrains] tag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254250/lets-remove-the-jetbrains-tag)*
- *[Is adding company name tags spam/vandalism?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253840/is-adding-company-name-tags-spam-vandalism)*

And in the Stack Overflow blog post *[The Death of Meta Tags](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/08/07/the-death-of-meta-tags/)* from 2010.

So now I see that there is no tag for Google for example, and the [apple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apple) tag was also removed, previously having a nice warning "DO NOT USE THIS TAG!!!".

Why does this tag still exist? Why not delete it?
How about a new company tag being created or used? What should be done?

I feel that the work has been started, but not finished. Am I missing a part of the story?

Comment: Odds are it did end up getting deleted, but someone else was hungry so they re-created the apple.

Comment: Does SO able to block the recreation of deleted tags?

Comment: Yes, they can blacklist them so they never come back.  There is even a tag on meta for blacklist requests.

Comment: Removal of such tags must be done by the community (for the most part), and it is a rather mundane task (read: so boring you would probably get more enjoyment out of dripping scalding hot bacon fat on your own eyes), so it generally takes a long time. The time it takes is directly related to how many questions a given tag has, and many other factors. The point being that the work did start and the is a lot of unfinished work left to do.

Comment: Ok so I can feel free to remove all company tags that I find?

Comment: No. You should first check to see that there is a burnination request for that tag. If there is, check the consensus and follow that. If there is not, create a new one, and wait for consensus.

Comment: Related: [How should we make tag blacklist requests?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239189/how-should-we-make-tag-blacklist-requests/239192#239192)

Answer (score 3):

I'm not convinced tag burnination is a good approach should for companies where no product exists that has the name of the company, but where the company name is often used as an - unofficial - reference to one or more products of the same company.

A good example for that would be [sap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sap), which you mentioned yourself. As I explained in my answer to the question [What are ABAP and SAP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1753412/what-are-abap-and-sap/36399835) :

> [...]
>
> Although SAP ERP isn't
>   the only software sold by SAP, people are typically refering to SAP
>   ERP when they say "*they're using SAP at work*". It's important to
>   note, though, that SAP is the name of the company and no software is
>   sold or licensed as just "*SAP*".
>
> [...]

I agree that it would make sense to burninate the [sap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sap) tag in analogy with the [apple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apple) & [microsoft](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/microsoft) tags and replace it with product specific tags like [abap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/abap), [bapi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bapi), [netweaver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/netweaver), [sap-erp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sap-erp), etc. However, this may confuse eg. ABAP programmers and leave them puzzled on which tags to use in one of two situations :

- Their question involves [sap-erp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sap-erp), but they don't think about using that tag as they're used to just calling the product [sap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sap) (like almost everyone does)
- They have a general SAP-related programming question that doesn't refer to any specific SAP product

Note that this second situation doesn't apply only to companies where no product exists that has the name of a company. As I - just - commented [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333833/should-we-burninate-the-apple-tag/350605#350605) :

> Personally, I don't how burninating eg. the [apple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apple) &
>   [samsung](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/samsung) tags would help people with general programming problems
>   that apply to multiple products of that company. When considering
>   situations where a programming question may apply to eg. all apple
>   operating systems or all samsung mobile devices, allowing only more
>   specific tags would result in less exposure of the question and
>   therefore a reduced likelihood of getting your question answered. How
>   is that progress?!

I raised this issue earlier today in the form of the question [Should we burninate [sap]?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/350750/should-we-burninate-sap). Someone pointed out that my question and your question are related (pretty closely actually), which is how I ended up here.

Anyway, I basically don't think it's a good idea to burninate tags like [apple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apple) or [microsoft](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/microsoft) because they're useful in cases that involve multiple products of the same company. In case of the [sap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sap) tag there's also the fact that the name `SAP` is often used as a reference to `SAP ERP` or one of its predecessors, which is an extra argument for not burninating it.

However, that's just my very personal opinion. I guess it's up to the community to decide, and there's now [an official burninate request](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/350750/should-we-burninate-sap) for the [sap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sap) to set things in motion if the community agrees upon burnination.