# Should we burninate [nokia]?

Tags: discussion, status-declined, tags, burninate-request

[nokia](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nokia) is a company, and in line with the recent burninations of [apple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apple) and [microsoft](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/microsoft), and [htc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/htc) I propose that we burninate it.

Addressing [the points Shog9 makes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/239191):

- > Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?

  Well, it sort-of describes the contents and it's mainly unambiguous.
- > Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?

  No, as it is a company, not a programming-related product.
- > Does the tag add *any* meaningful information to the post?

  Clearly not.
- > Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?

  Yes.

The tag wiki just states that it is a company that makes telephones and reads like a company promotion one-liner. Nothing programming related there.

I therefore propose that [nokia](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nokia) be burned from all [718 questions which are currently tagged with it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xSU87.png).

*This has been suggested before as part of [a longer list of company names which can be burninated](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/295660/5211833)*

Comment: Hmm… Looking at the first few questions that currently have that tag, I'm not sure I agree with this burnination request. There are questions specifically about Nokia phones and SDKs, and it seems proper to have those questions tagged [nokia]. ([This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42489241/is-there-any-sdk-for-the-new-nokia-3310) is just one example.) What else would you propose we tag them with?

Comment: Some of the questions regarding maps should be tagged with [tag:here-api]. Company called "Here" was [bought by Nokia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_(company)#Acquisition_by_Nokia)

Comment: There is also a thing called Nokia Imaging SDK - see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23028762/crop-an-image-in-nokia-imaging-sdk-1-2)

Comment: @VadimKotov a couple years ago it was sold again, to car manufacturers.

Comment: @CodyGray we can create a [Nokia-SDK], or whatever the official name for its SDK is, for SDK usage, which fits better in my opinion. If people want to keep the tag, it needs a solid rewriting of both excerpt and usage, to make it reflect what it's actually about. I do have concerns about misuse though, same as with [HTC] apparently being HTML-components as well. Are enough of the [nokia] tagged questions specific enough for Nokia phones, or is the majority of the questions about general app-development which happens to be on a Nokia model?

Comment: I don't see what problem it solves to append "-SDK" to the name. We have a [windows] tag. It doesn't need an "-SDK" wart. Again, a tag wiki edit is a completely separate project from a burnination request.

Comment: @CodyGray The problem it might solve is people tagging their general question [nokia] because they happen to own one of their phones and want it working on there, despite that being irrelevant to the question, same as tagging the question as well with [samsung], [htc], [lg] and whatever phone brands exist. Questions about app development specific for nokia phones can then have a tag which has a much lower amount of questions that should not have the tag, thus keeping the new tag much more focused than a broad company-name tag.

Comment: I propose this moves to a tag disambiguation, like sony tag.

Comment: @Cody Gray: But hardly anyone asks questions about the Windows SDK, and the vast majority of [windows] questions are questions about developing on the Windows platform, regardless of what SDK is being used (if at all). The [nokia] tag could easily be mistaken to mean, as Adriaan says, just anything involving a Nokia(-branded) product. Renaming it to [nokia-sdk] would reduce the number of misuses of the tag - assuming it was always intended for SDK-related questions.

Comment: @BoltClock Um, what? Hardly anyone asks questions about the Windows SDK? I see and answer a lot of them. If a question has a tag, but the tag is not germane to the question, then the tag should be removed from that question. This is nothing new; it's how *all* tags work. Just like when you put a [visual-studio] tag on a question about C# that has nothing to do with the IDE. The tag should simply be removed from the offending question, not *burninated*. I see no evidence that appending "-sdk" to a tag decreases misuse. Look how frequently, say, [tag:google-drive-sdk] is misused.

Comment: @CodyGray then, as you say "the tag is not germane to the question", I hardly see any tag germane to nokia, the company, as on topic, ever.

Answer (score 13):

[Quoting the rest of #2](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239190/when-to-burninate/239191#239191):

> Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?
>
> This is kinda self-explanatory; Stack Overflow doesn't need a kittens tag, at least not until someone releases a hot new framework and names it "Kittens". All that a blatantly off-topic tag is gonna do is encourage blatantly off-topic questions, so removing it is good for everyone. Just be sure and do your homework: the last thing you want is to start removing tags only to be attacked by a bunch of angry kitten.js users.

The problem here isn't that Nokia is off-topic; it's that - as usual with company tags - there's more than one specific on-topic thing associated with Nokia.

IOW, it's kind of a broad tag. That's not really a *big* problem though; there are only 700-some questions in it.

The bigger problem is that there are often no more specific tags that can be used, *nor are there likely to be*. This is almost exactly the same problem with [getting rid of the sony tag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253528/clean-up-the-sony-tag-is-it-useful-at-all-or-should-we-re-tag-and-clean-up/254124#254124) - we're never going to create new tag for every model of every thing Sony kicks out. To riff on Cody's comments, it'd be like getting rid of [windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows) and [winapi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/winapi) in favor of a tag for every past or future Windows SKU... (Except, it'd be worse since there are probably more Nokia SKUs and certainly a lot fewer questions about them).

Quoting myself again...

> If it looks like pointless busywork, it probably is pointless busywork...

See also: [Should we burninate [sap]?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/350750/should-we-burninate-sap)

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. The point that at this moment the tag is a mess remains however; it's excerpt is rubbish, there's no wiki and a lot of questions tagged with it don't need the tag. Should we try and fix those things? I'd love to do it, but I haven't seen any Nokia-specific feature here and since I'm not familiar with the techniques involved I can't do much except retag questions.

Comment: If you're so motivated, suggest edits to the wiki and retag questions. Otherwise, focus on areas where you feel you can do more good. Avoid frittering away your day removing a tag you don't care about from questions you also don't care about; that tends to not lead to good results.