# Get rid of google tag

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, retag-request

[google](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google) tag has no questions, no wiki and no synonyms.

Can we get rid of it? [google](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google) sounds like a much too broad tag and I see no reason for it to exist.

Comment: it appears to be a stuck tag. If the system doesn't clean it up automatically, the short answer is no. Tags cannot be manually deleted

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This tag (along with many other tags created on draft Articles) has now been cleaned up.

As indicated in the comments, this was one of several tags that was "stuck" due to being on a draft Article. There were a few issues involved here; originally, Article drafts allowed authors to create tags without needing the [create tags](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/create-tags) privilege or preventing blocked tags from being added; in addition, the tags would not be cleaned up by the system automatically, because they were present on Article drafts and could not be removed by anyone without editing permissions on those Articles.

The Collectives team recently went through and did a cleanup of tags created on Article drafts. I worked with the mods to get lists of the affected tags, and shared them with the Collectives team for cleanup; in all, we deleted about 79 tags. The reputation requirement is also now being enforced for tag creation via Articles, as is the blocklist. The Collectives team is also working on making changes to the Article draft process to prevent this sort of problem in the future.

Thank you all for your patience!

Answer (score 4):

You have not stated your reasons to get rid of this tag. Anyway, it apparently has been sitting that way for a while. From [Zoe's comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421553/get-rid-of-google-tag/421554?noredirect=1#comment934621_421554):

> No, I mean they've identified the cause of the bug that prevents tags, including this one, from dying. This was months ago, and I was told there was a developer on it, but that it wasn't clear if it'd be fixed. Months later, it's clear that it won't be. Fixing the bug preventing the tags from being deleted just means fixing the reason they're identified as having a single question when they clearly don't, which lets the system do its job again. That's not happening any time soon, if at all

Related

- [Is adding company name tags spam/vandalism?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/253840/1595451) from 2014
- [Is the "The Death of Meta Tags" finished?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/346273/1595451) from 2017

---

According to the tags page, [google](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google) has 1 question.

[image]

According to the tag popover, [google](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google) has 3.8k watchers and one question.

[image]

Comment: "Anyway, if it have been sitted that way for a while then only a develper could remove it." - no, because devs can't remove the tags either. Devs can _blacklist_ tags, but that doesn't make the tag go away. It's a [stuck tag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/417362/6296561), so it won't go away ever. I've been informed the problem has been identified, but it appears we're not getting devtime on it, sooooo

Comment: Sorry, I'm confused... do you mean that they can but we haven't devtime ? if they can't why do we need to get devtime for this?

Comment: No, I mean they've identified the cause of the bug that prevents tags, including this one, from dying. This was months ago, and I was told there was a developer on it, but that it wasn't clear if it'd be fixed. Months later, it's clear that it won't be. Fixing the bug preventing the tags from being deleted just means fixing the reason they're identified as having a single question when they clearly don't, which lets the system do its job again. That's not happening any time soon, if at all

Comment: Side question: Maybe a week ago, I stumbled upon a new question regarding [Google Routes API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/routes) (a new Google API) which was only tagged with [tag:google-maps] so I created the [tag:google-routes-api] tag, added a wiki and tagged the question with the new tag, and today, it's gone. Why is that?

Comment: @MrUpsidown because that _isn't_ a stuck tag. The normal process is that tags without any questions is removed automatically at 3:00 UTC. Something happened to the question that made the tag (or the question, and tag by extension) disappear. I cannot be more specific than that, because I have no idea where the question is, and I don't feel like digging for it

Comment: @ZoestandswithUkraine I felt like digging for it. The question is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74016242/google-maps-route-api-differences-with-directions-api). It got deleted by Community Bot. Now... Google Routes is a new API, I am pretty sure there *will* be future questions. I took the time to create the tag and to write a wiki. But all is gone. So in other words, we have useless, incomplete tags that remain alive for whatever technical reason, and useful, complete tags that get deleted without notice and any clear (visible) reason...