# Reach out to Sony

Tags: discussion, outsourcing

Sony seems to be outsourcing their support for their SDKs to Stack Overflow. Re: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51087927/how-to-apply-the-sonny-sdk-api-from-c-code

From their site:

> Support from Sony engineers at Stack Overflow
> If you have questions during development, you can scan Stack Overflow for answers, or post a question yourself. Sony engineers scan Stack Overflow daily for new questions. Check out the Support page for details.

and

> It’s easy to get developer support from Sony! Sony uses the strength of the StackOverflow forum and community to provide support for developers who are using Sony APIs. A team of Sony engineers scout Stack Overflow daily for new questions, and we take pride in helping third party developers as much as we can.
>
> When you post a question to Stack Overflow, be sure to tag it as being related to the Camera Remote API, to make sure a Sony engineer finds it and responds. To do this:
>
> 1. Go to Stack Overflow and write your question
> 2. Use this tag to highlight your question: sony
> 3. Post your question

Can we have a community representative contact them to clean this verbiage out.

Comment: Related https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/253528/792066

Comment: BTW, sony tagging recommendations are no more.

Comment: @Braiam huh? i dont get your last comment

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/why-were-not-customer-support-for-your-favorite-company

Comment: When Shog decided not to obliterate the tag, the guidance provided on Sony's part had some weight in the decision.

Comment: "strength of the StackOverflow forum" hehe... Well yes technically Stack Overflow is a forum, but if they write this, people are going to think it's a Discussion Forum which is the main kind of forum that jumps to people's mind when they see the word, which [Stack Overflow explicitly is not](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). I'd be fine with them just stripping the words "forum and" so it just says the "Stack Overflow community," or specifying with other words the strength of the questions and answers at Stack Overflow without calling it a forum.

Comment: Sony is doing what they promised, it is not just some webby company that leaves their api users without support whatsoever.  mldeveloper looks like he changed his job last year, Robert is actively participating today.  No, he's not going to answer crap like that, nobody does.  I had personally no idea he was actually talking about Sony software when I voted to close :)  Sonny, wtf.

Comment: It's all because Sonny is using [tag:Flash] and has [tag:zombie] issues: https://armorgames.com/play/505/sonny

Answer (score 9):

There's enough in [Sony's own verbiage](https://developer.sony.com/develop/cameras/support/) and utter lack of guidance that would justify a CM reaching out, but in reality...this was just a bad question. This person doesn't know what an SDK is so the very, very harsh reality is that this person isn't the target audience for Sony's SDK.  The only thing that would be justified for this question is closure and deletion.

Comment: So you're saying you agree with the general idea of the post but you don't think this question shouldn't be used as an example, if I understand well?

Comment: Pretty much, yeah.  The verbiage is bad on Sony's part.  The question posted doesn't feel like it's off topic *because* of their poor guidance, but rather *in spite* of it.

Comment: Resembles the US Supreme Court. Shut it down because it doesn't quite qualify. Would some guidance be possible in this case that would let the asker make the question valid? Or is it just not one that can be tweaked?

Comment: We are burniating IBM but leaving Sony, baah I hope they pay well, maybe we could ask IBM for some cash and avoid looking at 3K questions?

Comment: @PetterFriberg IBM has nothing to complain, there will still be a large pile of tags with their company name in it. Sony, only a handful.

Comment: @Gimby I was more into a blackmail thingzzz, pay as Sony or we burn it! :P