# The [visa] tag is commonly misused

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-disambiguation

The tag for [visa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/visa) seems to be misused rather often, Is there anything that can be done to help reduce confusion about this tags meaning?

Perhaps the fact that a [mastercard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mastercard) tag does refer to the credit card adds to the confusion as [visa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/visa) does not, it refers to "virtual instrument software architecture" as stated in the tag info.

> VISA stands for Virtual Instrument Software Architecture. It is a communication and I/O standard for instrument communication, mainly used in the test & measurement industry. DO NOT USE this tag for the payment card Visa, nor for a travel visa related question.

At the time of writing this, 1 of the 6 newest questions tagged [visa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/visa) is correct use of the tag:

[image]

I have since removed the tag from these questions, but looking through older ones I still see more [payment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/payment) and [mastercard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mastercard) tags being used, indicating those questions probably shouldn't have the [visa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/visa) tag

Comment: Well what else than the clarification in the tag wiki should be done about that? If you see it's used wrongly in a question post, edit it out, and leave an appropriate edit comment, or comment on the post, to explain the OP they used it wrong.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ - probably would be a good idea to create a tag like [visa-card] or [visa-payment]. At the very least we should rename the correct [visa] to something else (idk, something like [visa-architecture] should do). The tag as it currently stands is screaming "misuse me"

Comment: @OlegValter Good idea.

Comment: @OlegValter with those changes does that mean the [visa] no longer exists? Or is it a synonym to one of the tags? If it is gone how do you prevent it from being made again as a synonym?

Comment: Does visa have an api? Those questions don't look api-y at all

Comment: @Nifim - no longer exists - I think it is not a good idea to keep it around, it will inevitably lead to questions being mistagged. Although I won't mind it existing as a synonym of a tag for the payment system because I think those that are asking about VISA usually know what they are doing.

Comment: Briam's [tag:visa-api] looks good to me as well

Comment: @OlegValter I agree, if it were to stay around it should be used for the payment context, while I may have looked into the tag because of the visa the architecture I can admit it is less widely known and the tag would be much less likely to be misused if it referred to the payment.

Comment: @Braiam - seems like they have a set of APIs: https://developer.visa.com/. I like the [visa-api] idea (but probably we should make a tag for each of the APIs - [tag:google-api] turned out to be a hot mess) for questions about the payment system.

Comment: Questions that contain [tag:visa] or [tag:mastercard] to signify that they contain something about the respective payment system sound suspiciously like using these tags like meta tags to me

Comment: So the [[tag:mastercard]] tag is indeed about the CC company, but I do question the utility of that tag. Via the link in that tag's wiki, Mastercard does have [a *looot* of APIs](https://developer.mastercard.com/apis), but I'm not sure whether that means the generic tag is super useful or not... Just seems really broad as a category.

Comment: [mastercard] should go the way of [microsoft] and [apple]; that is, relegated to the dustbin of history. We don't do tags for companies. See, e.g., [I want my (overcooked) \[Apple\] pie!](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333833/215552)

Comment: [mastercard] and [visa] provide payment gateway apis. How about creating a new tag [Virtual-isa] and leave [visa] untouched?

Comment: @SagarV have you found a mc-api question?

Comment: @SagarV leaving [visa] untouched really wont mitigate the misuse. I think Oleg's comment of adding more detail to the tag name would mitigate the misuse. I have a suspicion most people who come to this post are probably assuming the [visa] tag was about `visa` the payment/credit card not about a communication architecture that happens to share the same name

Comment: Yeah, [visa] has to go too. The other visa needs to have a unambiguous tag name.

Comment: When I first saw this, I was wondering why this wasn't posted on the meta of [the site I moderate](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com).

Comment: `[visa-api]` wouldn't be my first choice - there are many payment gateway APIs that deal with Visa (MasterCard, etc.) payments, but not _directly_ through the Visa API (IOW, the payment gateway will have its **own** API that the developer will code against).  IMO, `[visa-payment]` would be better-suited as a tag for such questions (while `[visa-api]` might still be used for the Visa API questions _specifically_).  <-- how clear is all that (sorry)?  

Comment: @ouflak For a second, I wondered when you had become a moderator of Money.SE :P

Comment: At ~150 questions each, these two tags ([tag:visa] and [tag:mastercard]) would be rather quick/easy for SOCVR or any group to cleanup and burninate... or rename to appropriate things with moderator help (like [tag:mastercard-api], etc). cc @Machavity thoughts?

Comment: We'd probably need a proper burninate for [mastercard] but we could probably run a cleanup on [visa] since we have a Meta for it.

Answer (score 4):

So, I created the [visa-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/visa-api), for a simple reason: while there are many api's in the visa family, all of them are tightly integrated to a single purpose: payment processing. Unlike google pleathora of api's, visa has a handful, all documented in at most a single page (from a cursory glance, they don't even use different domains for the endpoint).

The other important reason: if we create a tag for each api, there will be more tags than questions. I decided to use [Shog's reasoning about the sony tag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/254124/792066). There aren't enough questions to warrant 6NF levels of atomicity.