# We should burn a [card] from the deck

Tags: discussion, burninate-request

A peek at the [recent discussion around](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/407554/the-visa-tag-is-commonly-misused?cb=1) [visa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/visa) and [mastercard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mastercard) led me to the [card](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/card) tag.

[card](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/card) [has 192 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/card) and no usage guidance or tag wiki.  Questions reference:

- [Cards](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/card/) in the open source Bootstrap library
- [Cards](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/cards/) in React Bootstrap
- The [Card](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Card-class.html) class in Flutter
- Oracle's [Java Card Connected Platform](http://ava%20Card%20Connected%20Platform) for smart cards
- Credit card payments (including recurring ones), Credit card verification, Detecting credit vs. debit cards, and Apple wallet card tokens
- Dealing a random card from a deck, animating rummy and other card games
- Reprogramming SIM cards

It does seem the majority of questions do tend to revolve around a "Card" class in various UI frameworks, and there is room for a counter-proposal to specify that usage and cleanup the unrelated questions.  But the range of questions are so broad that there is no value added by the tag.

Curiously, while there are 79 watchers, [top users](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/card/topusers) have only answered 4 questions each.

**1. Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?**

Generally it describes a question around the use of a "card" in various UI frameworks, except when it is used to refer to playing cards or credit cards or smart cards or SIM cards.  I would say "incorrectly used" if there were usage guidance specifying otherwise.  However, as a general term, "card" is very ambiguous.

**2. Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?**

Possibly if it were restricted to the most common use as an HTML/CSS/UI web element like a button.  The other uses primarily involve software that interacts *with* a card.

**3. Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?**

Possibly as a secondary filtering tag if it were restricted to the most common use as an HTML/CSS/UI web element, coupled with the particular framework being used.  However, a simple text search using "card" as a term is more useful than the tag.  Considering the top related tag, a search [using the keywords "`[css] card`"](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bcss%5D%20card&searchOn=3) returns 20,182 results, compared to the 33 bearing both [css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css) and [card](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/card) tags.

**4. Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?**

No. In addition to the list above, there are business cards (or address book cards), electronic greeting cards, ID cards, and more.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Proposal:

- Rename [cardlayout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cardlayout) to [swing-cardlayout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swing-cardlayout) (matches current tag wiki and *most* of the questions tagged with it)
- Create new tag ([card-layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/card-layout) or [card-widget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/card-widget)?) for the generic concept of a card widget in a UI framework and retag relevant [card](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/card) (and mistagged [cardlayout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cardlayout)) questions to that
- Retag questions about SIM cards to the existing [sim-card](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sim-card) tag
- Retag questions about credit cards to the existing [credit-card](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/credit-card) tag
- Retag questions about Java Card to the existing [javacard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javacard) tag
- Remove [card](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/card) entirely from questions about decks of cards or card games

Comment: Is there a difference between removing `card` entirely or making it a synonym of `card-layout` thus preventing its misuse?

Comment: @DanielWiddis My initial thought was to remove it entirely since the current usage is so wildly inconsistent, but maybe a synonym would be a good idea since that's by far the most common.

Comment: Upvote this comment if you think `card-layout` is a better name.

Comment: Upvote this comment if you think `card-widget` is a better name.

Comment: `card-layout` **is not** the same as `card-widget`. The former refers to laying out components within a container (e.g. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/CardLayout.html) while the latter refers to UI elements called "cards".

Comment: I prefer keeping just the ones that can be tied to a specific object/function/framework in programming. sim-cards, credit-cards, et al, are not specific to a programming product. That means only javacard gets to stay.

Comment: Having `swing-cardlayout` and *also* and new `card-layout` tag sounds like it would be wildly confusing, so my vote would be the `-widget` variant.

Comment: @zcoop98 - cards are not always widgets :) In Apps Script, we have a service for creating card-based interfaces but decided against a separate tag to avoid clutter. Maybe [card-interface], btw?

Comment: @Oleg That's a fair criticism... I'm not sure I'd even call the Bootstrap Vue cards that I'm most familiar with "widgets"; they're definitely `-interface` though. Maybe `card-component` could be thrown into the ring too? May that's too broad... language is hard to get right lol

Comment: @zcoop98 - the hardest part of our craft :) Maybe, although components are parts of interfaces. So I think if [card] is to survive, it should be something along the lines of [card-interface] (I am not adamant on the wording, though).

Comment: I like `card-component` for referring to a UI element.  That is the terminology which is used in the [Material Design specs](https://material.io/components/cards).

Comment: `card-games` could make sense...