# Liquidate the [companyname] tags. They are useless

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request

I think that all the tags for a company, corporation, or IT group in the form of [companyname] should be burned. They don't add any value to SO, because:

- They do not make it any easier to find questions, as these companies have many different products.
- Some of these tags seem to be a magnet for off-topic and bad questions.
- They are just generally useless.

Now, I realize we can't just get rid of these overnight, but we **can**:

- Avoid creating new ones. If you have 1.5 k rep, you *should* be reading Meta, and you will hopefully see this.
- Edit them out of existing questions while editing.
- Add a bigger "Use the correct tags, and avoid this one" warning to them.

#### Thoughts?

---

A small sample of the horde of terrible tags infecting SO:

- [amazon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/amazon) (4k) - [The [amazon] tag has been burninated](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/345643/1595451) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
- [epson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/epson) (160)
- [logitech](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/logitech) (60)
- [sony](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sony) (784) - [Sony tag clean-up](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253528/clean-up-the-sony-tag-is-it-useful-at-all-or-should-we-re-tag-and-clean-up) [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined)
- [jetbrains](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jetbrains) (300) - [Creator of my favorite IDE, but sorry..](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254250/lets-remove-the-jetbrains-tag) [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined)
- [adobe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/adobe) (3k)
- [autodesk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/autodesk) (100)
- [stackexchange](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/stackexchange) (60) - Not very useful here as a tag.
- [mozilla](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mozilla) (1k) - [[mozilla]? more like Lesszilla!](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/346213/mozilla-more-like-lesszilla)
- [ibm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ibm) (1k) - [Watson wants to get rid of [ibm]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/348131/watson-wants-to-get-rid-of-ibm) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
- [acquia](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/acquia) (20) - a hosting company specializing in hosting Drupal websites
- [activestate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/activestate) (90)
- [godaddy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/godaddy) (1.4k) - [Should we burninate [godaddy]?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/331817/) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
- [grapecity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/grapecity) (**5**)
- [componentone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/componentone) (20)
- [sun](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sun) (245)
- [alcatel-ot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/alcatel-ot) (10)
- [nokia](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nokia) (718) - [Should we burninate [nokia]?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/355199/should-we-burninate-nokia?cb=1) [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined)
- [htc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/htc) (500) - [Should we burninate the [htc] tag?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/351225/should-we-burninate-the-htc-tag) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
- [lg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/lg) (100)
- [motorola](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/motorola) (500)
- [intel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/intel) (1.3k)
- [symantec](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/symantec) (20)
- [intuit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/intuit) (200)
- [maxmind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/maxmind) (150)
- [atmel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/atmel) (617)
- [microchip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/microchip) (679)
- [qualcomm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/qualcomm) (130)
- [texasinstruments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/texasinstruments) (378)
- [infineon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/infineon) (32)
- [xilinx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/xilinx) (1379)
- [intel-fpga](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/intel-fpga) alias [altera](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/altera) (498)
- [nintendo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nintendo) (54)
- [samsung](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/samsung) (76)

(There are hundreds more...)

Comment: Careful, Shog doesn't like having more than 1 tag per burninate req, and will assert his wrath!

Comment: I support this. I think the [tag:logitech] tag has seem more spam questions than anything else. All of those scam phone number help postings have been tagged with just this tag lately, though I doubt removing the tag will stop them.

Comment: Are some of these tags used by companies that have made SO their support platform?

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara: I don't know. Are you sure the spammers will realize everything bounces because the tag doesn't exist anymore?

Comment: @MartinSmith, I did not specifically put any such tag in my list, but yes, possibly. That some company is using it for support does not mean we have to keep it though.

Comment: It doesn't mean we have to keep it but if those companies have knowledgable staff keeping an eye on the tags then they wouldn't be useless. (Not sure how frequently this actually happens)

Comment: @MartinSmith, Aggreed, But they can use tags for the specific products instead, no need for a tag for the whole company.

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251164 for the reasons for Sony, cc @martin. There are definitely some other companies that do the same. Also http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/253528/458741

Comment: I'll nominate [tag:maxmind] as well, while the GeoIP database that they provide is useful (along with their other services), very rarely is it actually needed on the question.

Comment: "godaddy (1.4k) https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288200/kill-the-godaddy-tag-with-fire (Why was this not burninated already ?)" because this https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/333768/792066

Comment: [tag:paypal] (17k)...

Comment: [tag:paypal] request - https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/345880/burninate-request-paypal-tag

Comment: [tag:sap] disambiguation request - https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/402154/, burnination request - https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/350750/ (declined)