# Should we burninate [godaddy]?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, burninate-request, blocklist-request, tag-blocklist

*The outcome of this process hasn't been a complete burnination but instead a [tag warning](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/334663/578411) has been implemented by Shog9. That is final*

In [Kill the [godaddy] tag with fire](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288200/kill-the-godaddy-tag-with-fire), we clearly agreed, that [godaddy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/godaddy) should die in fire. This is thus not a duplicate, but a different question, this time pulling things through.

It's still attracting new questions, most of which simply abuse the tag simply because, for example,

- "hey, it's my hoster" ("[how to upload image using REST to app running on godaddy domain"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38582517/how-to-upload-imagejpeg-into-godaddy-using-rest-api)) or
- "has something to do with domains, right?" (["help, my tumblr which
  is pointed to through a godaddy domain (or not, I'm not specifying)
  isn't reachable from Brazil"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38807961/403-responde-on-tumblr-when-linking-to-godaddy-domain)) , or
- are questions that should be
  raised with the godaddy company or simply self-researched (["can
  godaddy host PHP application XYZ?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38555321/does-godaddy-support-database-connections-to-app-data-mdf-databases)).

So the continued existence of this tag is actively hurting.

That was more than a year ago, and since then, the tag excerpt has been:

> Do not use this tag. It is due for removal.

Can we finally burninate the tag, instead of letting it live in Limbo?

**EDIT**: Laurel recommended blacklisting the tag. That's something we should instantly do, shouldn't we? I wasn't aware of that option.

Comment: Partial answer to your last question / things to add to your post: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239190/when-to-burninate

Comment: It wouldn't take *forever*.. just a couple days of concentrated effort by a core group of users. Most of these questions can be closed as off-topic, and that's a good place to start. I'd enlist the Close voters chat room for help.

Comment: @gunr2171 Interesting post, but that's also why I added the `[discussion]` tag. I think that this tag fails pretty obviously on all the points in that answer, and it attracts questions who are off-topic and therefor "harmeful" to the site.

Comment: FYI - @gunr2171 runs the bot in the CV chat room.

Comment: How does it help anything to run some bot or script that just adds a comment, and not even a close vote, to every one of these questions?

Comment: @bmargulies What do you mean?

Comment: I see a comment from you on all these questions, and I don't see a close vote.

Comment: My reputation is too low to close vote, so I flagged them and left a comment.

Comment: "what kind of questions this tag attracts": Do you think there would be less such questions if the tag wasn't there? Or would they be asked anyway, with worse tags?

Comment: I like the title of the question

Comment: [tag:hosting] probably merits being reviewed / burned similarly.

Comment: *Pun*ination request: **Go away, [godaddy]!**

Comment: Puns or not, there are today 335 questions more bearing the mark of [godaddy] than there were a year ago :(

Comment: Blacklisting it would help prevent new questions, which seems like a good strategy considering there are 1k+ questions tagged with it right now.

Comment: It would be funnier to automatically remove the account of anyone who uses it

Comment: perhaps  'Hunt down [godaddy]'? http://www.huffingtonpost.com/2011/03/31/bob-parsons-godaddy-ceo-elephant-hunt_n_843121.html

Comment: `[godaddy], go away from Stack Overflow`

Comment: I think it's a great tag. At least you know a better lay-of-the-land prior to giving assistance. Otherwise, half the time you are well into it before they mention facts of diminished rights and locked-down features.

Comment: @Drew not really an argument, is it? we don't want to foster the kind of "heuristic" knowledge this implies, like "if your apache httpd doesn't work, disable SELinux" or "roundcube doesn't work on godaddy", we want people to learn the reasons why some things don't work, and we want to encourage people describing their setup and problem in full. tagging [tag:godaddy] actively discourages people to take the time to study their environment, which is the solution to their problems very often.

Comment: A tag like "shared-host" is perfect for my eyes as I debug questions in that realm

Comment: @Drew like that much more! Problem is that people with this kind of question don't realize they should be tagging [tag:shared-hosting]; they just know that godaddy hosts their website; so they don't come to the conclusion they should be using a tag that describes the class of problems.

Comment: Well it is like your solution-providing peers helping you to tag it python3. It saves everyone the grief once someone stumbles into that factoid. But backing up though, it has nearly 2k questions. We were briefly discussing it (read: 1 minute) in SOCVR. I can't speak for them, but it is not as if they/we would be taking on this task.

Comment: @Drew can understand that

Comment: @Idea: blacklist  [tag:godaddy]; remove [tag:godaddy] on the questions that are also tagged [tag:shared-hosting].

Comment: Is it possible to show a user posting with `godaddy` a polite notice to reinforce what is and isn't an acceptable question on SO? If you remove the categorisation of `godaddy` that just means that we no longer know how many questions there are in the wild and cleaning them up could be a nightmare.

Comment: @WilliamIsted pretty sure a tag excerpt saying, verbatim, "Do not use this tag. It is due for removal." is all the hint one should be given; the likelihood of someone sensibly tagging with [tag:godaddy] is slim; I'd love to see some warnings that read "you seem to be entering a question regarding <xyz>; many of such questions are off-topic here because <abc> and will be closed by the community without answer", but I don't think, on the other hand, that this is possibly on a "fair" basis.

Comment: @MarcusMüller I'd encourage alternatives rather than nuking the tag, I do think the warning you've given as an example would provide a polite warning of what to expect. If they tag simply says "Do not use this tag. It is due for removal." surely (in theory ofc) the asker would choose a different tag and not quite get the reasoning for why the tag isn't in use

Comment: @WilliamIsted sure, I'd prefer that, too, but the point is that this reduces to "making sure people have understood the tagging system before they post a question", which, in my experience, SO is failing, and frankly, I don't know a remedy but to make the entry hurdle higher, which is probably not in the best interest of SE.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Completely agree. Sounds like good grounds for an A/B test though

Comment: Should the same apply for other hosting provider tags? [tag:bluehost], [tag:dreamhost], [tag:linode]?

Comment: @duskwuff imho, yes. We might want to put that into a separate question, though. Would you mind? "There's a host of badness in [tag:bluehost],[tag:dreamhost],[tag:linode]" sounds like a good title.

Comment: Trogdor supports burnination. Provider-specific issues are more of a tech-support issue, not a general programming one.

Comment: @B.K. no. A tag is just a social norm, arbitrarily imposed on innocent questions, that would much rather be recognized what they're *about*, not from which hoster they originate. Rude.

Comment: So, this has been up for 2 days. Ready to move to [meta-tag:status-planned] yet or am I missing something?

Comment: that status tag was just added yesterday, but I, too agree, think we should move on. I think, however, that's @undo's job, isn't it?

Comment: Rather than deleting it, rename it to WebHosting, for support with any webhosts, rather than just godaddy

Comment: @4g0tt3nSou1 that would mean we would have another bad tag. This is clearly not a good solution.

Comment: I believe by burning the GoDaddy tag it would show that SO is particular in providing support for third party services and or environments. If someone today chooses to burn the godaddy tag will someone tomorrow vote to burn the paypal tag? I smell a net-neutrally discussion coming on.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Got any support as to why it would be bad? Realistically, it solves this request, and if there are tags for other providers, it condenses it all to one tag, rather than several, unused tags

Comment: @4g0tt3nSou1 In what way would the [tag:web-hosting] tag be helpful in classifying a question? not very much at all.

Comment: @WilliamKnauss Interesting point. Though I can clearly say that Paypal does have a programming API and questions (that shouldn't be closed or re-tagged) carrying the [tag:paypal] tag actually have something integral to do with programming with special respect to that API, or other Paypal services. Whereas the [tag:godaddy] tag is a wild collection of questions without a common denominator (just like 4g0tt3nSou1's suggested [tag:web-hosting] would terribly be).

Comment: @MarcusMüller - Godaddy has an API as well.  https://developer.godaddy.com/

Comment: @MarcusMüller the `godaddy` tag should be renamed `shared-hosting` to make clear that the user has an issue specific to the problems of shared webhosts, which many people are forced to use. if a problem is not `shared-hosting`-specific then the question is likely off-topic. If I could vote, I'd vote to rename all `godaddy` to `shared-hosting` after closing the too-general and too-specific.

Comment: @Ber - Should the "Paypal" tag be renamed to "payment gateways" as well?

Comment: [godaddy] we don't need thoughts of your sketchy borderline pornographic tv ads here. You are based on lies and click bait, BE GONE!

Comment: @LukeA.Leber ... and it's under discussion whether this tag *should* apply to that. However, if I had a guess, about 99% percent of [tag:godaddy] questions now are *not*. This is so much that it would make much more sense to add a [tag:godaddy-api] tag to those that actually refer to that API, and get rid of the raw [tag:godaddy] tag – experience clearly has shown that this tag attracts unspecific and mis-tagging.

Comment: @LukeA.Leber given that other commercial service specific tags have been blocked... it's an interesting point. If paypal were less of a monopoly and if it didn't use a highly customized payment system, you might want a tagname like `online-payment`. But given its own problems it's more of a product than a generic service. So I'd vote to keep `paypal` on that basis.

Comment: Isn't there a way/ feature that if someone trys to tag go daddy, so display something along the lines of, "no, tag shared-host instead"?

Comment: maybe it is much too easy here on stackoverflow to create new tags? I mean, how many good tags do we really need to create, say, per month? Wouldn't it be much better to have a discussion here on meta/stackoverflow for each proposed tag? And some kind of voting process? What is the probability of the next created tag to be a good one? Other tags that I consider suboptimal (coming from a quick 1-minute-search): microphone, nsrangeexception, animation, facebook, revenue, uiscrollview, slave. Burninating godaddy is like going into a slimy student apartment, cleaning one square meter, and leaving.

Comment: @Michael One needs at least 1500 reputation to create tags. Since it's quite hard to get that much rep, creating new tags isn't that easy.

Comment: @Michael as someone having lived long enough in student apartments: it's always *starting* at a specific m²; if you don't start somewhere... But yes, that is another, interesting discussion. However, this case is like a lot of others (and could set a precedence): SO has evolved over the years, and someone might have thought it was a good tag a couple of years ago, when it was created. That proved to be wrong. We now need to clean up that mess.

Comment: @dorukayhan I wouldn't agree with that. Sure, it took *me* 16 active days, but I not once touch a "popular" web-dev topic, but always answered niche questions.

Comment: also, looking at the amount of misspelled and not-checked-for-duplicate ([tag:doing-stuff] vs. [tag:do-stuff] vs. [tag:stuff-doing] vs. [tag:stuff-do]), your argument doesn't seem to be based off the full reality of this site. To illustrate http://stackoverflow.com/tags/synonyms

Comment: What about forcing all tagged questions to go through an enhanced moderation with a (super easy) close option and some instructions. That way, editors with some discretion get to kill the rubbish questions. This way a more scalable plan is created for unwanted tags and future napalm targets.

Comment: Not sure who requested this to be featured in the first place but as it is now status-planned the SOCVR is open to be heading this effort.

Comment: This question seems to be biased towards the perception of people that find the tag annoying. However it doesn't present enough information on why the tag should be burninated, It mentions that there are 1439 questions using the tag but when presenting evidence only talks with vague terms like: [...you can sense that this tag... A lot of the questions are... Some questions would be... Here's a few posts with...] I think the same statements can be made against practically every tag if you take only "some" poorly written questions. In the other side no technical reason is explained.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Kill the \[godaddy\] tag with fire](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288200/kill-the-godaddy-tag-with-fire)

Comment: @Yvette this question started with the statement that the question you're referring to was more than a year ago, and nothing had been done. It thus has gone through multiple stages of the burnination process. Please refer to the  edit history for more details.

Comment: @MarcusMüller I haven't seen you in here http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120759/godaddy-burnination we need some close votes, but mainly delete votes

Comment: @MarcusMüller I dupe voted it other way around. If I'm correct circular duplicates will raise a message for close voters. We'll see how this end. No harm done though, we can keep editing and updating this until we're done.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

## Progress

You have helped out by reviewing the questions and answers in these tags by performing one or more of the following actions:

- flag or close questions that are duplicate/off-topic/unclear/too broad/opinion based;
- filter on these tags in the Close Vote Queue and review;
- vote on the questions and its answers;
- delete vote the question or answer(s) if there is nothing of value;
- editing to add value (re-tag), or;
- flag obsolete comments.

For the final stretch we need you to review the closed questions with a positive score and delete vote those that are not worth keeping around. Please note that the moderator team [isn't thrilled about some calls we made](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/333768/578411), please be careful with your actions.

- [Evaluate positive scored closed, not duplicate, questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgodaddy%5D+score%3A2..+is%3Aq+duplicate%3Ano) 57
- [Evaluate positive scored closed, not duplicate, questions with no accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgodaddy%5D+score%3A2..+is%3Aq+hasaccepted%3Ano+duplicate%3Ano) 16

There is no need to remove the tag from questions if you think if it should stay closed. The tag will bulk-removed by a Community Manager when this review is finished.

[godaddy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/godaddy)

- <strike>[Open](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgodaddy%5D+closed%3Ano)
  0</strike>
- [Closed](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgodaddy%5D+closed%3Ayes) 75
- <strike>[No answers](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgodaddy%5D+answers%3A0+closed%3Ano) 0</strike>
- <strike>[No accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgodaddy%5D+hasaccepted%3A0+closed%3Ano) 0</strike>

More focused searches [open questions only]:

- <s>[`[godaddy] [web]`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgodaddy%5D+%5Bweb%5D+closed%3A0) mostly off-topic, 0 questions</s>
- <s>[`[godaddy] [cpanel]`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgodaddy%5D+%5Bcpanel%5D+closed%3A0) mostly off-topic, 0 questions</s>
- <s>[`[godaddy] [dns]`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgodaddy%5D+%5Bdns%5D+closed%3A0) mostly off-topic, 0 questions</s>
- <s>[`[godaddy] [.htaccess]`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgodaddy%5D+%5B.htaccess%5D+closed%3A0) mostly off topic, but be alert for good duplicates, 0 questions</s>
- <s>[`[godaddy] [email]`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgodaddy%5D+%5Bemail%5D+closed%3A0) mostly off topic, 0 questions</s>
- <s>[`[godaddy] [mysql]`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=relevance&q=%5bmysql%5d%5bgodaddy%5d%20closed%3a0) mostly off topic, 0 questions</s>
- <s>[`[godaddy] [hosting]`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgodaddy%5D+%5Bhosting%5D+closed%3A0) mostly off topic, 0 questions</s>

Reviewing

- [Review in the Close vote Queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close?filter-tags=godaddy)
- [Delete vote with the MagicReview User Script](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/32257993#32257993)

Remember that we don't want to destroy value so let salvaging a post be your first priority!
If you have specific questions feel free to drop in the [SOCVR](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers), the [GoDaddy Burnination room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120759/godaddy-burnination) or leave a comment under this post.

Comment: @dorukayhan unless he has a comment or edited the post, he's not notified.

Comment: @dorukayhan with all due respect, I'll decide what I accept, and I don't actually think this post is the answer to my question. It **is** a step in the right direction, but at a very specific point, there will be things left that are tagged [tag:godaddy], and we'll have a stalling progress like 2015. I've myself already voted on quite a few posts, but this is really going slow manually; my sad prediction is that manual retagging is too big an effort to do for those who come across this. No, this is not the *answer*, though this is really *the right thing for a community to do*.

Comment: Oh ... challenge accepted ...

Comment: @MarcusMüller This is not the first nor the largest tag that has been handled by this process... trust the process, my friend :-)

Comment: @TylerH http://i.imgur.com/2jsfax6.jpg :)

Comment: @MarcusMüller wrote: "Idea: blacklist [godaddy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/godaddy); remove `godaddy` on the questions that are also tagged [shared-hosting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/shared-hosting)." As you said, we'd need to remove all the irrelevant tags/posts before we can re-tag the remainder, but this sounds like a good idea for a start.

Comment: Who is going to help us with this in socvr? We need 4000 close votes roughly. Give or take thousands. Not to mention Delete votes.

Comment: @Drew I agree, I don't know who requested this to be featured in the first place. Who ever did that now keeps quiet it seems. As I pinged Undo about taking it off the featured list and nobody stepped forward then the least we can do is provide some coordination. Totally agree with your call out here. If all who voted on this post care enough they will join.We'll see how it develops.

Comment: @Drew 4000 close votes are *a lot*. Like, for every one who's voted on my question, these are more than ten close votes. Assuming everyone has the privileges to do that kind of voting. Realistically, this means we need about twice as many close votes per person, not even counting the fact that I still skip questions with topics that I can't claim to be sufficiently confident in to choose a valid course of action. Really. Manually, this will, like last year, simply dry out.

Comment: @rene I'll flag my post for moderator intervention, hoping this will do *anything*. Want me to add anything in the flag comment?

Comment: @Drew also, just extrapolating from current speed: 40 closes in 10 hrs; this would take years.

Comment: @MarcusMüller I doubt a mod will take the tag out. I'm more in favor to give this a try for a week or so to underpin those guestimates. Drew and myself are getting the SOCVR just about organized and our available tooling configured.

Comment: If we keep this answer updated, it will popup in the active list on meta, that will attract those who care

Comment: good approach; but I think I could actually ask for the featured tag again. Not like this isn't the single biggest community effort currently.

Comment: @MarcusMüller you think annoying users by  making this featured *again* is helping? I doubt it will. I'm even afraid it might backfire on SOCVR, something I don't fancy much.

Comment: @MarcusMüller it is a large undertaking and people are chipping away at it. Featuring it again will not get it done any faster. We only have a finite number of votes and hours in the day. ;)

Comment: @GregP that's **exactly** my problem. Finite amount of votes/day * finite amount of people willing to help = finite amount of closes / day. Can we get an estimate that's not done by me of how long this will take in the ideal case, ie. everyone upvoting this answer (10 people so far) would spend all of their daily close votes on this?

Comment: The initial rough estimate is a month or so @MarcusMüller. The SOCVR, Campaigns and SOCVFinder have a  crew of 30 to 40 regulars that know how to do this stuff, day in, day out.

Comment: @rene these are people of strict discipline and great efforts. Thank you, internet strangers!

Comment: @rene all out of close review votes for today :)

Comment: I burned a total of 120 CV reviews on [tag:godaddy] now.

Comment: @Magisch I beat you. I burned a total of undefined [0] CV reviews on go daddy now :P

Comment: @Zizouz212 Ha! I burned NaN godaddy questions.

Comment: Two people have voted to close my question as duplicate of the "dead" question I was referring to. Could the SOCVR team please help clarify, so that we don't end up with a closed question in the middle of the burnination process?

Comment: Would it be time now to initiate phase 5?

Comment: @MarcusMüller No, we are looking at the positive scored closed questions if they need to be deleted or salvaged. That is what I agreed on with Shog9. That process is still going but needs enough users with delete votes were warranted and so needs a bit more time.

Comment: @rene: "needs time": thought so, which is why I let this "linger" for a few days; wasn't aware of agreements on how to proceed. Godspeed! Note that I'll be AFK for a couple of weeks soon; I'm clearly not spearheading this, but just so that no-one tries to get my approval for anything (I don't presume anyone cares, but nevertheless): I'm very happy with all that's happening!

Comment: @MarcusMüller well, there was another meta post for a call to action on the deletion part but one of the mods disagreed with some of the deletions we already did. So I had to [summarize our plans](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333706/assisting-with-godaddy-deletions/333768#comment390906_333768) for the CM and mod team.

Comment: @rene I'm back from my travels. Um, as far as I can see there's not a single unclosed question left, so have we met all requirements to proceed to the next step in the process, and also: I lost track, where exactly are we in that process? What's left to do?

Comment: You brought us in a tough fight with the community and [this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/334663/578411) was the resolution. I've flagged this to be tagged as status-completed

Comment: There are new 272 questions on this tag

Comment: @VadimKotov No, there are not, [only 274 closed](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgodaddy%5D+closed%3Ayes) remaining. At the top of the question a CM ruled: *The outcome of this process hasn't been a complete burnination but instead a tag warning has been implemented by Shog9. That is final*. So let's move on...

Comment: @rene oh, I see. Maybe we should retag remaining questions with [tag:shared-hosting] then?

Comment: @VadimKotov No, we should do nothing. It is *Final*, *finito*, *done*, *ready*, no need to rip open the wounds caused by this.

Answer (score 62):

Given that there [are several examples](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5bgodaddy%5d%20score%3a1%20is%3aq) of the [godaddy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/godaddy) tag being used where other tags are more appropriate, a blacklist and manual cleanup should be performed. There are some questions about the [GoDaddy API](https://developer.godaddy.com/) that might need a [godaddy-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/godaddy-api) tag if they don't have [other problems](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). There are many others that might be fine questions asked in the wrong place (DNS stuff normally). Going through [this list](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5Bgodaddy%5D%20score%3A1%20is%3Aq%20closed%3A0) can give some ideas of what other tasks need to be done.

Comment: @MarcusMüller is easier to convince people to do a task when they aren't going against the tide...

Comment: :D message gotten

Comment: This would appear to be the only use case for a Godaddy related tag, otherwise customers of Godaddy should use their knowledge base https://www.godaddy.com/help

Comment: Still, point is that there are **less questions with a positive score** than there are zero-score questions. Manual cleanup ... might not feel overly rewarding.

Comment: @MarcusMüller that's actually something positive, less questions to manually check ;)

Comment: The problem with manual cleanup with 600+ questions of positive score that come from the same family of questions that 900+ non-positive score questions is still a hell of a job, as of these 600+ questions 500+ are bound to be no fun to read

Comment: @MarcusMüller if 1 out 10 people that view this question did 1 edit, we have 100 people to do other stuff.

Comment: Rename it `shared-hosting` per @Drew's suggestion above and vote to close anything that is not specific to the problems affected by shared webhosts: limited permissions etc. which is helpful to know; or otherwise unless it is retagged something more relevant. Delete tag / retag / close all off-topic or irrelevant use. (i.e. anything not relevant to `shared-hosting` and how it affects the problem at hand)

Comment: Add a note saying *"This tag is blacklisted. if your question is specific to a single hosting provider, it is better asked of your webhost tech support. If it is relevant to the question that you are on an Apache shared webhost, or other type of host, please use the `shared-hosting` tag instead."*

Comment: @Ber we can't "rename it" since some (most) are about people that just happen to be using GoDaddy... they are generic questions normally.

Comment: Rename the tag in all questions where the type of host is actually relevant, then delete the invalid tag or close the rest. This should be easy if so few have a hosting specific issue.

Comment: @Ber err... and in what way that's different of what I propose?

Comment: It might not be. I'm just saying it might be helpful to post a notice directing users to the `shared-hosting` tag if it is relevant that they're on a shared webhost with limited functionality.

Comment: @Ber but in that case, it's not a tag rename. It's a manual sorting of questions; Braiam is right, your suggestion doesn't contribute a viable alternative to this.

Comment: It contributes a perspective on the need for tags that address a general set of problems that relate to, as @Drew and @ChrisHayes suggested, problems with the webhost. These can be generalized to a tag such as `shared-hosting` which is why that should be emphasized. All other use of such "brand-name" tag is simple mis-tagging which amounts to complaining (accurately) that users of certain tags, especially brand-names instead of product names like `apache`, are less likely to be experienced SO users. It's a fairly straightforward and common issue, nothing to get too frustrated about.

Comment: @Ber a programmer don't deal with shared hosting... that's the sysadmin job (through most guys at [sf] will kill me...)!

Comment: Which isn't to say I don't agree that it's a straightforward and common *problem* (use of generic brand-name tags that do not address the question) that needs to be addressed ;) It could be emphasized that *"tags aren't for describing your setup unless it is relevant to the problem at hand..."*

Comment: @Braiam sometimes the answer to a server-side question depends on what type of hosting they're on, tho. As somebody whose project is stuck on a webhost and has had to get info on how to deal with that, I know how that goes...  (Not with `godaddy` specificity though, if that appeals to the lowest denominator of dealing with bugs pertaining to a specific webhost, and thus violates the general applicability rule. But if a person's question can be answered and the general principle is sound, then it can certainly help, just not as a tag.)

Comment: @Ber how about this, look for a practical programming question that the fact that is a shared hosting is critically relevant, where if you remove that variable none of the possible answers will apply anymore.

Answer (score 53):

I agree with most of the community in saying that [godaddy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/godaddy) needs to be burninated. The [SO Close Vote Reviewers](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers) are already in the process of cleaning it up, but the (off-topic) questions within the tag need close votes first.

> Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?

It is not ambiguous, let's get that out of the way. Clearly any question tagged with [godaddy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/godaddy) is going to involve GoDaddy in some way. You could call it broad though, as GoDaddy offers a range of services that the tag could possibly be signaling.

> Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?

It's nowhere near as on-topic as [microsoft](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/microsoft) and [apple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apple), [and we know how that ended up](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284167/359284). Some of the services provided *may* be on-topic here, but they aren't tag-worthy. And most of the questions aren't on-topic because there is nothing in the tag to encourage them.

> Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?

**No.** The tag could not stand alone on a question, and having it on a question adds no extra information that is useful.

Comment: What I miss is what to do when I hit this in the CVQ. Off-topic/SF? Are they open for these kind of questions? Can we add some guidance on that?

Comment: I'm making this as correct. It answers my question wether this tag deserves to be burnt. Now all we have to do is bring on the napalm.

Answer (score 26):

Rename it `shared-hosting` per [Drew's suggestion above](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/331817/should-we-burninate-godaddy?cb=1#comment380322_331817)* and vote to close anything that is not specific to the problems affected by shared webhosts: limited permissions etc. which is helpful to know; or otherwise unless it is retagged something more relevant. Delete tag / retag / close all off-topic or irrelevant use. (i.e. anything not relevant to shared-hosting and how it affects the problem at hand)

- (After removing invalid use of the tag to specify irrelevant details, "I am on GoDaddy, btw" which applies to any improperly used tag; should account for 90% of prior deprecated use)

Add a note saying *"This tag is blacklisted. if your question is specific to a single hosting provider, it is better asked of your webhost tech support. If it is relevant to the question that you are on an Apache shared webhost, or other type of host, please use the `shared-hosting` tag instead."*

Wash, rinse, repeat for all other hosting service providers. (Don't discriminate.)

Comment: "we can't "rename it" since some (most) are about people that just happen to be using GoDaddy... they are generic questions normally." it will require anyways a human to clean it up.

Comment: Again, see my comment / edit which I made per your earlier reply. I'm not proposing anything automatic except for the notice for future use of the tag. I'm only seconding Drew's suggestion that the tag be renamed to the non-host specific `shared-hosting` only on questions that are on-topic and relevant.

Comment: We can't automatically retag a thousand questions to [tag:shared-hosting] if of those thousand a solid percentage is plainly so bad that it shouldn't ruin another tag.

Comment: This is simply data logic: (to use an analogy) you select all uses of the tag (valid or invalid), sort out and remove all the *irrelevant* use of the tag, and rename only the rest *afterward*. If the percentage is small it should be easier: you can leave it up to the users rescue a question by retagging after step 1 has occurred.

Comment: @Ber that's manual sorting, as already suggested by Braiam

Comment: I agree. Anything to spare the SOCVR folks of it. +1

Comment: I totally agree with this. I am reviewing posts, voting to close off topic ones and the ones that are on topic, I'd much prefer to retag with a generic tag such as shared-hosting. But hey, who cares, we now need to delete a billion blinking posts off the site, like there's not enough to do already.

Answer (score 18):

As someone who has fairly often worked on complex web applications hosted on GoDaddy, who has some level of interest in such, I'd say go ahead and vet and prune the questions and burninate the tag.

- Someone who wants to find Godaddy questions on StackOverflow can just use searches to find them anyway.
- Currently, clicking on the Godaddy SO tag yields an atrocious blather of random questions on very different topics, because so many different things can be hosted there, and they have (and have had) all sorts of "tools" and "services" which change over time. Clicking on the Godaddy tag seems like a fairly silly thing to do unless you are a Godaddy customer support manager/researcher or something, in which case, you can also just use search.
- I'm also someone who likes old arcane questions and newbie questions and doesn't like to see them die, but removing the tag won't hurt, and many of the older questions may have truly obsolete answers anyway, because Godaddy changes their stuff so often.
- Godaddy also has quite good live 24-hour customer support for most basic-to-intermediate problems. I've never actually used SO for "actual Godaddy questions" because I can just phone them up.

On the other hand, I would say that there are a few topics which really are Godaddy-specific and some of them are SO-relevant... but you could still just use search rather than a tag.

Burn away...

Comment: sounds like it's just one of those [meta-tag:meta-tags]