# Don't feel blue about [bluehost]

Tags: discussion, burninate-request

The [godaddy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/godaddy) tag [is in the process of being burninated](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/331817/1983854). Recently, I noticed another web hosting company attracting a lot of questions: Bluehost with [bluehost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bluehost) containing 290 questions right now.

Should we also remove this tag, by removing it from the questions that unnecessarily use it ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38277400/1983854), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37412093/1983854)), and closing most of those that are seemingly off topic here?

Comment: I would say yes. It's too specific and we're not [customer support for Bluehost](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/why-were-not-customer-support-for-your-favorite-company). It would make sense to burninate this tag as well.

Comment: Yessssssssssss.

Comment: Let's stop backing the Blue

Comment: _"Bluehost ... I saw you standing alone .. without a dream in your heart ... without a tag of your own ..."_ - apologies to fans of Elvis. [ref](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blue_Moon_(1934_song))

Comment: Maybe it is a good idea to retag with [tag:shared-hosting]. See more [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333093/lets-dream-dreamhost-is-gone?noredirect=1&lq=1#comment387198_333093)