# Let's dream [dreamhost] is gone

Tags: discussion, burninate-request

The [godaddy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/godaddy) tag [is in the process of being burninated](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/331817/1983854), and so there is for [bluehost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bluehost) with a [Don't feel blue about [bluehost]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/332911/1983854).

Now I have noticed yet another web hosting service tag: Dreamhost! [dreamhost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dreamhost) is used in 413 questions right now.

Should we also burninate this one?

Comment: You may say I'm a dreamer / but I'm not the only one / I hope someday you'll join us / And the world will live as one / and burninate this tag

Comment: On the godaddy proposal there was a suggestion to have a generic tag called `shared-hosting`. As we will be occupied with this for awhile I'm starting to wonder if [that idea](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/332053/578411) has merit, as in: we make dreamhost a synonym of [tag:shared-hosting]  and be done with it. Every other tag we find can follow the same procedure, like bluehost

Comment: I don't know about the other services being discussed, but I will note that Dreamhost has a [relatively mature API](https://help.dreamhost.com/hc/en-us/articles/217560167-API_overview), so in theory one could ask on-topic programming questions about it. That said, it's likely that most of the questions are actually hosting support questions.