# Is there a standard text for tag info about use only for programming questions?

Tags: discussion, tags

Some tags, such as [mikrotik](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mikrotik), need some text in their tag info to let users know* that only programming-related questions should be asked, e.g., regarding an API.

Is there a boilerplate text that we can/should use for the tag info in such cases?

<sub>*Yes, I know they don't all study that info, but that isn't what I'm asking about.</sub>

Comment: Isn't this kind of covered by them asking on [so]?

Comment: The [tag:machine-learning] tag is the only one I know to make a similar statement. It does not seem standardised.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi Are you suggesting that the text "Questions about *general computing hardware and software* are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming." from [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) could be used in the tag info? That's an idea I hadn't thought of.

Comment: Well, actually I was being in a "kids should know that when they tread here" mood. :D But I have to agree that a snippet from the help center, and perhaps a link to it, would seem appropriate. At least it would increase the chance of someone reading it.

Comment: I agree with MisterMiyagi about the notion that such phrase is redundant - it is not tag-specific. By simply asking in SO, you are supposed to ask programming-related questions. Nevertheless, some tags do have such statements. An example that comes to mind is [tag:zoom-sdk] which states: *"For programming questions related to the Zoom SDK and how it can be used for integrating Zoom communication platform features. GENERAL USAGE QUESTIONS ABOUT ZOOM ARE OFF-TOPIC! Stack Overflow questions must be about programming using the Zoom SDK/API."*

Comment: Another example is [tag:android] which states: *"...For questions other than development or programming, but related to the Android framework, use this link: https://android.stackexchange.com"* and yet it [doesn't seem to help](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71208709/6045800)...

Answer (score 4):

There is no such standard text or consensus that I am aware of. Maybe because generally speaking, such text is redundant and doesn't need to be part of a tag's usage guidance. I mean, the first sentence of [the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) is:

> Stack Overflow is a question and answer site for professional and enthusiast programmers

If you're here it's because you want to ask (or answer) something about programming. Further clarification in tags *shouldn't* be necessary.

Of course, off-topic questions are still going to be asked. That's why we have a specific close reason for general computing, and even one for networking. But honestly, if someone posts a question on Stack Overflow that is *not* even about programming, I really doubt that a warning in a tag description is going to change anything.

But if you really feel that a tag is being constantly misused and such text *might* somehow help, I would say that any kind of phrase like these in a tag guidance is acceptable:

- *"For programming questions about ..."*
- *"... general use questions are off-topic ..."*
- If there is a relevant Stack Exchange site, something like *"For non-programming questions see site.se"*, like [android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android) does.

But again - the very need of those phrases is a [red herring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_herring). Instead, before adding such phrase to a tag guidance, consider if it could maybe benefit more from a disambiguation, a rename, or maybe even a burnination if the majority of questions are simply off-topic.

Comment: (Upvoted.) But if I really, really want to configure my router device, isn't that programming it? That could be the way that some people think, and with that idea their question will be on-topic.

Comment: Mmm I see where you're going, but no. It will not be on-topic. Their reasoning will just be wrong and the question still off-topic and such phrase is still redundant because this site is for programming questions... Unless of course, the question is actually about programming a router at which point that might be on-topic?

Answer (score 3):

The verbiage shouldn't be added in the tag wiki or excerpt, [people never read that](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/256114/people-dont-read-the-tag-excerpts-because-we-dont-swat-them-into-their-faces). What it should be done is to make the name unambiguously about the specific thing that is on topic: mikrokit-api.

So, if a tag can potentially give the impression that off topic things are on topic, just change the tag name. That helped on many cases like [godaddy burnination](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/331817/792066) where we went from +1k questions with several of them being off topic, to only a couple tens on the [godaddy-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/godaddy-api) tag, something much more manageable.

Comment: Following on with that, are there any cases you can think of where hardwaremanufacturer-api would not be the correct form for a tag? So cisco->cisco-api, mikrotik->mikrotik-api, juniper->juniper-api, and so on?

Comment: @AndrewMorton where said manufacturer (although I prefer the term vendor) has several api's for several products. Example: google.