# [mozilla]? more like Lesszilla!

Tags: discussion, burninate-request

## Tag description

> [mozilla](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mozilla)
>
> The Mozilla Foundation is a non-profit organization that exists to
> support and provide leadership for open source Mozilla projects.
>
> Mozilla Firefox is a free, open-source browser built by Mozilla
> Foundation and Mozilla Corporation, first released in 2002 as
> 'Phoenix', becoming 'Firefox' in 2004.

---

## Why should it be burninated?

I came across some questions tagged [mozilla](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mozilla) and from what I've seen this tag is mostly used for the Mozilla Firefox browser. Mozilla Firefox already has a specific tag ([firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/firefox)). Some of those questions are about Mozilla Thunderbird ([thunderbird](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/thunderbird)). In addition, some of the questions will be about XULRunner ([xulrunner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/xulrunner)). There are also questions about XUL [xul](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/xul), which is a UI language developed by Mozilla and used in all of the above applications.

**1) Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? Is it unambiguous?**

The tag does not describe anything as it is **ambiguous**.

**2) Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?**

Mozilla is a company, it is not related to programming.

**3) Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?**

It allows one to guess that the question will be about one of the tools developed by Mozilla... not specific enough.

**4) Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?**

Related to *1)*, the tag is ambiguous and can refer to different tools.

---

## What can be done?

- [Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mozilla+firefox) tagged [mozilla](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mozilla)+[firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/firefox) can be changed to [firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/firefox) only
- [Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mozilla+thunderbird) tagged [mozilla](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mozilla)+[thunderbird](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/thunderbird) can be changed to [thunderbird](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/thunderbird) only
- [Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mozilla+-xulruner) tagged [mozilla](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mozilla)+[xulrunner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/xulrunner) can be changed to [xulrunner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/xulrunner) only
- [Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mozilla+-xul) tagged [mozilla](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mozilla)+[xul](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/xul) should be evaluated on a case by case basis. This tag combination could be intended to mean just [xul](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/xul), as generally used in Mozilla products. Most commonly, this will be intended to mean [firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/firefox)+[xul](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/xul), particularly in the presence of [firefox-addon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/firefox-addon), [firefox-addon-sdk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/firefox-addon-sdk), or other tag that begins with "firefox", but the presence of one of the Firefox add-on tags does not guarantee that the question is about Firefox, as the Firefox add-on tags are also used in conjunction with Thunderbird and XULRunner.
  Just the [mozilla](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mozilla)+[xul](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/xul) tag combination can also be intended to mean [thunderbird](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/thunderbird)+[xul](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/xul) or [xulrunner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/xulrunner)+[xul](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/xul).
  Care should be taken when evaluating this case. It will commonly be necessary to examine the question body to determine the product which is intended.
- [Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mozilla+-firefox+-thunderbird) tagged only [mozilla](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mozilla) should be checked by the community on a case by case. Most will be related to Firefox, but any of the combinations mentioned above may be appropriate.

Comment: Suggested title: "[mozilla] is tearing the site to pieces"

Comment: Just to help, [here is a query](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/revision/651496/813402/) that finds the most commonly used tags that also use 'mozilla'.

Comment: Suggested title: "[mozilla]? more like lesszilla!"

Comment: Humorous Title Approved by Meta Stack Overflow Neighbourhood Association.

Comment: The Mozilla foundation itself seems to use Mozilla and Firefox almost interchangeably in developer facing docs, which could be leading to confusion: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/

Comment: I would have gone with [mozilla] mo problems, but to each their own.

Comment: Since 2016 only a few tags are related to mozilla http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/652073/posts-with-tag-mozilla-since-2016 (firefox javascript css html google-chrome firefox-addon jquery)

Comment: @Mistalis, It's not just about [feature]ing a post, you need to take the responsibility, that you can take care of the complete procedure [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/324071/4099593). You sure that you can, right? (If not we'll end up like [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333833/should-we-burninate-the-apple-tag))

Comment: @BhargavRao I've posted a [**Progress answer**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/346213/mozilla-more-like-lesszilla/346394#346394) as described on the procedure. Hope this is what should be done :)

Comment: @Mistalis Not that way, I meant to say, there's a lot of questions. So can you take the ownership of the burnination till the end? (it's a bit hard, but not impossible)

Comment: @BhargavRao I've started to eliminate the `mozilla` tag from questions, but can we **forbide** the use of this tag during burnination? There is already massive data about this tag, and we could avoid new questions... Furthermore, is that possible to insta-retag `mozilla`+`firefox` and `mozilla`+`thunderbird` instead of doing it by hand?

Comment: @Mistalis CMs can do it, moderators can't. You'll need to flag your own post asking for that. (At the moment there are many such pending requests, so can't guarantee you)

Answer (score 11):

`Mozilla` used to be an un-ambiguous tag as [the Mozilla suite](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mozilla_Application_Suite), before Firefox and Thunderbird went their own separate ways. Old questions might be referring to that.

I am unsure what to or whether those questions should be retagged (but most probably to Firefox). For what it's worth, the Mozilla suite has been rebranded as [seamonkey](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/seamonkey) (and is no longer officially supported by the Mozilla Foundation).

Another component of the Mozilla Suite was Chatzilla, an IRC client, but precious few questions seem to be referring to that.

Comment: But this site was only founded in 2008, when the Mozilla Suite was long gone.

Comment: `seamonkey` tag is used on [**9 questions**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/seamonkey) on SO. I'm pretty sure the [1200~ questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mozilla+-firefox+-thunderbird) only tagged `mozilla` are **not** about `seamonkey`.

Comment: @MrLister You're right, last release of the mozilla suite 2006... I might have forgotten to check the dates before writing this. My bad.

Comment: Well, the transition from the Mozilla Suite to SeaMonkey went fairly seamless - people who were using the former could easily switch over, so it did not feel like the end of an era. That's probably the reason you don't remember it so vividly.

Comment: I don't remember the last time someone used [mozilla] intentionally on a question about the Mozilla suite or SM either. Pretty much anyone who tags their questions [mozilla] actually thinks the name of the Firefox browser is "Mozilla", or the phrasal "Mozilla Firefox" (a la "Internet Explorer").

Comment: If this is really an issue, where the question actually refers to the Mozilla suite, as opposed to Seamonkey,  then we can create an unambiguous [tag:mozilla-suite] or [tag:mozilla-application-suite], which accurately refers to the suite, as opposed to the organization.

Answer (score 7):

## Progress

You can help out by reviewing the questions and answers in these tags and:

- flag or close questions that are off-topic/unclear/too broad/etc;
- filter on these tags in the Close Vote Queue and review;
- vote on the questions and its answers;
- delete vote the question or answer(s) if there is nothing of value;
- editing to add value (re-tag), or;
- flag obsolete comments

All questions where [mozilla](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mozilla) are applicable for re-tagging. Please review this tag in addition to [firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/firefox) or [thunderbird](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/thunderbird).

---

Here are some easy queries:

[mozilla](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mozilla)
[Open](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bmozilla%5D-%5Bthunderbird%5D-%5Bfirefox%5D-%5Bxul%5D+closed:no) <del>1671</del> 1038
[Closed](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bmozilla%5D-%5Bthunderbird%5D-%5Bfirefox%5D-%5Bxul%5D+closed:yes) <del>76</del> 51
[No answers](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bmozilla%5D-%5Bthunderbird%5D-%5Bfirefox%5D-%5Bxul%5D+closed:no+answers:0) <del>301</del> 200
[No accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bmozilla%5D-%5Bthunderbird%5D-%5Bfirefox%5D-%5Bxul%5D+closed:no+hasaccepted:no) <del>894</del> 572

[mozilla](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mozilla)+[firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/firefox)
[Open](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bmozilla%5D+%5Bfirefox%5D+closed:no) <del>473</del> 387
[Closed](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bmozilla%5D+%5Bfirefox%5D+closed:yes) <del>20</del> 0
[No answers](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bmozilla%5D+%5Bfirefox%5D+closed:no+answers:0) <del>85</del> 77
[No accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bmozilla%5D+%5Bfirefox%5D+closed:no+hasaccepted:no) <del>241</del> 183

[mozilla](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mozilla)+[thunderbird](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/thunderbird)
[Open](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bmozilla%5D+%5Bthunderbird%5D+closed:no) <del>39</del> 0
[Closed](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bmozilla%5D+%5Bthunderbird%5D+closed:yes) <del>3</del> 0
[No answers](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bmozilla%5D+%5Bthunderbird%5D+closed:no+answers:0) <del>5</del> 0
[No accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bmozilla%5D+%5Bthunderbird%5D+closed:no+hasaccepted:no) 0

[mozilla](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mozilla)+[xul](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/xul)
[Open](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bmozilla%5D+%5Bxul%5D+closed:no) <del>80</del> 0
[Closed](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bmozilla%5D+%5Bxul%5D+closed:yes) <del>2</del> 0
[No answers](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bmozilla%5D+%5Bxul%5D+closed:no+answers:0) <del>5</del> 0
[No accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bmozilla%5D+%5Bxul%5D+closed:no+hasaccepted:no) <del>29</del> 0

Remember that we don't want to destroy value so let salvaging a post be your first priority!

If you have specific questions feel free to drop in the [SOCVR](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers) room.

Answer (score 1):

I used this tag in several questions because I was talking about the Mozilla *platform*. At the time I was building a desktop application based on the Mozilla platform.

These questions are now tagged “firefox”. This is subtly less appropriate because some of the questions only make sense for Firefox in the context of writing a plugin, or possibly only in the context of modifying Firefox itself.

I don’t hugely object to this change, I just wanted to point out that I had a perfectly good reason for choosing “mozilla” over “firefox” at the time, and that this context is now lost.

Comment: I've checked questions of you I've edited. First there is [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/375710/detect-failure-to-load-contents-of-an-iframe) about `xul` (*a  user interface markup language developed by Mozilla*). I've retaged it as `xul-runner`, which, *as explained in the tag desc*, is a Mozilla tool. I didn't retag it as `firefox`. I've also added to the **Progress** answer I've posted something about the related tag Xul.

Comment: I've also retagged a [second](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/425274/prevent-line-paragraph-breaks-in-contenteditable) question by you. This question is about the attribute `contentedittable`. After reading it again, I don't get how it relates to either Firefox or the Mozilla Foundation. Anyway, feel free to change the tags if you think it can be improved.