# Should we burninate the [htc] tag?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request

HTC is a company, and in line with the recent burninations of [apple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apple) and [microsoft](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/microsoft) I propose that we burninate it.

Addressing [the points Shog9 makes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/239191):

- > Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?

  Well, it sort-of describes the contents and it's mainly unambiguous (There is HTML Components, as [Tieson T.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/351225/should-we-burninate-the-htc-tag#comment485395_351225) mentioned, but that's a small minority of the questions and leaving [htc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/htc) for this would surely lead to abuse).
- > Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?

  No, as it is a company, not a programming-related product.
- > Does the tag add *any* meaningful information to the post?

  Clearly not.
- > Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?

  Yes.

The tag wiki just states that it is a company that makes telephones and which OS they run. Nothing programming related there.

All in all, I think the 538 questions currently tagged [htc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/htc) can do without the tag.

Comment: I doubt there are enough questions to justify it, and it'd probably be misused, but [htc] _would_ be a valid tag synonym for [HTML components](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms531018.aspx)

Comment: @TiesonT. in that case I'd say make a tag [HTML-Components] and maybe synonimise [HTC] to it, but don't let [HTC] live on its own.

Comment: Are there no hardware-specific features of an HTC phone that a programmer might care about that would merit the tag?

Comment: Yes, the tag wiki needs to be updated. That's a very different request than "burnination". [htc-programming] is a *horrible* suggestion, not in line with *anything* else on this site. We don't call it [java-programming] because the "-programming" part is implicit on a Q&A site dedicated to programming. And a specific name is fine, unless it's a general hardware feature found on *all* HTC devices. Then, [htc] makes good sense, analogous to [iphone] and [ipad].

Comment: Anyone that "develops" on HTC needs to develop on Windows Mobile, Android, SmartPhone (yeah, it's an OS), Pocket PC, etc. Heck, they have manufactured the Sony Xperia just that they didn't *brand* it. HTC is the exact equivalent to a "bunch of loosely related devices". This tag is just saying "the brand of the phone is htc". Oh, and lets not get into the VR business.

Comment: I develop Android apps, and to be honest, I've faced a brand-specific issue (looking at you, [Samsung](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16398294/2821954) :/). It's part of a problem on the Android fragmentation. Of course, this is just my 2 cents, not judging if the tag is needed or not.

Comment: @AndrewT. looks like your specific problem would warrant a tag [samsung-TouchWiz] (or just [TouchWiz]), not an actual [samsung] tag; the same as the suggestion of the answer below to create [htc-opensense], instead of the meaningless manufacturer's name tag

Comment: @Adriaan fair point. The manufacturer's name is indeed too broad.

Comment: Stats at the start of featuring. +57/-1. 1 answer saying Aye! (+36/0)

Comment: On a side note with regards to HTML components, I'd understand [htmlc] or [hc], but why [htc]? Hyper-text components maybe, but it does not make sense to use [htc] to tag 'Hyper-text makup language components'.

Comment: @Knickerless-Noggins: Because Microsoft has referred to HTML Components as "HTCs" (plural) and "HTC" (singular) since the days of Internet Explorer 5, when they were introduced. Note: I'm not saying they should be called HTCs, but rather that that's what Microsoft decided to call them, so people looking for help with them will likely call them that.

Comment: I say we burn it.

Comment: Many HTC phones have custom interfaces on top of the Android OS; presumably questions pertaining to leveraging those interfaces in code would be a valid use of the tag. But that's more a niche case; I agree the tag is largely redundant.

Comment: @Extragorey [htc-android]?

Comment: Stats at the end of featuring - +123/-2 on the question, Answer saying Aye! +86/0. The community is in favor of the burnination.

Comment: IMO, all tags related to mobile companies should be burninated and be made more specific htc-android, samsung-gearvr, htc-vive etc.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

## [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

## The [htc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/htc) tag is now burninated!

[image: BURNINATED! (by Trogdor)]

- [Open](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bhtc%5D+closed%3Ano) <s>474</s> <s>424</s> <s>333</s> <s>91</s> <s>1</s> **0**
- [Closed](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bhtc%5D+closed%3Ayes) <s>17</s> <s>28</s> <s>50</s> <s>49</s> <s>61</s> **0**
- [No answers](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bhtc%5D+answers%3A0+closed%3Ano) <s>87</s> <s>50</s> <s>35</s> <s>5</s> **0**
- [No accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bhtc%5D+hasaccepted%3A0+closed%3Ano) <s>263</s> <s>221</s> <s>167</s> <s>40</s> **0**

Remember that we don't want to destroy value so let salvaging a post be your first priority! If you have specific questions feel free to drop in the  [SOCVR](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers), or leave a comment under this post.

Answer (score 85):

I support this burnination (burninate?).

Android as a platform is largely oem-agnostic. It is very unlikely that we would need manufacturer specific tags.

The only SDK that could warrant such a thing is HTC's OpenSense, which is designed for access to their specific hardware features that are not part of the base Android code (dual cameras, infrared, and integration with HTC Sense for instance). For questions regarding those, we can add [htc-opensense](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/htc-opensense) if necessary (or something along those lines).

Comment: Thanks for your experienced view on the matter. Seeing your suggestion on the [htc-opensense] I'd like to ask that either you, or others with experience on android and HTC devices look into retagging where necessary, as I have no knowledge whatsoever on anything phone-related.

Comment: Remember that HTC also makes VR products!

Comment: @Braiam Sure, but we already have [htc-vive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/htc-vive). You can have product/platform specific tags if needed. Having one for an entire manufacturer seems unlikely

Comment: My comment was aimed towards those that think that HTC makes only phones, they do not only make phones.

Comment: And not all of their phones run android either.

Answer (score -2):

Companies like HTC and Samsung roll their own flavor of Android. [Job postings even list experience with specific manufacturers' flavor of Android as a desired skill.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/03iNh.jpg) So I don't think we should burninate the HTC tag, because there very well could be specific HTC issues or features that a user might want to ask about. I think we're destroying value when we burninate this tag, or any manufacturer tag.

Comment: If we need it, we could create a htc-android tag... but nobody has pulled examples of any of such questions on the site, so right now is in the realm of the impossibility theory.

Comment: [There are definitely cases of HTC-specific questions on the site.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12962645/noclassdeffounderror-on-htc-sense) But an htc-android tag would be fine. Actually, what I didn't realize is that there's an htcsense tag, which is honestly just as good as an htc tag.