# It's my way or the [huawei]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request

In the grand tradition of [[apple]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333833/should-we-burninate-the-apple-tag?s=5|38.9499), [microsoft] and [[htc]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/351225/should-we-burninate-the-htc-tag?s=1|53.6864) (all [company tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/190916/244695)) I give you

[huawei](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/huawei)

164 questions that don't describe the question, just the company who made the hardware.

Comment: Honestly the pun made me throw up in my mouth a little...

Comment: Objectively speaking, are there any questions in this pile that would still be subjective and on-topic?  There may be some that talk about this as *hardware* instead of as a *company*, which may be a reason to keep this around.

Comment: @Makoto I've not seen any, but the same argument could have been made about [htc] and wasn't

Comment: This is an EXCELLENT pun.

Comment: If i was a pun agent right now, I would probably jump on a desk and shout "Xiaomi the money" at you.

Comment: @Makoto i don't think objectivity comes into this one, the title is too much of a winner.

Comment: @NickDewitt I don't have any [oppo]sition.  But there is a b[asus] for burnination.

Comment: @rgettman [oneplus] for that comment.