# What's with the Huawei [hms-xxx] Tag Bombing?

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-system

In the course of my reviewing the Suggested Edits queue, in recent days, I have been coming across *so many* new tags of the form `[hms-xxx]` - each for one particular 'function' from the HMS (Huawei Mobile Services) package. There are currently **18** such tags (plus `[hms]` itself), one of which has 4 questions, one with 2, and the others with only 1 (or zero) questions each. *Most of these seem to have been created within a period of a week or so.*

Do we really need so many such tags? And, if not, is there a 'bulk-burninate' process to remove (or merge) them?

Related (possibly relevant) reading: [It's my way or the [huawei]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/366908/10871073).

Comment: A moderator can merge all of these in short order. Seems they could all be merged into [huawei-mobile-services] (which [hms] is itself a synonym of).

Comment: Hmm, looks like these were all created by the same user. Maybe a moderator should do something about *that*, too. Any volunteers?

Comment: @CodyGray Did some unknown moderator *already* merge them? I didn't notice they were all made by the same user, but the suggested edits I came across were from at least three different folks.

Comment: No, they're not merged. Go [here](https://stackoverflow.com/tags?tab=name), type in "hms", and you'll see all the tags that start with that prefix. If a tag only has one question associated with it, it's quite easy to see who created that tag.

Comment: @CodyGray OK. What I did was then select the `hms-integration` tag (which has zero questions), and it sent me to `huawei-mobile-services` instead. So I was confused.

Comment: Maybe also related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/397817/578411

Comment: Yes, [hms-integration] was merged into [huawei-mobile-services] by a moderator back on March 22. So *that one* is already merged, but plenty of others are not. (You can't see when it was actually merged, but the fact that the tag exists with 0 questions and redirects to another tag is a tell-tale sign that it's been synonymized.)

Comment: I can just go through quickly and remove them all, and make sure they have the hms tag.

Comment: @S.S.Anne *If* you do that, then use [huawei-mobile-services] rather than [hms]. But I was thinking that a more 'formal' process could prevent such tags being re-created in the future. (And moderators have so little to do these days, you'd be depriving one of their fun!)

Comment: @Adrian They're synonyms.

Comment: It looks like Huawei employees are doing this. A prolific HMS answerer, [shirley](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13329100/shirley), almost definitely works for Huawei in the HMS division. Many other users with most of their posts being related to HMS are based in or around Shenzhen, where Huawei is headquartered.

Comment: @TheWanderer I did suspect some sort of synchronized activity between the users who created the tags, but you seem to have nailed it down a bit more. Is there any way a tag "blacklist" can be applied in a 'wildcard' sort of way, like to any [hms-*] tag?

Comment: Someone could contact Huawei. I'm not sure how receptive they'll be, though.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I've merged all those tags into [huawei-mobile-services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/huawei-mobile-services).

[image: tag synonyms]

Please ping me if you see any more cropping up (use [this search link](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=%5Bhms-*%5D&mixed=0))

Comment: Posting this comment *in lieu* of pinging you ... a new tag, [hms-core], has been appearing on a number of posts recently. Nearly all added by two users (one of which was mentioned in comments to this question). Does it need 'nipping in the bud'?

Comment: @AdrianMole handled