# Is [huawei-developers] just a rebranding of [huawei]?

Tags: discussion, tags

Apparently since [huawei](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/huawei) was synonymised to [huawei-mobile-services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/huawei-mobile-services) some users really missed having a generic tag to reference all of the technologies that Huawei produces.

But that synonym was triggered exactly because [it wasn't a great tag to begin with](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394772/huawei-too-many-tags) (more [discussion here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/397817/tag-huawei-as-a-synonym-for-huawei-mobile-services-is-approiate-or-not)).

[huawei-developers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/huawei-developers) looks like tries to do exactly the same thing that [huawei](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/huawei) used to.

If [huawei](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/huawei) should not exist then [huawei-developers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/huawei-developers) also shouldn't exist.

And even *if* [huawei-developers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/huawei-developers) makes sense, then I think the name is bad: it's not really about the *developers*, is it. If anything it's about the technology or the products or something like that.

Comment: Looks like the dashboard name is really [*Huawei Developers*](https://developer.huawei.com/en/). I haven't/cannot check if there's anything that is related to SO though.

Comment: That just seems like a documentation hub. I mean there's also https://developer.android.com/ which isn't sufficient reason to have a [tag:android-developer] tag.

Comment: Looks like [there's a history about the creation of this tag](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/60217616/2): "*Created [huawei-developers] because it is related wit HiAI. Tag created according to acceptance Huawei and Stackoverflow meeting on zoom ~13 of May 2020.*" Coincidentally, the editor was also the OP of the linked meta post.

Comment: There is a [burninate request for "huawei"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/366908/1707091).

Comment: I think maybe the whole company needs to be burniated

Answer (score 39):

There is no application, platform, library, or technology called "Huawei Developers". Based on its tag wiki excerpt

> Questions related to huawei-developers, for example: Safety Detect, AppGallery, Huawei AR, Huawei HiAi etc.

it is clearly just a reference to the landing page website, developer.huawei.com, which exists only to point users to one of two other websites, which focus on actual products (like Safety Detect, AppGallery, etc.) and should be disambiguated, cleaned up, and then burninated.